# How to generally match, unify and merge patterns?

Tags: pattern-matching

This question was split from [this one](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/2778/how-to-match-a-pattern-with-a-pattern). While that question is now about how to match two *particular* patterns (mostly using `Verbatim` or `HoldPattern`), this question is about **how to match *any* pattern with another one**, in other words: "How can I test if a given pattern intersects with, or is a subset of another pattern?" (borrowed from Mr.Wizard). Consider the following examples where one can see that the left pattern should "match" the right one, but which all return `False`:

```
MatchQ[a|b, b|a]
MatchQ[{a..}, {a..}]
MatchQ[{a..}, {a...}]
```

Of course one trivial way to deal with `Alternatives` would be to simply `Sort` its arguments:

```
MatchQ[a | b | c, Verbatim[Sort[b | c | a]]]  --->  True
```

but things get complicated if the pattern involves more than `Alternatives`.

### Problem specification:

Therefore I am looking for a predicate function that **compares any pattern with another pattern** and decides whether the first one matches the second one. For this, one needs a general way of matching two expressions that may contain any of these operators: `{|, .., ..., _, __, ___}` and possibly anything else that is specific for patterns. The predicate should have the following behaviour:

```
PatternMatchQ::usage="PatternMatchQ[e1, e2] returns True
if the set of expressions matched by pattern e1 is the same
or is a subset of the expressions matched by pattern e2, False otherwise."
```

i.e. the first pattern should cover the same (or smaller) domain as the second does. Now of course if any of the arguments is a non-pattern, `PatternMatchQ` can fall back to `MatchQ`.

### Examples:

- `a|b` agrees with `b|a`
- `a|b` agrees with `c|b|a` (as `a|b` covers a
  domain that is covered by `a|b|c` as well)
- `a|b|c` does not agree
  with `b|a` (as `a|b|c` covers a domain that is larger than the domain
  covered by `b|a` **unless** `c == a` or `c == b`, in which case the
  pattern simplifies to `a|b`)
- `{a..}` agrees with `{a..}`
- `{a..}` agrees with `{a...}`
- `{a...}` does not agree with `{a..}`

### Extension:

Now the concept of matching can be extended in the following way. So far we were only concerned about whether it is true that $domain(e_1) \subseteq domain(e_2)$, and if not, return `False`. But even if the test gives false, it is possible to define the smallest (most simple) domain that both patterns cover. Also, a full pattern-set-algebra emerges, if one thinks it further. Accordingly, for example `PatternUnion` could work on any number of arguments, and should return the most general unifier of all the argument patterns. The union of patterns would be equivalent to the merging of patterns.

Now, of course, "*The thing that hath been, it is that which shall be; and that which is done is that which shall be done: and there is no new thing under the sun*"... in certain fields (e.g. in logic or in linguistics and especially in construction grammar), this method is called [unification](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unification_%28computer_science%29):

> Two expressions $e_1$ and $e_2$ are said to unify iff there exists a
>   substitution $s$ such that $s(e_1) = s(e_2)$

where a substitution is a **binding** of variables (i.e. implicit, hidden variables introduced by *Mathematica* to deal with e.g. `_`, `__`) in patterns $e_1$ and $e_2$ with actual fitting values. Note that the substituted value of a pattern-variable can be any atom, even symbols, it does not matter. Thus what the code should look for is the equality of variables (i.e. implicit pattern variables). If such an $s$ exists, it is called a **unifier**.
It is known that if two expressions $e_1$ and $e_2$ unify, then there always is only one most general unifier (up to a renaming of variables). Now this general unifier of two pattern expressions can be called (or used to describe) the intersection of $e_1$ and $e_2$.

Comment: Interesting question. Not sure whether I'd call the name PatternMatchQ a good match for a function that tests on one argument being the *subset* of another. Anyway, I wonder what uses you have in mind. One thing that I can come up with would be simplification of patterns. The function could be used to find a simpler equivalent of a complicated one. But that would require the function to return True only for exact matches not subsets.

Comment: Very interesting. Some time ago I did some simple functions to simplify patterns involving `Alternatives` but not the `Blank..` or `Repeated` families. I think a `PatternUnion` would be much simpler than a `PatternIntersection` (which could complement your `PatternMatchQ`)

Comment: Given that Patterns can contain `Condition` and `PatternTest`, I'm pretty sure that a general solution would need solving the halting problem. Therefore I guess any solution would need to either exclude those patterns, or need to be allowed to fail. There might be cases not using those constructs which are undecidable as well.

Comment: @FJRA: `PatternUnion` already exists, it is called `Alternatives`. What you are thinking of is probably something like `PatternSimplify[pat1|pat2]` (neither `Simplify` nor `FullSimplify` seem to simplify patterns). Indeed, a `PatternSimplify` function would probably need `PatternMatchQ` functionality (but failures to compute would just cause the original pattern to be retained). Note that also `PatternIntersection` (without simplification) can be implemented as `_?(MatchQ[#,pat1]&&MatchQ[#,pat2]&)`.

Comment: @celtschk Yes, you are right, what I meant was a `PatternUnion` that simplifies too, simple union and intersection might be done using `||` (or `Alternatives`) or `&&` as you showed. But like `Union` (which merges the list and delete duplicates) that function should simplify too. Interesting problem.

Comment: I just notice that `PatternIntersection` (without simplification) is even simpler implemented as `pat1?(MatchQ[#,pat2]&)`.

Comment: @MrWizard: Just for reference, [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/4283/89) is a nice finding by @Oleksandr R. in the comments about using Internal`ComparePatterns. I almost forgot about it and had to scan through all my comments to find the source...

Comment: @IstvánZachar You can make a nice answer with that one

Comment: @belisarius: I am actually waiting for Oleksandr to do it, as it was his discovery.

Comment: @IstvánZachar You might want to remind him again... the last conversation on this was in April and he probably doesn't remember

Comment: @R.M.: I have pinged him in the comment above, wouldn't that be enough? Sadly we cannot send private messages in SO...

Comment: @IstvánZachar I'm actually surprised that you managed to get two `@` pings in there... usually the system blocks you from pinging a second person. In any case, even if it worked, it wouldn't have pinged Oleksandr, because he has not been a party to this discussion. (you can't randomly ping users in comments — you can only ping those who have already commented or edited your post)

Comment: @R.M I knew about the one-ping-per-comment thing, but regularly I try it just to test the system, and it seemed like it went through. Though I did not know that only involved users can be pinged. This should be advertised more heavily (thanks for the info). Left a comment at the place referred above for Olex.

Comment: @IstvánZachar usernames are not required to be unique on SE sites. Should you be allowed to ping by username only, you may end up awakening a tide of @ Jim s

Answer (score 53, accepted):

In my opinion, this is a very good and worthwhile question, but certainly not easy to answer. I don't have a full solution by any means, but as far as the **comparison/matching** part is concerned, the undocumented function `` Internal`ComparePatterns `` may be of substantial assistance. What follows is a short summary of what I know about this function, which exists in *Mathematica* 7 and 8, but not version 5.2. I would guess that it is new-in-6 and used in the implementation of `OptionsPattern` and related functions.

`` Internal`ComparePatterns[p, q] `` (where `p` and `q` are patterns) operates somewhat like `MatchQ`, except that rather than simply `True` or `False` to signify agreement or disagreement, multiple (namely, five) possibilities exist to describe the relationship `p` has to `q`:

1. **Identity**

   Two patterns are considered identical if they match verbatim up to, but not including, naming. This relation should obviously be transitive and commutative, and I haven't observed any counterexamples so far. An example could be:

   ```
   Internal`ComparePatterns[a_, b_]
   (* -> "Identical" *)
   ```

   It is also aware of attributes that affect pattern matching. Here we attempt to mask the `Orderless` attribute of `Plus` (and thus possibly confuse `` Internal`ComparePatterns ``) by wrapping it in `HoldComplete`:

   ```
   Internal`ComparePatterns[
    HoldComplete[x_Real + y_Integer],
    HoldComplete[y_Integer + x_Real]
   ]
   (* -> "Identical" *)
   ```

   Pattern names are not completely ignored, however, and seem to be taken into account where appropriate:

   ```
   Internal`ComparePatterns[x_Real + y_Integer, x_Integer + y_Real]
   (* -> "Incomparable" *)
   ```
2. **Equivalence**

   If `p` has the same *meaning* as `q` but is not structurally identical, the patterns are considered equivalent:

   ```
   Internal`ComparePatterns[a | b, b | a] (* Alternatives is not Orderless *)
   (* -> "Equivalent" *)

   Internal`ComparePatterns[a : y_ + x_, b : (f : Plus)[x_, y_]]
   (* -> "Equivalent" *)
   ```

   However, determination of this relationship is not completely robust. Patterns that are sufficiently structurally different sometimes will not be considered equivalent even if they manifestly are:

   ```
   Internal`ComparePatterns[a : y_ + x_, b : (f : Plus | Plus)[x_, y_]]
   (* -> "Specific" *)
   ```

   Here are two more examples of patterns that are equivalent, but where the relationship is misstated. The second of these is particularly interesting:

   ```
   Internal`ComparePatterns[Repeated[_, Infinity], Repeated[_]]
   (* -> "Specific" *)

   Internal`ComparePatterns[Repeated[_, {1, Infinity}], Repeated[_, Infinity]]
   (* -> "Identical" *)
   ```
3. **Specificity**

   In some circumstances, `` Internal`ComparePatterns `` is able to determine when one pattern is a special case of another:

   ```
   Internal`ComparePatterns[_h, _]
   (* -> "Specific" *)
   ```

   However, this situation is often misdiagnosed with equivalent patterns, which will instead be identified as special cases of each other:

   ```
   Internal`ComparePatterns[__, (_) ..]
   (* -> "Specific" *)

   Internal`ComparePatterns[(_) .., __]
   (* -> "Specific" *)
   ```
4. **Disjointness**

   What is more reliably stated is when one pattern is exclusive of another, i.e. there are no expressions that could be matched by both:

   ```
   Internal`ComparePatterns[_a, _b]
   (* -> "Disjoint" *)
   ```
5. **Incomparability**

   Finally, we have the situation whereby the patterns are either unrelated, or `` Internal`ComparePatterns `` simply does not know how to interpret their relationship:

   ```
   Internal`ComparePatterns[a | b, b | c]
   (* -> "Incomparable" *)
   ```

   Notably, it seems to be the case that `` Internal`ComparePatterns `` works entirely inside the pattern matcher, so that conditional patterns (which need to invoke the main evaluation loop), if not identical, are generally incomparable (by this mechanism):

   ```
   Internal`ComparePatterns[_ /; True, _ /; Sequence[True]]
   (* -> "Incomparable" *)

   Internal`ComparePatterns[_?(True &), _ /; True]
   (* -> "Incomparable" *)
   ```

Now let's try it on the examples:

```
Internal`ComparePatterns[a | b, b | a]           (* -> "Equivalent" -- correct *)
Internal`ComparePatterns[a | b, c | b | a]       (* -> "Specific" -- correct *)
Internal`ComparePatterns[a | b | c, b | a]       (* -> "Incomparable" -- correct *)
Internal`ComparePatterns[a | b | (c : b), b | a] (* -> "Incomparable" -- incorrect, but: *)
Internal`ComparePatterns[a | (c : b), b | a]     (* -> "Equivalent" -- correct *)
Internal`ComparePatterns[{a ..}, {a ..}]         (* -> "Identical" -- correct *)
Internal`ComparePatterns[{a ..}, {a ...}]        (* -> "Specific" -- correct *)
Internal`ComparePatterns[{a ...}, {a ..}]        (* -> "Incomparable" -- correct *)
```

So, `` Internal`ComparePatterns `` fails only in one case, and its answer is still *technically* correct as it is the result of the inability of the function to see the relationship between these patterns (`` Internal`ComparePatterns[a | b | b, b | a] `` gives `"Specific"` rather than `"Equivalent"`) and not a statement about the expressions they will match.

I should finish by saying that I wasn't able to find any concrete examples of where `` Internal`ComparePatterns `` is actually used in *Mathematica*, which should give one pause considering its occasional mistakes. However, it may be that I didn't find it because I wasn't trying hard enough, rather than because it isn't used anywhere. Here is code for a hook that can be installed (using `$Pre = withHookedComparePatterns`) during normal usage. If you're lucky enough to stumble on a function that uses `` Internal`ComparePatterns ``, the call stack and the call itself will be printed out at that point, which will help to identify what its use case is, if any. Anyone finding any examples is welcome to edit this answer to include them below (marking as Community Wiki at the same time, if desired).

```
ClearAll[withHookedComparePatterns];
SetAttributes[withHookedComparePatterns, HoldAll];
Begin["System`Private`"];
withHookedComparePatterns[expr_] :=
  Internal`InheritedBlock[{Internal`ComparePatterns},
   Unprotect[Internal`ComparePatterns];
   cp : Internal`ComparePatterns[___] /;
     StackInhibit[Print[{Stack[], HoldForm[cp]}]; True] := cp;
   Protect[Internal`ComparePatterns];
   StackBegin[expr]
  ];
End[];
```

Comment: Beautiful and exhaustive answer. Thanks!

Comment: Well deserved bounty awarded.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard thanks very much! Wasn't sure if you considered this bounty-worthy or not given that it's not a full answer and I'd already somewhat committed to posting this before. Out of interest, do you feel that the outcome of your featuring this question was favorable in terms of getting enough additional attention? It's a hard question for sure, so maybe no further answers are to be expected, but it didn't generate that many extra views either AFAICT. Do most people even look at the featured questions?

Comment: This is surely worthy of the bounty.  I may however offer a second bounty at a later time in search of a supplemental answer.  I am pleased with the outcome of the bounty, and it *did* get attention as the question gained 12 votes during the week.

Comment: Oleksandr, @Mr.Wizard I've just discovered that the order arguments are supplied to `ComparePatterns` does matter. In some cases swapping argument position yields a sensible result if otherwise it was `Incomparable`. A new example: `f[___]` and `f[]` - try them with both orders. Accordingly, I think `ComparePatterns` expects arguments to be supplied in the order of specificty: more specific patterns should precede more general patterns. If one thinks of function definition (like `f[___]:=f[]`) then _rhs_ should precede _lhs_ when comparing them.

Comment: In V10, there is ``GeneralUtilities`PatternOrder``, which is based on ``Internal`ComparePatterns``.  The definition is available (after loading ``"GeneralUtilities`"``).  It may be worth exploring.