# Why does Mathematica choose the second function definition?

Tags: programming, pattern-matching

While working on a solution to [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/2918/how-to-generally-match-unify-and-merge-patterns) I've come across a case where I simply don't understand Mathematica's behaviour.

I've got the following definitions:

```
PatternImplies[(x:(Verbatim[Blank]
                  |Verbatim[BlankSequence]
                  |Verbatim[BlankNullSequence]))[h_],x[]]:=True

(*CatchAll rule*)
PatternImplies[_,_]:=Maybe;
```

Now I try this:

```
PatternImplies[_Integer,_]
(*
==> Maybe
*)
```

I would have expected `True`. My first thought was that I probably got the pattern wrong, so I tested:

```
MatchQ[PatternImplies[_Integer,_],
       PatternImplies[(x:(Verbatim[Blank]
                         |Verbatim[BlankSequence]
                         |Verbatim[BlankNullSequence]))[h_],x[]]]
(*
==> True
*)
```

In other words, the pattern matches. Moreover, looking at `Downvalues` I see that the special rule is indeed stored before the catch-all rule.

So why does Mathematica chose the second definition (and more importantly, what can I do about it?)

Comment: I am really curious about what you are cooking here celtschk! :)

Comment: Just thought I'd better make you (and @István) aware, if you're not already, that what this implements seems quite similar to the undocumented function ``Internal`ComparePatterns``. For instance ``Internal`ComparePatterns[_Integer, _]`` gives `"Specific"`, i.e. `_Integer` is a special case of `_`.

Comment: @OleksandrR.: Ah thanks, I was not aware of that. Is there any place where this function is described?

Comment: @OleksandrR. would you care to post your findings as an answer to my question [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/2918/89)? It would be nice to gather related stuff there, and it might nudge others knowing more to share information about `ComparePatterns`. So far it seems that this amazing function handles all my example cases posted there.

Comment: @István I haven't looked into this function in great detail so far; I just know that it exists and, in general terms, what it does. I think I'll research it further and then post an answer to your question mentioning it. I hadn't done so previously as what you ask for covers a much broader scope than ``Internal`ComparePatterns`` can actually address.

Comment: @OleksandrR. Now is the perfect time to show what you have unearthed concerning `ComparePatterns`, as there is a bounty on the [question here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/2918/89). As I said it before, this would make a perfect answer!

Comment: @IstvánZachar and thanks to Mr. W for the reminder. :) I will post something tonight so that at least the question will not go unanswered, although I fear that what I can say about it is still rather limited.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As far as I can tell, it should match the catch all rule. That's because `_` isn't of the form `x[]`

Now, when you test the `MatchQ` expression, both arguments are first evaluated. So, you're actually doing `MatchQ[maybe, maybe]` which of course returns `True`.

You can do the checking as you intended to by first holding the arguments

```
MatchQ[Hold@PatternImplies[_Integer, _], 
 Hold@PatternImplies[(x : (Verbatim[Blank] | Verbatim[BlankSequence] |
         Verbatim[BlankNullSequence]))[h_], x[]]]

False
```

EDIT:

I now see what you intended with `x[]`. You could do `x_[]` instead. That would mean "any no-argument expression whose head coincides with the previous pattern labelled `x`. If you write `x[]` it matches literally

Comment: Thank you. So I got fooled by MatchQ — next time I'll know to use `Unevaluated`. With the `x_[]` now it works great.