# Which function definition is used to evaluate an expression that matches the lefthand side of more than one definition?

Tags: argument-patterns

In a case like this:

```
f[a_] := a;
f[{a_, b_}] := a;
```

I'm wondering whether I should expect `f[{2, 3}]` to return `{2,3}` or `2`, because:

```
MatchQ[{2, 3}, a_] == MatchQ[{2, 3}, {a_, b_}]
```

Is the behaviour in this situation defined, or should I avoid this at all costs?

Comment: I thought I recalled a simple question in similar form to this one but the only (open) question I could find is the yet-unanswered:  [(8619)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/8619)  -- I do feel that this question is a duplicate but I'll not close immediately in case others disagree.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I feel that at the level of the example, the question is best answered by the documentation in the tutorial set [Transformation Rules And Definitions Overview](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/TransformationRulesAndDefinitionsOverview.html), in particular [The Ordering of Definitions](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/TheOrderingOfDefinitions.html).  The linked question seeks a deeper answer.  The community might close the question as "easily found in the documentation."

Comment: @MichaelE2 I retract my recommendation for closure.  I think this question is sufficiently different, and further I think it is (just) obscure enough not to warrant closure as *easily found in the documentation.*

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I agree.  With the obsolescence of *The Virtual/Mathematica Book* ([html](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/VirtualBookOverview.html), [pdf](http://reference.wolfram.com/legacy/v5_2/Mathematica_V5_Book.zip), 24M) -- the tutorial I linked above is from "Core Language"/Part 2 -- it's hard to know what basic things are *easily* found.  Now we have [Fast Introduction for Programmers](http://www.wolfram.com/language/fast-introduction-for-programmers), but it doesn't include ordering of definitions.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Look at the `DownValues` of `f` to see how *Mathematica* will proceed:

```
DownValues[f]
```

> ```
> {HoldPattern[f[{a_, b_}]] :> a, HoldPattern[f[a_]] :> a}
> ```

OR

```
?f
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

So, though you defined `f[a_] := a` first, the other definition is more specific, hence is applied first. If *Mathematica* cannot decide it will use the definitions in the order they were entered.

---

From [the documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/PatternsAndTransformationRules.html):

> The transformation rules associated with a particular symbol s are
>   always stored in a definite order, and are tested in that order when
>   they are used. Each time you make an assignment, the corresponding
>   transformation rule is inserted at the end of the list of
>   transformation rules associated with s, except in the following cases:
>
> - The left‐hand side of the transformation rule is identical to a transformation rule that has already been stored, and any conditions
>     on the right‐hand side are also identical. In this case, the new
>     transformation rule is inserted in place of the old one.
> - The Wolfram Language determines that the new transformation rule is more specific than a rule already present, and would never be used
>     if it were placed after this rule. In this case, the new rule is
>     placed before the old one. Note that in many cases it is not possible
>     to determine whether one rule is more specific than another; in such
>     cases, the new rule is always inserted at the end.

However this doesn't appear to be quite the whole story.  See:

- [How is pattern specificity decided?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/8619)

And also

- [The Ordering of Definitions](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/TheOrderingOfDefinitions.html)

Comment: @MichaelE2. Thanks, I have added it.

Answer (score 2):

```
Clear[f]
f[a_] := a
f[{a_, b_}] := a
```

Downvalues of a symbol hold the patterns used for its evaluation.

```
dv = DownValues[f]
```

> ```
> {HoldPattern[f[{a_, b_}]] :> a, HoldPattern[f[a_]] :> a}
> ```

Downvalues are searched in normal order, first to last. Therefore,

```
{f[{2, 3}], f[42]}
```

> ```
> {2, 42}
> ```

Downvalues can be reordered to get a different evaluation order.

```
DownValues[f] = Reverse @ dv
```

> ```
> {HoldPattern[f[a_]] :> a, HoldPattern[f[{a_, b_}]] :> a}
> ```

```
{f[{2, 3}], f[42]}
```

> ```
> {{2, 3}, 42}
> ```

If a new rule is added to downvalues, it is inserted into the list of downvalues according to *Mathematica*'s idea of specificity, but ordering of the downvalues is not otherwised changed.

```
f[42] := 0
DownValues[f]
```

> ```
> {HoldPattern[f[42]] :> 0, HoldPattern[f[a_]] :> a, HoldPattern[f[{a_, b_}]] :> a}
> ```

```
{f[{2, 3}], f[42], f[3]}
```

> ```
> {{2, 3}, 0, 3}
> ```

There are many situations in *Mathematica* where overloading function definitions in the manner you describe is extremely useful. So don't fear overloading function definitions, make it one more tool in your programming toolbox.