# Upvalues and order of interpretation

Tags: upvalues, order

I'm trying to use UpValues to improve the usability of some code, but I am running into an issue where the order of the UpValues is important, and I am not sure if it is my understanding or a fundamental problem.

I have a construct called "elementDefinition" that consists solely of a set of rules.
I can transform those rules using the following nomenclature

```
elementDefinition[<some rules>][<property>]-><value>
```

with the upvalue given by (I have overloaded the "SetProperty" in-built function for my own use here!)

```
elementDefinition /: Rule[elementDefinition[list__][var_String],val_] :=  SetProperty[elementDefinition[list],var->val]
```

or, for a concrete example where QUAD is an elementDefinition construct,

```
QUAD["k1"]->2
```

which modifies the property "K1" to the new value of 2.

I also want to be able to return the value of a property using

```
QUAD["k1"]
```

which uses the upvalue definition

```
elementDefinition /: elementDefinition[list__][var_String] :=  var /. {list}
```

However, now when I try and use the first upvalue, it is superceded by the second and my Rule never gets applied, in fact it returns

```
2 -> 2
```

Is there a way to force Mathematica to apply the Rule upvalue before the Replace upvalue and achieve both functions at the same time?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 2) Read the [faq]! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Comment: related: [how-is-pattern-specificity-decided](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/8619/how-is-pattern-specificity-decided)

Comment: @Kuba, I think this is more a question of evaluation control than pattern specificity. In `QUAD["k1"]->2` OP needs `QUAD["k1"]` to partially evaluate to give an `elementDefinition` expression, but then for the `elementDefinition` SubValues **not** to evaluate - so that the UpValue definition kicks in instead when `Rule` evaluates. I'm not sure how this can be done. Personally I would steer clear of using built-ins like `Rule` as part of a homebrew syntax.