# Sorting a list of rules

Tags: sorting, downvalues

When we give several definitions for a function `f`, the `DownValues` of `f` are automatically sorted with respect to the domain defined by the pattern:

```
f[x_]:=2;
f[x_?Positive] := 3;
f[1]=4;
DownValues[f]

(* {HoldPattern[f[1]]:>4,HoldPattern[f[x_?Positive]]:>3,HoldPattern[f[x_]]:>2} *)
```

I am wondering if it possible to sort a list of rules in the same way. For example,

```
{_->6, _?Positive->3, 1->4}
```

should be sorted as

```
{1->4, _?Positive->3, _->6}
```

Of course it can be done by transforming the list of rules to a list of function definitions, and then translate back the (automatically sorted) `DownValues` of that function to the original rules. I am looking for a way not using `DownValues`. Therefore, an alternative title of this question could be: how does *Mathematica* sort `DownValues`?

Comment: This may be helpful: [How is pattern specificity decided?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/8619/47416)

Comment: @Shadowray. Indeed, looks very interesting, thanks.

Comment: I think this question might be considered a duplicate of [(8619)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/8619/121) (which Shadowray linked) -- if that question cannot be answered I think neither can this one, and conversely if this one has an answer it would apply there as well?

Comment: My initial idea was to use ``Reverse@Sort[rules, Boole @* GeneralUtilities`MoreSpecificRuleOrPatternQ]``. It gives a correct result for this example, but it may fail with more complicated lists of patterns.

Answer (score 1):

When using the function `ReplaceAll`, the result may depend on the order in which the rules are given. This is due to the fact that when more than one rule can be applied, `ReplaceAll` uses the first rule in the list. Here is an example:

```
rules={_Integer->1,_?EvenQ->2,1->4, 2->5, _?OddQ->3}
(* {_Integer->1,_?EvenQ->2,1->4,2->5,_?OddQ->3} *)

Range[10] /. rules
(* {1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1} *)

Range[10] /. Reverse[rules]
(* {3,5,3,2,3,2,3,2,3,2} *)
```

I want to use the rules in such a way that the most specific rule is used first. We know that the `DownValues` of a function are automatically sorted such that the most specific definition is used first. We call this mechanism in the following sorting function for rules:

```
sortrules[rules_] := Module[{f}, (f[#[[1]]]=#[[2]])& /@ rules; DownValues[f] /. f[x_]:>x]

sortrules[rules]
(* {HoldPattern[1]:>4,HoldPattern[2]:>5,HoldPattern[_Integer]:>1,
     HoldPattern[_?EvenQ]:>2,HoldPattern[_?OddQ]:>3} *)
```

This is good, but not perfect: it is not recognized that the last two rules are more specific than the third one. That can be improved by using the pattern `_Integer` instead of `_` in the last two rules.

```
sortrules[{_Integer->1, _Integer?EvenQ->2, 1->4, 2->5, _Integer?OddQ->3}]
(* {HoldPattern[1]:>4, HoldPattern[2]:>5, HoldPattern[_Integer?EvenQ]:>2, 
    HoldPattern[_Integer?OddQ]:>3, HoldPattern[_Integer]:>1}
```

My problem is how we can arrive at more or less the same result by using other *Mathematica* functions than `DownValues`.

This [link](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/8619) provided by @Shadowray refers to a very interesting discussion on how to order patterns with respect to the specificity. My question is very related to this discussion and I completely agree with @Mr.Wizard that it can be considered as a duplicate, though I am only  looking for existing *Mathematica* functions, not creating new ones.

As mentioned by Shadowray, in the context `` GeneralUtilities` `` we find some functions for sorting patterns. The most promising is the function `PatternSort`, of which the documentation states that it returns a list of patterns, in order of most specific to least specific.

```
GeneralUtilities`PatternSort[rules[[All, 1]]]
(* {_?OddQ,2,1,_?EvenQ,_Integer} *)
```

Obviously, this result is not in agreement with the documentation: the most specific patterns 1 and 2 follow the less specific pattern `_?OddQ`.

By using `Information` on these functions, we find that at the end they call the function `` Internal`ComparePatterns ``. That function cannot handle patterns that contain a function test very well:

```
Internal`ComparePatterns[1,_?(True&)]
(* Incomparable *)
```

So my conclusion is that using `DownValues` for sorting patterns or rules with respect to specificity, as done above, has to be preferred over using the functions in the context `` GeneralUtilities` ``.