# When is a symbol a Symbol? Is there an easy Mathematica way to test if an object is a symbol sort of like a SymbolQ?

Tags: variable-definitions, grid-layouts, symbols

Yes I know there is no built-in native function called `SymbolQ` (but JavaScript does). However, could one be simulated to work for most cases? I often rely on `objectName[symbol]` and `makeRuleRow[symbol]` to return the name of a defined variable and its value in a ready-to-use row for structured `Grid` layouts of results to computations. However, sometimes an error is returned if a variable is not a `Symbol` which leaves me asking, "When is a *symbol* a `Symbol`?"

I would like to catch such errors and return as much useful information as possible. That is why I ask if there is an easy hack for determining if a variable is a symbol.

Here is some working code where I might use such a function...

```
SetAttributes[symbolQ, HoldAllComplete];
symbolQ[x_] := ResourceFunction["SymbolQ"][x];

SetAttributes[{objectName}, HoldFirst];
objectName = Function[Null, SymbolName[Unevaluated[#]], {HoldFirst}];
objectName::usage = 
  "objectName@# returns Unevaluated shortened SymbolName.";

SetAttributes[{makeRuleRow}, HoldFirst];
makeRuleRow[symbol_, altname_ : Null, desc_ : Null] := 
 Module[{name = "", prepend = ""},
  If[ResourceFunction["SymbolQ"][symbol] === False && 
    altname === Null, 
   Return[Row[{Style["Argument ", Red], symbol, 
      Style[" is not a symbol. Use altname in makeRuleRow.", Red]}]
    ], False
   ];
  name = If[StringQ[altname], altname, objectName[symbol]];
  prepend = If[StringQ[desc], desc <> " ", ""];
  {Row[{Style[prepend, Brown], name, rule}], 
   TraditionalForm[symbol]}
  ]
```

The following is how it would be used for most cases (including an error) expected to be encountered when setting up name-value pairs for `Grid` row elements...

```
xxx = 123;

makeRuleRow[xxx] (* this outputs name and value *)
makeRuleRow[xxx, "alternate name"] (* this creates alternate name *)
makeRuleRow[xxx, "alternate name", "this is a symbol"] (* this prepends a description and creates alternate name *)
makeRuleRow[69] (* this generates an error message suggesting a fix *)
makeRuleRow[69, "XXX"] (* bypasses error by creating alternate name *)
makeRuleRow[69, "XXX", "not a symbol"] (* bypasses error by creating alternate name and prepend a description *)
```

The actual output when done correctly conveniently makes `{name ->, value}` rows ready to be inserted into two-column Grid layouts...

```
{xxx -> ,123}
{alternate name -> ,123}
{this is a symbol alternate name -> ,123}
Argument 69 is not a symbol. Use altname in makeRuleRow.
{XXX -> ,69}
{not a symbol XXX -> ,69}
```

Comment: You mean something like this? https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/SymbolQ

Comment: @SjoerdSmit Yes that is exactly what I wanted. But I don't know how to access it. Am I supposed to download the definition to my pc and install it to my mathematica as an addon? Or copy the function `SymbolQ` and paste it to my open notebook? As you can tell I am sort of new to Mathematica.

Comment: Is it enough just to check that `SymbolName` works? Something like: `symbolQ[x_]:=Quiet[Check[StringQ@SymbolName[x], False, General::sym], General::sym]`

Comment: @JulesManson You can just click on the code blocks on that page to copy code you can paste into your notebook. For example, clicking on the first block copies `ResourceFunction["SymbolQ"][x]` to the clipboard. The function will download automatically. You can also download the source notebook if you want to see how it works internally.

Comment: @SjoerdSmit  yeah i figured it out. it's very straight forward. i noticed that to use the function for some `x=123` you have to call it like this `ResourceFunction["SymbolQ"][x]` so i tried to make a short alias for it but it wouldn't work `symbolQ = ResourceFunction["SymbolQ"][#] &;`. do you have ideas of how i could do that?

Comment: @JulesManson - you can just do `symbolQ = ResourceFunction["SymbolQ"]`.  My kernel init.m file is *filled* with definitions like that.

Comment: @JasonB. Actually, I just found out that that doesn't work for resource functions. It seems like the attributes don't propagate correctly for some reason. You need `SetAttributes[symbolQ, HoldAllComplete]; symbolQ[x_] := ResourceFunction["SymbolQ"][x]` to make it work. I think I'll report a bug about this.

Comment: Can you not use a pattern in makeRuleRow like `foo[s_Symbol,..]:=...`?

Comment: @MichaelE2 I don't think you can because there is no Head called symbol.

Comment: @SjoerdSmit What makes you think that this is fixable at all? The only way to make `SubValues` - based definitions hold their second group of arguments is to use the `Stack`, more or less along the lines I described [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/545/81) - and if you look at `DownValues` of `ResourceFunction`, you will see that they use exactly that  (which is an ugly hack that actually also adds significant overhead to the function call, potentially changing its complexity).This is why your method worked, but I just don't see an easy way to make it work as initially requested.

Comment: @Jules Try `Head@Plot` and `MatchQ[Plot, _Symbol]` for instance.

Comment: @LeonidShifrin I appreciate that this is not easy to make work, but from a user perspective I expect the head `symbolQ` to evaluate to the resource function and then evaluate the same as `ResourceFunction["SymbolQ"][x]`. That's how it should behave and it doesn't. If it's fixable or not, I will leave up to whoever's in charge of that.

Comment: @SjoerdSmit Sure thing, I don't dispute that your plan for filing a bug is the right thing to do. I was trying to hint that the design itself is problematic. Actually, this problem shows just one facet of it, it doesn't stop here.

Comment: @LeonidShifrin I just discovered you can do `symbolQ = ResourceFunction["SymbolQ", "Function"]` to avoid this problem. See the answer I posted.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I'd probably use `x_Symbol` in a function argument to control evaluation. Otherwise, one might do the following (thanks to @Leonid for pointing out an oversight).

If the argument is to be evaluated before testing:

```
SymbolQ = MatchQ[#, t_Symbol /; AtomQ[t]] &
```

If the argument is not to be evaluated:

```
SymbolQ = Function[s,
  MatchQ[Unevaluated@s, t_Symbol /; AtomQ[Unevaluated@t]], 
  HoldAllComplete];
```

Examples with the second definition:

```
SymbolQ@Plot
```

> ```
> (*  True  *)
> ```

```
x = 1;
SymbolQ[x]
```

> ```
> (*  True  *)
> ```

```
Clear[y];
SymbolQ@y[1]
```

> ```
> (*  False  *)
> ```

---

***Addendum***

Here's what I had in mind for `makeRuleRow`:

```
ClearAll[makeRuleRow];
SetAttributes[makeRuleRow, HoldFirst];
makeRuleRow[symbol_Symbol, altname_ : "", desc_ : ""] := 
  "execute body of function";
makeRuleRow[symbol_, altname_ : "", desc_ : ""] := 
  Null /; (Message[makeRuleRow::sym, symbol, 1]; False);

makeRuleRow[123]
```

> makeRuleRow::sym: Argument 123 at position 1 is expected to be a symbol.
>
> ```
> (*  makeRuleRow[123]  *)
> ```

```
makeRuleRow[y]
```

> ```
> (* "execute body of function"  *)
> ```

---

***Addendum 2***

*1.*
You could use `Replace` or `Switch` to define `name` in either way below:

```
ClearAll[makeRuleRow];
SetAttributes[{makeRuleRow}, HoldFirst];
makeRuleRow[symbol_, altname_ : Null, desc_ : Null] := 
  Module[{name = "", prepend = ""},
   name = Replace[Unevaluated@symbol, {
      s_Symbol :> objectName[symbol]
      , s_ /; StringQ@altname :> altname
      , _ -> $Failed}
     ];
   prepend = If[StringQ[desc], desc <> " ", ""];
   {Row[{Style[prepend, desccolor], name, rule}], 
     TraditionalForm[symbol]} /; FreeQ[name, $Failed]];
makeRuleRow[symbol_, altname_ : Null, desc_ : Null] := Null /; (
    Message[makeRuleRow::args, makeRuleRow]; False);
```

*2.*
Or:

```
ClearAll[makeRuleRow];
SetAttributes[{makeRuleRow}, HoldFirst];
makeRuleRow[symbol_, altname_ : Null, desc_ : Null] := 
  Module[{name = "", prepend = ""},
   Switch[Unevaluated@symbol
    , s_Symbol, name = objectName[symbol]
    , s_ /; StringQ@altname, name = altname
    , _, name = $Failed
    ];
   prepend = If[StringQ[desc], desc <> " ", ""];
   {Row[{Style[prepend, desccolor], name, rule}], 
     TraditionalForm[symbol]} /; FreeQ[name, $Failed]];
makeRuleRow[symbol_, altname_ : Null, desc_ : Null] := Null /; (
    Message[makeRuleRow::args, makeRuleRow]; False);
```

Some may prefer `Switch` because they know it from another language or just find it easier to read.  Too many commas for me, and I find the `Replace` method easier.

*3.*
There are a few ways to handle complicated argument checking.  Another is to call an "internal" version which throws `$Failed` when there's is an error:

```
func[symbol_, altname_ : Null, desc_ : Null] := Module[{res},
   res = Catch[iFunc[symbol, altname, desc], func];
   res /; FreeQ[res, $Failed]
   ];
iFunc[symbol_, altname_, desc_] := Module[{ ...},
   If[error1,
    Message[func::err1, ...];
    Throw[$Failed, func]
    ];
   If[error2,
    Message[func::err2, ...];
    Throw[$Failed, func]
    ];
   ...
   res (* return result *)
   ];
```

*4.*
Yet another way is to have the outer function process the arguments and call the internal function with canonicalized arguments (for example, `iMakeRuleRow[name_, desc_]`) or indicate an error. The internal function then can assume the arguments are valid.

Comment: first off thank you for taking the time to answer this post. :)  The first definition with `symbol_Symbol` works perfect in filtering out non-symbols. How could I modify it so that `makeRuleRow` still executes if `symbol_Symbol` is not a `Symbol` but `altname_` is given as a string (not `Null`). BTW I modified my function a little. The updated version is shown at the top. The argument `altname_` provides an alternative variable name to display if the first argument is not a `Symbol`. So to encapsulate I only want it to fail if both `symbol_Symbol` and `altname_` do not pass.

Comment: @JulesManson I see, I did not appreciate the role of `altname`. See my update

Comment: i want you to know that i really appreciate your help. I noticed a lot of advanced features (at least to me) in both solutions which I know I will love learning. I think I will go with your `ReplaceAll` version. I also hate all those commas from switch statements which I believe come from procedural languages. Mathematica is primarily a functional language and that is how I like it. Just one last question. Where do I put the argument checking functions `func` and `ifunc`? Should it go in my notebook where I am using the `makeRuleRow`?

Comment: +1. One tiny nitpick is that as written, your function will give `True` also for e.g. `SymbolQ[Symbol[123]]`. So I'd throw in e.g. `AtomQ` test after the pre-screening `_Symbol` pattern:  `SymbolQ = 
 Function[s, MatchQ[Unevaluated@s, t_Symbol /; AtomQ[Unevaluated[t]]],
   HoldAllComplete]`.

Comment: @JulesManson I meant `func` to stand for `makeRuleRow` (and `iFunc` for `iMakeRuleRow`). I meant `func[]`/`iFunc[]` to illustrate a general strategy, and the internal details I presented won't necessarily match exactly the details of `makeRuleRow[]`. The last point I thought would be clearer if I called the function `func` by a name different from `makeRuleRow`.  So if you're talking about the approach I've just numbered *3*, I would put the argument checking in `iMakeFunction` (represented by the `If[error1,...]...` statements.

Comment: @MichaelE2 I really liked your two-part approach (depending on if evaluated first) to `symbolQ`. my question is, how will mathematica know which definition to choose?  for example could i modify the first definition so that it only runs if it has a value, like this: `symbolQ[s_?ValueQ]= MatchQ[s, s_Symbol /; AtomQ@s];

Comment: @JulesManson If I understand what you’re asking, the order the rules are tried are determined by the specificity of the pattern. The more specific ones are tried first and the more general ones last.  When two rules have the same specificity, then the order is determined by the order in which the rules are defined, the first one going before the second, etc.  See https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/8619/4999 for discussion of how specificity is determined. `DownValues[func]` and `? func` show the order of the definitions.

Answer (score 12):

How about:

```
SymbolQ[_Symbol] = True
SymbolQ[_] = False
```

?

Comment: That's what I had in mind, tho' with the attribute `HoldFirst`.  Actually, I thought the pattern could go directly in the def. of `makeRuleRow` and skip `SymbolQ` altogether...

Comment: @MichaelE2 please bare with me as I am still new to mathematica. could you elaborate a little more on how i could use that for `makeRuleRow[]`?

Comment: @JulesManson I added a shortened paradigm to my answer.

Answer (score 8):

I found my answer thanks to Sjoerd Smit who referenced me to the Mathematica Function Repository. And yes it is appropriately called `SymbolQ` which is used like the following...

```
xxx = 123
ResourceFunction["SymbolQ"][xxx] (* returns True *)
```

A little bit ugly and long but it works. But why not fix if it isn't broken? And that is what I tried to do...

```
SetAttributes[symbolQ, HoldAllComplete];
symbolQ = ResourceFunction["SymbolQ"][#] &;
symbolQ[xxx] (* returns False *)
```

However Sjord came up with a solution that looks eerily similar to mine which leaves me scratching my head, why doesn't my *alias* work?...

```
SetAttributes[symbolQ, HoldAllComplete];
symbolQ[x_] := ResourceFunction["SymbolQ"][x];
symbolQ[xxx] (* returns True *)
```

Comment: Your function does not work correctly, because Mathematica is first replacing ```symbolQ``` with the ownvalue ```ResourceFunction["SymbolQ"][#] &```, and then applying it to ```xxx```, so the ```HoldAllComplete``` attribute never comes into play. You can see that when you run ```Trace@symbolQ[xxx] ``` with your function.

Comment: There is more detail [here](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/EvaluationOfExpressions.html#18938)

Comment: In the comment to your question I have hinted why your alias didn't work. It is due both to a specific approach being used in the design / implementation of `ResourceFunction`, and to the general fact that it is hard and non-trivial to maintain attributes for `SubValues` - based definitions.

Comment: As a general rule: attributes don't affect `OwnValues` (like `symbolQ = ...`) because the transformation will happen before the attributes can take effect. That's why I used a definition based on `DownValues` (`symbolQ[arg___] := ...`).

Comment: And to add: you could also use `symbolQ = Function[x, ResourceFunction["SymbolQ"][x], HoldAllComplete];`. In that case, you attach the attribute to the anonymous function instead.

Answer (score 7):

I want to add something to the discussion about the `ResourceFunction` SymbolQ. The OP observed that doing something like:

```
x = 1;
symbolQ = ResourceFunction["SymbolQ"];
ResourceFunction["SymbolQ"][x]
symbolQ[x]
(* True *)
(* False *)
```

does not work because the attributes of the resource function are not applied correctly. However, I just discovered that you can do the following instead:

```
x = 1;
symbolQ = ResourceFunction["SymbolQ", "Function"];
ResourceFunction["SymbolQ"][x]
symbolQ[x]
(* True *)
(* True *)
```

It seems like `ResourceFunction["SymbolQ", "Function"]` will give you direct access to the function without having to go through the `ResourceFunction` wrapper. This is also nice because it avoids some evaluation overhead from `ResourceFunction`.

Comment: +1. I am not a big fan of the `ResourceFunction` design in general, but within what it is, this is definitely a useful thing to know.

Comment: @SjoerdSmit

 Thanks for the update. I also have a question about resource functions. Are they ever promoted to Mathematica native code in updates? If some have been promoted in the past (due to for example popularity or usefulness) I can see `SymbolQ` getting a bump up.

Comment: @JulesManson It's difficult to say; it's possible they might make it into the language. That said, `SymbolQ` is already a built-in function. It's just a wrapper for ``Developer`HoldSymbolQ``.