# Is it safe to alias a ResourceFunction with a symbol of the same name?

Tags: functions, warning-messages, symbols, resourcefunction, input-alias

The following will show how easy I alias `Ding` which is my very first `ResourceFunction` and it works very well. `Ding` is a more polite alternative to `Beep` designed for alerting on positive or successful events. But first the standard form for using it.

```
 ResourceFunction["Ding"][] (* at full relative system volume *)
 ResourceFunction["Ding"][1/3] (* at 1/3 relative system volume *)
```

And now the alias so that I may use it like I would any native Mathematica symbol. I place all my frequently used aliases in my `init.m`. ***But is aliasing like the following a good idea or standard poor practice?*** If so why?

```
Ding = ResourceFunction["Ding"] (* a very simple alias *)

Ding[] (* at full relative system volume *)
Ding[1/3] (* at 1/3 relative system volume *)
```

If you get a `Paclet` error while trying `Ding` its not the `ResourceFunction` or the alias. It's a bug somewhere in Mathematica. A quick and easy solution is to prepend it with Quiet. If you recognize the error bug please inform us on what's causing it. For the record, `Ding` has no `Paclet` commands, syntax, or symbols in it at all and it does not attempt to install anything. The error looks like this.

```
Sound`ToSampledSound: The SoundFont paclet cannot be installed.
```

Here is the simple solution.

```
Quiet@ResourceFunction["Ding"] []
Quiet@Ding[] (* at full relative system volume *)
Quiet@Ding[1/3] (* at 1/3 relative system volume *)
```

I tried to prepend the alias but unfortunately, it did not work. I mean, it still generated an audible ding but the bug error still appeared.

```
Ding = Quiet@ResourceFunction["Ding"];
```

Comment: Using `Ding` as the alias is not optimal because user-defined variables should not start with a capital letter (to avoid any potential name conflict with existing or future built-in names).

Comment: I recommend reading my answer [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/226612/how-can-i-avoid-performance-losses-from-resourcefunction). Long story short: it's better to use `Ding = ResourceFunction["Ding", "Function"]`.

Comment: Also: `Ding = Quiet @ function` simply does not work because the `Quiet` evaluates away immediately. You'd need `Ding[args___] := Quiet @ function[args]` or `Ding = Quiet @* function` to make that work.

Comment: This might be of use: [PersistResourceFunction](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/PersistResourceFunction/)

Comment: @BobHanlon good idea going lowercase. but i would really love for wolfram to promote my function to the official source code some day. dem is bragging rights lol

Comment: @GregHunt yeah i use that too but watch out for the bugs. works fine if you define individual symbols but if you use lists it wont work.

Comment: @SjoerdSmit thanks for the fantastic tips which i will try but just need one clarification. did you mean this: `Ding = Quiet @*ResourceFunction["Ding"]` ?

Comment: @JulesManson yes, `function` was just my shorthand for whatever thing you want to abbreviate in this situation. I'd recommend `Ding = Quiet @*ResourceFunction["Ding", "Function"]`, though.