# How to check whether an object is an Entity or not?

Tags: curated-data, entity

Perhaps this is trivial - if so I am happy to delete.

I have a mixed list of objects that are Entities and strings. Is there a way of telling the difference between them ?

For example we have the following list:

```
list = {Entity["Country", "France"],Entity["Country", "Germany"],"New Country"}
```

and I want to process this data in a way that I can work out whether this is an entity or not.

i.e.

```
 Map[EntityQ[#]&,list]
```

which would give the output
{True,True,False}

Comment: There was similar question on stack exchange in the past about how to define a `SymbolQ` [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/225811/86543). If the list elements contain either entities or strings you could also use `Not@*StringQ`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Note :** This answer uses internal functions so it might not work in the future.

---

**Code**

```
entityQ[entity_] := 
  Internal`PossibleEntityQ[entity] && 
   EntityFramework`EntityExistsQ[entity];
```

---

I wrote a function that searches all functions and variables in Mathematica including those that are internal:

```
 all…names[name_]:= Information[{___~~"`"~~___~~name~~___ ,___~~name~~___~~"`"~~___}]//Sort;
```

Using :

```
all…names["Entity*Q"]
```

one finds a list with multiple matching names. The three considered in the following are :

- Internal`PossibleEntityQ
- EntityFramework`EntityExistsQ
- EntityFramework`Predicates`Private`iEntityExistsQ

One may check the definitions of these functions using, for example :

```
<< GeneralUtilities`

PrintDefinitions@EntityFramework`EntityTypeExistsQ
```

Consider some examples to see what these functions do.

```
EntityFramework`Predicates`Private`iEntityExistsQ[
 Entity["randrand", "rand"]]
```

`(* False *)`

and

```
EntityFramework`EntityExistsQ[
 Entity["randrand", "rand"]]
```

`(* False *)`

But

```
EntityFramework`Predicates`Private`iEntityExistsQ[
 Entity["Company", "StackExchange::n59g4"]]
```

`(* True *)`

```
EntityFramework`EntityExistsQ[
 Entity["Company", "StackExchange::n59g4"]]
```

`(* True *)`

If the object does not have the expected structure of an `Entity` for example `"word"` or `Entity["english"]` instead of `Entity["Language", "English::385w8"]` then

```
EntityFramework`Predicates`Private`iEntityExistsQ
```

throws an error while

```
EntityFramework`EntityExistsQ
```

does not evaluate.

One can use the following internal function first that seems to just test whether the structure is correct:

```
Internal`PossibleEntityQ[Entity["randrand", "rand"]]
```

`(* True *)`

```
Internal`PossibleEntityQ[Entity["rand"]]
```

`(* False *)`

```
Internal`PossibleEntityQ[42]
```

`(* False *)`

So one can combine those two functions to make an entityQ :

```
entityQ[entity_] := 
  Internal`PossibleEntityQ[entity] && 
   EntityFramework`EntityExistsQ[entity];
```

Verify that the code works:

```
entityQ[42]
```

`(* False *)`

```
entityQ[Entity["randrand", "rand"]]
```

`(* False *)`

```
entityQ[Entity["Company", "StackExchange::n59g4"]]
```

`(* True *)`

Answer (score 3):

You can use a function that expects an [`Entity`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Entity.html) object and will throw an error if not given.  [`CanonicalName`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/CanonicalName.html) is an example.

`CanonicalName` throws `CanonicalName::noent` when not provided an `Entity`. It returns a string that can be tested for success. I only [`Quiet`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Quiet.html) this message so other errors will get passed up.

```
entityQ[expr_] := Quiet[Head@CanonicalName[expr] === String, {CanonicalName::noent}]
```

then

```
entityQ[Entity["apple"]]
```

> ```
> False
> ```

```
entityQ[Entity["Planet", "Earth"]]
```

> ```
> True
> ```

Other messages will be passed up and `entityQ` will still provide a result.

```
entityQ[1/0]
```

> Power::infy: Infinite expression 1/0 encountered.

> ```
> False
> ```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

One way is to define the following function which would have these properties:

```
entityQ[ent_] := Entity === ent[[0]];
Map[entityQ[#] &, list]
```

output is:

```
{True,True,False}
```

as hoped.

Comment: `entityQ[Entity["apple"]]` returns true but `Entity["apple"]` is not an entity object.