# Are these tacit functions?

Tags: functions

I am new to Mathematica and am reading the primer document by Peter Young. Early on, before even introducing functions, he introduces constructions like

```
a[1] = 1; a[2] = 1; Do [ a[k] = a[k-1] + a[k-2], {k, 3, n} ]; a[n]
```

This snippet is meant to generate the Fibonacci sequence up to entry $n$, but what I am asking about here is the `a` in the snippet. How should I understand it? Based on the square bracket syntax, I am tempted to interpret it as a (user-defined) function. Is that correct? Is it a temporary function? And can one define a function in Mathematica simply by defining its value at various points in a given domain? For example, if I write `b[5] = 7; b[8] =2`  have I thereby defined a function `b` ? What happens if I ask for a value outside of the domain so defined, e.g. `b[5]` ? I do not have access to Mathematica right now and so cannot check unfortunately.

Comment: In the Wolfram Language, the term 'function' really means that a symbol has a downvalue, which is a kind of rewrite rule that applies to expressions of the form sym[args]. The evaluation model is based on term-rewriting. You would probably benefit from reading the documentation thoroughly, In general, if no applicable rewrite rule is found for an expression, then it is left unevaluated.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica StackExchange. I would suggest you go on with reading the document and experimenting with Mathematica. Then, at some point, read the tutorial about [Everything is an Expression](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/Expressions.html).

Comment: I consulted the official documentation linked (including by @Domen) but am afraid I still don’t quite see. I understand defining a function in one fell swoop as, e.g. in ` f[x_] = x^2 ` . But my concern is about whether we can do this iteratively, as seems to be done in the snippet I gave. Are we defining ` a ` as a function (at the level of description which I understand thus far) or as something else? I don’t think it’s an array because, IIRC, one uses double square brackets to that end.

Comment: I am not familiar with some of the terms used (“downvalue”?) @GlennWelch Perhaps my comment above clarified my concern though?

Comment: Expressions like `a[1]` are indexed variables. Check [Making Definitions for Indexed Objects](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/TransformationRulesAndDefinitions.html#24351) and compare to [Making Definitions for Functions](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/TransformationRulesAndDefinitions.html#9133). For example, expressions like `a[1]` with an integer define an indexed array, while `a[x]` and `a[x_]` define functions. See also [Defining functions](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/FunctionsAndPrograms.html#13037).

Comment: Thank you so much! “Indexed variable” was a term I haven’t heard. If I am understanding correctly, the underscore is, effectively, what distinguishes the definition of an indexed variable and a function? @creidhne

Comment: There are 2 equivalent interpretations. You may interpret a[1] and a[2] as 2 different variables. But you may as well interpret them as a discrete function defined on the set {1,2}.

Answer (score 3):

```
$Version

(* "13.3.1 for Mac OS X ARM (64-bit) (July 24, 2023)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]
```

`a` and `b` can be considered discrete functions defined for a finite set of arguments.

To broaden the definition for `a` (i.e., for all positive integers) use

```
Clear[a]

a[1] = 1; a[2] = 1; 
a[k_Integer?Positive] := a[k] = a[k - 1] + a[k - 2]
```

where [`memoization`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/workflow/WriteAFunctionThatRemembersComputedValues.html) is used to remember any calculated values

Generating a sequence of values

```
seq = a /@ Range[6]

(* {1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8} *)
```

Then generalizing from the sequence,

```
Clear[a]

a[k_] = FindSequenceFunction[seq, k]

(* Fibonacci[k] *)
```

Or more directly from the recursion

```
Clear[a]

a[k_] = a[k] /. 
  RSolve[{a[1] == 1, a[2] == 1, a[k] == a[k - 1] + a[k - 2]}, a[k], k][[1]]

(* Fibonacci[k] *)
```

Although generated from only positive integer input, this function is defined for all `k`

```
a[k] // FunctionExpand

(* ((1/2 (1 + Sqrt[5]))^k - (2/(1 + Sqrt[5]))^k Cos[k π])/Sqrt[5] *)

Plot[a[k], {k, -5, 5}]
```

[image]

Even for complex arguments, e.g.,

```
a[1.7 + 3.5 I]

(* -4336.77 + 3974.81 I *)
```

Answer (score 1):

You might want to read [Evaluation of Expressions](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/EvaluationOfExpressions.html). What it calls a "definition" is a replacement rule of the form

```
pattern :> newExpression
```

If during evaluation an expression `expr` matches a `pattern` in a definition, then the expression is replaced with `newExpression`. A `pattern` can have argument variables that match parts of `expr`, which parts are insert in `newExpression` where the variables occur. This can mimic the standard notion of "plugging into a function" (e.g. $f(x+h)$ and "function composition" ($f(g(t))$) one encounters in high-school mathematics. Thus one can use definitions to model functions in Mathematica.

On the other hand, the replacement rules and patterns are more general than the notion of function normally encountered in high-school mathematics. Using functions to model evaluation is much more difficult and for most, a bit confusing, at least at the beginning.

Consider the Fibonacci example from the Evaluation tech note linked above:

```
fib[n_] := fib[n - 1] + fib[n - 2]

fib[0] = fib[1] = 1
```

Now, are `fib[0]` and `fib[1]` indexed variables or function definitions? That distinction is solely in the imagination of the user. In my view, it's good for the user to distinguish the two applications, but to Mathematica there is no difference in how `fib[0]` is evaluated.

The code above creates three definitions, which are tested for a match in the following order:

```
{HoldPattern[fib[0]] :> 1,
 HoldPattern[fib[1]] :> 1,
 HoldPattern[fib[n_]] :> fib[n - 1] + fib[n - 2]}
```

Note the third definition was the first line of code. The definitions are ordered by Mathematica according to a mysterious [pattern specificity](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/8619/how-is-pattern-specificity-decided), which I won't go into. There are many kinds of possible definitions, represented by the commands `{DefaultValues, DownValues, FormatValues, NValues, OwnValues, SubValues, UpValues}`. For instance, an ordinary variable assignment `var = 7` creates an "OwnValue" associated to the symbol `var`, whereas `fib[0] = 1` creates a "DownValue" associated to the symbol `fib`.

There's a lot to learn, which makes it confusing. Most of it isn't needed at the beginning, and a simple function model is usually enough, as long as you define a function with a `Blank[]`: `f[x_] := x^2` and not `f[x] := x^2`. See the tech note [Functions and Programs](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/FunctionsAndPrograms.html), which is a good next-step.

To finish up with the OP's `b` example and a comparison with `fib[]`:
The code

```
b[5] = 7; b[8] = 2;
```

creates two definitions:

```
{HoldPattern[b[5]] :> 7,
 HoldPattern[b[8]] :> 2}
```

When `b[5]` is evaluated, the first definition replaces `b[5]` by `7`; and `7` is the output.

When `b[6]` is evaluated, there is no definition that applies, so no transformation and evaluation stops; and the output is `b[6]`.

The definition of `fib` above exposes a pitfall in evaluation. Mathematica has an "infinite evaluation" model. This means that an expression keeps being re-evaluated as long as each evaluation changes the expression. For instance, `b[6]` does not change above and evaluation stops at `b[6]`. Infinite evaluation means evaluation can continue forever or until some system limit is reached.

So in evaluating `fib[2]`, the third definition is applied with `n` being the number `2`:

```
fib[2] --> fib[2-1] + fib[2-2]
```

The subtraction is evaluated in `fib[2-1]` and then the second definition is applied to `fib[1]` to get `1`. Likewise, `fib[2-2]` is evaluated to get `1`. Finally `1+1` is evaluated to give `2`, to which no definition applies. Evaluation stops and `2` is the output.

On the other hand, the third definition is applied to `fib[-2]`, in which `n` is `-2`:

```
fib[-2] --> fib[-2-2] + fib[-2-1]
```

This leads first to the evaluation of `fin[-4]`.
Applying the third definition to `fib[-4]` leads to the evaluation of `fib[-6]`. And so on. Evaluation would go on forever if not for `$RecursionLimit`:

```
fib[-2]
```

> $RecursionLimit::reclim: Recursion depth of 1024 exceeded.
>
> ```
> TerminatedEvaluation["RecursionLimit"] + fib[-2 - 2]
> ```