# Unexpected behavior when directly assigning to DownValues

Tags: downvalues

I'm encountering some unexpected behavior when assigning to `DownValues`. When I assign two definitions for `test[1]` as below, *Mathematica* stores both definitions:

```
DownValues[test] = {HoldPattern[test[1]] :> 1, HoldPattern[test[1]] :> 2};
DownValues[test]

(*{HoldPattern[test[1]] :> 1, HoldPattern[test[1]] :> 2}*)
```

After evaluating `test[1]` I get the expected result `1`. However, if the list of rules contains more than 17 elements, *Mathematica* removes the duplicate definitions and only stores the last one, for example:

```
DownValues[test] = HoldPattern[test[1]] :> # & /@ Range[18];
DownValues[test]

(*{HoldPattern[test[1]] :> 18}*)
```

This of course means that when I evaluate `test[1]` I get `18`, and so the behavior of test becomes dependent of the number of definitions I include in my assignment to `DownValues[test]`:

```
Table[
 DownValues[test] = HoldPattern[test[1]] :> # & /@ Range[i]; 
 test[1], 
 {i, 25}
]

(*{1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25}*)
```

This behavior is problematic when I try to copy the down values of multiple symbols to a new symbol, for example:

```
(a1[#] = #) & /@ Range[5];
(b1[#] = 2 #) & /@ Range[5];

(a2[#] = #) & /@ Range[10];
(b2[#] = 2 #) & /@ Range[10];

DownValues[c1] = Join[DownValues[a1] /. a1 -> c1, DownValues[b1] /. b1 -> c1];
DownValues[c2] = Join[DownValues[a2] /. a2 -> c2, DownValues[b2] /. b2 -> c2];

c1[1]
c2[1]

(*1*)
(*2*)
```

I would expect here that both `c1[1]` and `c2[1]` return `1` -- the downvalue of the first symbol.

Note that the threshold of 17 elements does not seem to depend on the actual number of duplicate definitions, see this example with only one duplicate:

```
DownValues[test] = Append[
 HoldPattern[test[#]] :> # & /@ Range[25], 
 HoldPattern[test[1]] :> 2
];
test[1]

(*2*)
```

Can anyone offer an explanation for this behavior? And is there a way to assign a given list of definitions to a symbol such that the expected behavior is obtained? For example, is there a function `f` such that `test[1]` returns `1` after evaluating

```
DownValues[test] = f[Prepend[list, HoldPattern[test[1]] :> 1]];
```

independent of the definitions in `list`?

Comment: This behavior is not specific to DownValues; it occurs also for example when assigning to OwnValues or to Language`ExtendedDefinition.

Comment: I think purposely defining duplicate DownValues is misguided. Why can't you just use `test[1] = 1` instead of prepending an explicit DownValues? If you must define DownValues in this baroque fashion, why not include a DeleteDuplicatesBy[dv, First] in your definition?

Comment: @CarlWoll I encountered this problem when merging the definitions of two symbols, so the list of definitions is generated from those symbols and does not purposely consist of duplicates. Of course in the presented illustration test[1] = 1 would suffice, but this is not an option in my setting. DeleteDuplicatesBy would not be sufficient for example when there are conditional definitions in the rhs, e.g. when test[1] := 1 /; False; test[1] := 2 /; True;.

Comment: @tom perhaps an example of a couple definitions that better highlight your actual problem would improve the question, then. Perhaps this minimal example is *too* minimal to represent your problem faithfully.

Comment: @MarcoB Thanks for the suggestion, I've added a (hopefully) more representative example.

Answer (score 6):

#### Update:

So you mention a specific case where you need this to work, and I think that's doable. So, owing to the fragility of the `DownValues` under direct assignment I think your best case is a form of [`DeleteDuplicates`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DeleteDuplicates.html) that leverages [`` Internal`ComparePatterns ``](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/7904/38205).

You need to handle cases with [`Condition`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Condition.html) so here's my shot at that:

```
DownValues[d3] =
 DeleteDuplicates[
  Join[DownValues[a2] /. a2 -> d3, DownValues[b2] /. b2 -> d3, 
   DownValues[a3] /. a3 -> d3],
  Internal`ComparePatterns @@
     Map[
      Replace[
        Verbatim[HoldPattern][Verbatim[Condition][t_, ___]] :> 
         HoldPattern[t]]@*First,
      {##}
      ] === "Identical" &
  ]
```

And here's a test example, extending on your base case

```
(a2[#] = #) & /@ Range[10];
(b2[#] = 2 #) & /@ Range[10];
(a3[#] /; $test = #) & /@ Range[10];

DownValues[d3] =
 DeleteDuplicates[
  Join[DownValues[a2] /. a2 -> d3, DownValues[b2] /. b2 -> d3, 
   DownValues[a3] /. a3 -> d3],
  Internal`ComparePatterns @@
     Map[
      Replace[
        Verbatim[HoldPattern][Verbatim[Condition][t_, ___]] :> 
         HoldPattern[t]]@*First,
      {##}
      ] === "Identical" &
  ]

{HoldPattern[d3[1]] :> 1, HoldPattern[d3[2]] :> 2, 
 HoldPattern[d3[3]] :> 3, HoldPattern[d3[4]] :> 4, 
 HoldPattern[d3[5]] :> 5, HoldPattern[d3[6]] :> 6, 
 HoldPattern[d3[7]] :> 7, HoldPattern[d3[8]] :> 8, 
 HoldPattern[d3[9]] :> 9, HoldPattern[d3[10]] :> 10}
```

Note this is stronger than a `DeleteDuplicatesBy[First]` and `` Internal`ComparePatterns `` is stronger:

```
Internal`ComparePatterns[a_, b_]

"Identical"

DeleteDuplicates[{a_, b_}]

{a_, b_}
```

#### Original:

So clearly there's some [`DownValues`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DownValues.html) simplification that's happening here.

But to understand the full behavior it helps to understand what exactly is happening with the `DownValues`. The rough-approximation is that there's a [`ReplaceRepeated`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ReplaceRepeated.html)-like mechanism happening in the evaluator that takes the patterns defined in the `DownValues` of the current expression [`Head`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Head.html). And so it just matches the first pattern that works.

Now, to your case, the simplification is happening at 18 `DownValues`. Given the replacement mechanism, it makes sense to drop unnecessary `DownValues`, why 18 is something I failed to find in the literature. It could be some pattern-complexity estimate or something. I don't know what's going on in the evaluator internals.

On the other hand, the fact that it takes the last value does make some sense. If you think about that assignment in a sequential manner it's entirely reasonable to take the last one.

But note that this simplification doesn't always happen.

```
DownValues[g] = HoldPattern[g[1]] :> # & /@ Range[-1, -25, -1];
DownValues[g]

{HoldPattern[g[1]] :> -25}

DownValues[f] = HoldPattern[f[a_]] :> # & /@ Range[-1, -25, -1];
DownValues[f]

{HoldPattern[f[a_]] :> -1, HoldPattern[f[a_]] :> -2, 
 HoldPattern[f[a_]] :> -3, HoldPattern[f[a_]] :> -4, 
 HoldPattern[f[a_]] :> -5, HoldPattern[f[a_]] :> -6, 
 HoldPattern[f[a_]] :> -7, HoldPattern[f[a_]] :> -8, 
 HoldPattern[f[a_]] :> -9, HoldPattern[f[a_]] :> -10, 
 HoldPattern[f[a_]] :> -11, HoldPattern[f[a_]] :> -12, 
 HoldPattern[f[a_]] :> -13, HoldPattern[f[a_]] :> -14, 
 HoldPattern[f[a_]] :> -15, HoldPattern[f[a_]] :> -16, 
 HoldPattern[f[a_]] :> -17, HoldPattern[f[a_]] :> -18, 
 HoldPattern[f[a_]] :> -19, HoldPattern[f[a_]] :> -20, 
 HoldPattern[f[a_]] :> -21, HoldPattern[f[a_]] :> -22, 
 HoldPattern[f[a_]] :> -23, HoldPattern[f[a_]] :> -24, 
 HoldPattern[f[a_]] :> -25}
```

Even more than that, though, we can actually find oddities in the assignment procedure if we construct the appropriate pathological cases by manually manipulating the values.

Consider first the basic, expected behavior:

```
Clear[f]
f[a___] := 1
DownValues[f]

{HoldPattern[f[a___]] :> 1}

f[a_] := 1
DownValues[f]

{HoldPattern[f[a_]] :> 1, HoldPattern[f[a___]] :> 1}
```

The more specific pattern gets filtered up, as one would want. But we can change this:

```
DownValues[f] = RotateRight[DownValues[f], 1];
DownValues[f]

{HoldPattern[f[a___]] :> 1, HoldPattern[f[a_]] :> 1}
```

And then when we do future assignments no such simplification happens:

```
f[a___] := 2
DownValues[f]
f[1]

{HoldPattern[f[a___]] :> 2, HoldPattern[f[a_]] :> 1}

2
```

But now it thinks that final `DownValue` doesn't exist:

```
f[a_] := 1
DownValues[f]
f[1]

{HoldPattern[f[a_]] :> 1, HoldPattern[f[a___]] :> 2, 
 HoldPattern[f[a_]] :> 1}

1
```

But note sometime we still get simplification:

```
DownValues[f] =
  Join[
   DownValues[f],
   HoldPattern[f[1]] :> # & /@ Range[-1, -25, -1]
   ];
DownValues[f]

{HoldPattern[f[1]] :> -25, HoldPattern[f[a___]] :> 2, 
 HoldPattern[f[a_]] :> 1}
```

Although the simplification is not wholly what we'd expect.

This all suggests that the top-level `DownValues` expressions we see are not perfectly correlated to the internally maintained [`down codes`](https://tqft.net/other-papers/Mathematica%20Internals.pdf) or at the very least there's some opaque simplification mechanism.

One final case where this is crucially important is when using `` Internal`InheritedBlock `` on symbols with top-level `DownValues`. If you use the standard [Vilegas-Gayley](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/39711/understanding-villegas-gayley) override, sometimes your override fails.

For example, this fails to print, because there's already a general enough definition:

```
Internal`InheritedBlock[{
  System`GeoGraphicsDump`iGeoGraphics
  },
 Unprotect[System`GeoGraphicsDump`iGeoGraphics];
 System`GeoGraphicsDump`iGeoGraphics[e___] /; ! TrueQ[$override] :=

  Block[{$override = True},
   Print[Length@{e}];
   System`GeoGraphicsDump`iGeoGraphics[e]
   ];
 System`GeoGraphicsDump`iGeoGraphics[{RandomEntity["Country"][
    "Polygon"]}];
 ]
```

But using [`RotateRight`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RotateRight.html) on the `DownValues` works:

```
Internal`InheritedBlock[{
  System`GeoGraphicsDump`iGeoGraphics
  },
 Unprotect[System`GeoGraphicsDump`iGeoGraphics];
 System`GeoGraphicsDump`iGeoGraphics[e___] /; ! TrueQ[$override] :=

  Block[{$override = True},
   Print[Length@{e}];
   System`GeoGraphicsDump`iGeoGraphics[e]
   ];
 DownValues[System`GeoGraphicsDump`iGeoGraphics] = 
  RotateRight[DownValues@System`GeoGraphicsDump`iGeoGraphics];
 System`GeoGraphicsDump`iGeoGraphics[{RandomEntity["Country"][
    "Polygon"]}];
 ]

1
```

But beware *sometimes this fails*. I can't remember what my exact failure conditions have been (something like overriding some part of [`NotebookOpen`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NotebookOpen.html) or something), but I can remember the `RotateRight` trick not working.

Long story short, any assignment to any of the `*Values` is fragile, since simplifications and rearrangements happen opaquely.

Answer (score 6):

Perhaps you could do something like:

```
DownValues[d1] = DownValues[a1] /. a1 -> d1;
d1[x_] := Replace[a1[x], z_a1 :> b1 @@ z]

DownValues[d2] = DownValues[a2] /. a2 -> d2;
d2[x_] := Replace[a2[x], z_a2 :> b2 @@ z]
```

Then:

```
d1 /@ Range[5] === c1 /@ Range[5]

d2 /@ Range[10]
c2 /@ Range[10]
```

> True
>
> {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10}
>
> {2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18, 20}

Paradoxically, `d2` is faster than `c2`:

```
data = RandomInteger[{1, 10}, 10^6];
r1 = d2 /@ data; //AbsoluteTiming
r2 = c2 /@ data; //AbsoluteTiming

2 r1 === r2
```

> {0.535748, Null}
>
> {0.63291, Null}
>
> True

**Update**

Another possibility is to just run the new [`DownValues`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DownValues) again. For example:

```
DownValues[d2] = DownValues[a2] /. a2 -> d2;
Replace[
    DownValues[b2] /. b2 -> d3,
    _[_[lhs_], rhs_] :> SetDelayed[lhs,rhs],
    {1}
];

d2 /@ Range[10]
```

> {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10}

This way you should never get duplicate downvalues.

Comment: You could even be a little bit more secure in the new dvs using a `Verbatim` and `HoldPattern`. By the way I think the OP wanted to make sure the list comes in the original definition order (`a2` then `b2`), so maybe you want to run the `a2` dvs after the `b2` dvs.