# Find elements of a list matching specific patterns

Tags: list-manipulation, pattern-matching

I have defined several symbolic function `f[x],g[x,y],h[x,y,z]` etc... And I have a list made of elements which are product of these functions with different arguments; for example,

```
list = { f[a]f[-a], f[a]g[c,d]h[-a,-c,-d],  f[c]f[-c] ,
       f[d]g[a,y]h[-d,-a,-y] , f[b]f[-a] , f[-c]f[c] ,
       f[d]g[a,y]h[-d,-a,-z] }
```

Actually, these functions are just symbolic. They do not return any value.  You can think the functions' arguments as tensorial indexes.

I want to find an efficient function `checkPattern[list_]` which does the following

1) Take the first element `f[a]f[-a]` and find if there are others elements matching this pattern; so, for example, the third element of `list` is "equal" to the first one, in the sense that `f[a]f[-a]~f[c]f[-c]~f[-c]f[c]` irrespectively of the arguments. Note that the elements `f[a]f[-a]` and `f[b]f[-a]` are different.

2) Take the second element (which is more complicated) and does the same check as the step 1.

So the result would be

```
checkPattern[list]
(* {{1,3,6},{2,4},{5},{7}}*)
```

Comment: Why not represent your products using TensorProduct/TensorContract? For example, both `f[-c]f[c]` and `f[a] f[-a]` could be `TensorContract[TensorProduct[f, f], {{1,2}}]` and `f[a]g[c,d][h[-a,-c,-d]` could be `TensorContract[TensorProduct[f,g,h], {{1, 4}, {2,5}, {3, 6}}]`. This eliminates the use of dummy indices.

Comment: I know the TensorProduct function; but this would not allow me to do symbolic computation

Comment: Why would `TensorProduct` prevent you from doing symbolic computations?

Answer (score 3):

Here is your list:

```
list = {f[a] f[-a], f[a] g[c, d] h[-a, -c, -d], f[c] f[-c], 
   f[d] g[a, y] h[-d, -a, -y], f[b] f[-a], f[-c] f[c], 
   f[d] g[a, y] h[-d, -a, -z]};
```

Borrowing from [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/7904/38178), we can find a list of all distinct patterns as follows:

```
patterns = Quiet[
   SortBy[
    DeleteDuplicates[
     list /. 
      p : Alternatives[a | b | c | d | x | y | z] :> 
       Pattern[p, Blank[]],
     Internal`ComparePatterns[##] == "Identical" &
     ],
    MemberQ[{"Identical" , "Specific"}, Internal`ComparePatterns[##]] &]
   ];
```

Observe that I had to specify which symbols may be used as "indices".

A first approximation to the ultimate result could be

```
allpos = Map[Flatten@Position[list, #] &, patterns]
```

> {{1, 3, 6}, {1, 3, 5, 6}, {2, 4}, {2, 4, 7}}

This can be cleaned up by utilizing that `patterns` is already ordered:

```
Table[Complement[allpos[[i]], Union @@ allpos[[1 ;; i - 1]]], {i, 1, Length[allpos]}]
```

> {{1, 3, 6}, {5}, {2, 4}, {7}}

Comment: Thank you. I did not understand the last passage, when you clean `allpos`. Is this operation valid for any type of list like `list` or it is specific for the example I gave?

Comment: The cleaning just removes duplicated from `allpos` while preserving the _first_ occurence (since `patterns` is ordered by "specificallity", the first occurence belongs to the most specific pattern). It is meant to work with all input lists `list` for which `patterns` can be set up correctly. I haven't performed any further tests, though.

Comment: Ok thanks. I'll do some tests and let you know :)