# Lint checker for overlapping or conflicting function signature patterns

Tags: argument-patterns

In building a system like [Mathics](https://mathics.org) (or anything having the number of builtin functions of Mathematica) there are lots of function definitions. I would like to sanity check or lint check the pattern in the function signatures to look for obvious mistakes.

I realize solving the general problem is intractable if maybe even uncomputable/undecidable. So I am just looking for common mistakes of the kind that are likely to be made.

One kind of mistake is if the same rule is given twice:

```
F[x_] = 1
F[y_] = 10
```

Assume that the above assignments are available in a List of some sort. Or suppose instead of using `Set` directly, it is is done indirectly in a magical `SetIfNoConflict` function. Here, this would look like:

```
SetIfNoConflict[F, x_, 1]
SetIfNoConflict[F, y_, 10]
```

For the above, I would expect a warning that these two rules match the same thing.

Consider another kind of situation:

```
F[x_Integer] = 10
F[x_] = "x"
```

This is okay (in Mathics) because the first rule is more specific than the second one. If the rules were switched around though, this could be a problem because pattern matching for function application in Mathics would try the more generic rule and matches that before considering a match of the more specific rule. So here a warning might be about how the more specific rule will never get matched.

The problem is a bit open-ended so it will probably require some imagination to decide what is feasible. The above is to give an idea of the kinds of common mistakes that a function signature checker might find when scanning a sequence of definitions as you might find in a package or module.

As suggested in the comments by @CarlWoll `` Internal`ComparePatterns `` seems useful. Anyone know how that is implemented or could be extended for function signatures?

Comment: Your question is very unclear.  Each time you write a definition, it over writes and supplants the previous one.  So what exactly is your question?

Comment: Instead of say passing this to the interpreter directly, suppose you take the definition and check if first against all existing definitions.

Comment: Define "this."  Define "check."  Define "all."

Comment: Might investigate ``Internal`ComparePatterns``

Comment: Interesting. https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/2918/how-to-generally-match-unify-and-merge-patterns/7904#7904  seems to be for more general types of patterns not specific to functions.

Comment: We anticipate an talk at the upcoming [Wolfram Technology Conference](https://www.wolfram.com/events/technology-conference/2021/) that will describe use of a linter-like tool among other things. This will be presented by an in-house speaker.