# why combining 2 patterns in Alternatives in Cases do not give same output as when each pattern is used separately?

Tags: pattern-matching

Given expression

```
expr = y'[x]^3 + y'[x]*Log[y[x]*y'[x]^2] + y'[x]^(1/2) + x/y'[x]^7
```

$$y'(x)^3+\sqrt{y'(x)}+\frac{x}{y'(x)^7}+y'(x) \log \left(y(x) y'(x)^2\right)$$

The goal is pick all $y'(x)^n$ terms out anywhere they show.  So the final list should be

$$\left\{\frac{1}{y'(x)^7},\sqrt{y'(x)},y'(x)^2,y'(x),y'(x)^3\right\}$$

The following first pattern finds some subset of them, and the second pattern finds the rest.  But when used together using `Alternatives` not all pattern are found.

```
pat1 = _.*D[y[x], x]^n_.;
pat2 = _.*_[_. * D[y[x], x]^n_.];
Cases[expr, pat1 :> D[y[x], x]^n]
```

$$\left\{\frac{1}{y'(x)^7},\sqrt{y'(x)},y'(x),y'(x)^3\right\}$$

```
Cases[expr, pat2 :> D[y[x], x]^n]
```

$$\left\{y'(x)^2\right\}$$

So one would expect that using both in `Alternative` then the result will be combined. But it does not

```
Cases[expr, (pat1 | pat2) :> D[y[x], x]^n]
```

$$\left\{\frac{1}{y'(x)^7},\sqrt{y'(x)},y'(x)^2,y'(x)^3\right\}$$

You see, the $y'(x)$ does not show up.

Why is that?  Should not all the patterns matched when combining the two patterns using `|` be the union of each pattern applied separately?

V 12.3.1 on windows 10

Comment: `DeleteDuplicates@Cases[expr, (pat1 | pat2) :> D[y[x], x]^n, 2]`?

Comment: @kglr  But each pattern works on its own, so one would expect using `|` not to have any effect on this. But it seems then `|` if I understand you, tries one level only (1), compared when there is only one pattern, which will try different levels then? Ok, I think I understand the issue if this is what it is.

Comment: or use just `pat1` with level spec 3:  `DeleteDuplicates@Cases[expr, pat1 :> D[y[x], x]^n, 3]`

Comment: @kglr  sure, I could ofcourse do `DeleteDuplicates@Cases[expr, pat1 :> D[y[x], x]^n, Infinity]`  also. My main question was I thought using `|` will just combine both results. I guess I did not know it will make difference. If you like to make this an answer, will accept it.

Comment: You could use a default value: `pat = y'[x]^(n_ : 0) ;
Cases[expr, pat, -1] // DeleteDuplicates`

Comment: @DanielHuber sure. That is similar to what I wrote also (but your pattern is shorter which is better). But my main question is not to find workaround, but why when combining the patterns using `|`, it did not give the union of each result when done separately. I did not know it will work differently. But it does.

Comment: `Cases[expr, (pat1 | pat2) :> D[y[x], x]^n] ` and `Cases[expr, (pat2 | pat1) :> D[y[x], x]^n] `  give different results. (Use  `Trace` on both to see the source of the difference). (The difference might have to do with [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/7904/125))

Comment: Looks like a bug to me. Maybe you should report it to Wolfram.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The difference is due to the fact that the second term in `expr` matches both `pat1` and `pat2` (`pat1` matches the leaf `y'[x]` and `pat2` matches the leaf `Log[y[x] (y'[x]^2]`) and when `pat1|pat2` is used with default level specification (1) the first pattern returns `y'[x]`.

Using a simpler input expression:

```
expr2 = {y'[x]*Log[y[x]*y'[x]^2]}
```

> [image]

```
Cases[expr2, pat1 :> D[y[x], x]^n]
```

> [image: {Derivative[1][y][x]}]

```
Cases[expr2, pat2 :> D[y[x], x]^n]
```

> [image]

```
Cases[expr2, pat1 | pat2 :> D[y[x], x]^n]
```

> [image]

```
Cases[expr2, pat2 | pat1 :> D[y[x], x]^n]
```

> [image]

```
Trace[Cases[expr2, pat1 | pat2 :> D[y[x], x]^n]] // Column
```

[image]

```
Trace[Cases[expr2, pat2 | pat1 :> D[y[x], x]^n]] // Column
```

[image]

When we use the third argument to specify a deeper level, both orders give the same result:

```
Cases[expr2, pat1 | pat2 :> D[y[x], x]^n, Infinity] // DeleteDuplicates
```

> [image]

```
Cases[expr2, pat2 | pat1 :> D[y[x], x]^n, Infinity] // DeleteDuplicates
```

> [image]