# How to avoid nested With[]?

Tags: scoping

```
With[
  {v1 = #},
  With[
    {v2 = f[v1]},
    g[v1, v2]
  ]
]
```

How to avoid nested `With[]` like the above?  I'd like to use `v1` and `v2=f[v1]` in the module's body. Is using `Module[{v1, v2}, v2=f[v1]; g[v1, v2]]` the best/only way to avoid nested module?

Comment: In _Mathematica_ 10, you can do it with [Inactivate](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Inactivate.html), see [example here](http://www.wolfram.com/mathematica/new-in-10/inactive-objects/transform-code.html).

Comment: Strongly related: "[A version of `With` that binds variables sequentially](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/comp.soft-sys.math.mathematica/b6awrZ1dERw/kY6TEmhCKj0J)" and "[Iterative constants and variables definitions](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/comp.soft-sys.math.mathematica/T1GrizPbtok/h_CcKPa_wb0J)."

Answer (score 73, accepted):

I don't think one can avoid the need for nested `With` altogether - I find it a very common case to need declared variables use previously declared variables.

Since I once wrote the function (actually macro) that automates nesting `With`, and generates nested `With` at run-time, this is a good opportunity to (re)post it as an answer to an exact question that it actually addresses. I will partly borrow the discussion from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5866016/question-on-condition/5869885#5869885).

#### Implementation

***Edit Aug.3, 2015 - added `RuleDelayed` UpValue, per @Federico's suggestion***

Here is the code for it (with added local-variable highlighting):

```
ClearAll[LetL];
SetAttributes[LetL, HoldAll];
SyntaxInformation[LetL] = {
   "ArgumentsPattern" -> {_, _}, 
   "LocalVariables" -> {"Solve", {1, Infinity}}
};
LetL /: (assign : SetDelayed | RuleDelayed)[
  lhs_,rhs : HoldPattern[LetL[{__}, _]]
] := 
  Block[{With}, 
    Attributes[With] = {HoldAll}; 
    assign[lhs, Evaluate[rhs]]
  ];
LetL[{}, expr_] := expr;
LetL[{head_}, expr_] := With[{head}, expr];
LetL[{head_, tail__}, expr_] := 
  Block[{With}, Attributes[With] = {HoldAll};
    With[{head}, Evaluate[LetL[{tail}, expr]]]];
```

What it does is to first expand into a nested `With`, and only then allow the expanded construct to evaluate. It also has a special behavior when used on the r.h.s. of function definitions performed with `SetDelayed`.

I find this macro interesting for many reasons, in particular because it uses a number of interesting techniques together to achieve its goals (`UpValues`, `Block` trick, recursion, `Hold`-attributes and other tools of evaluation control, some interesting pattern-matching constructs).

#### Simple usage

First consider simple use cases such as this:

```
LetL[{a=1,b=a+1,c=a+b+2},{a,b,c}]
```

> ```
> {1,2,5}
> ```

We can trace the execution to see how `LetL` expands into nested `With`:

```
Trace[LetL[{a=1,b=a+1},{a,b}],_With]
```

> ```
> {{{{With[{b=a+1},{a,b}]},With[{a=1},With[{b=a+1},{a,b}]]},
>     With[{a=1},With[{b=a+1},{a,b}]]},
>     With[{a=1},With[{b=a+1},{a,b}]],With[{b$=1+1},{1,b$}]}
> ```

#### Definition-time expansion in function's definitions

When `LetL` is used to define a function (global rule) via `SetDelayed`, it expands not at run-time, but at definition-time, having overloaded `SetDelayed` via `UpValues`. This is essential to be able to have conditional global rules with variables shared between the body and the condition semantics. For a more detailed discussion of this issue see the linked above answer, here I will just provide an example:

```
Clear[ff];
ff[x_,y_]:= LetL[{xl=x,yl=y+xl+1},xl^2+yl^2/;(xl+yl<15)];
ff[x_,y_]:=x+y;
```

We can now check the definitions of `ff`:

```
?ff
```

> ```
> Global`ff
>  ff[x_,y_]:=With[{xl=x},With[{yl=y+xl+1},xl^2+yl^2/;xl+yl<15]]
>
> ff[x_,y_]:=x+y
> ```

Now, here is why it was important to expand at definition time: had `LetL` always expanded at run time, and the above two definitions would be considered the same by the system during definition time (variable-binding time), because the conditional form of `With` (also that of `Module` and `Block`) is hard-wired into the system; inside any other head, `Condition` has no special meaning to the system. The above-mentioned [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5866016/question-on-condition/5869885#5869885) shows what happens with a version of `Let` that expands at run time: the second definition simply replaces the first.

#### Remarks

I believe that `LetL` fully implements the semantics of nested `With`, including conditional rules using `With`. This is so simply because it always fully expands before execution, as if we wrote those nested `With` constructs by hand. In this sense, it is closer to true macros, as they are present in e.g. Lisp.

I have used `LetL` in a lot of my own applications and it never let me down. From my answers on SE, its most notable presence is in [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/36/file-backed-lists-variables-for-handling-large-data/209#209), where it is used a lot and those uses illustrate its utility well.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why did you call it "LetL" ?

Comment: @QuantumDot The `Let` part comes from an analogy with Lisp, where there is a similar function. The `L` stands for Leonid, because originally there was a mathgroup thread with different implementations, and I had to somehow differentiate mine from the others.

Comment: @QuantumDot I call it `WithAll`

Comment: Why wrap `Verbatim` around `SetDelayed`?

Comment: @bdforbes That's a good question. I don't see now, why it is there.  But I do recall that it was necessary at some stage. I did have several versions of this function, so presumably that was left from that older code. Unless I am overlooking some subtlety.

Comment: I can't find a situation where it changes the result. Based on my research, this type of usage of `Verbatim` is always to prevent evaluation of the head, e.g. as used here: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/2867/8612
In the present context, we wouldn't expect `SetDelayed` to evaluate in any scenario, is that correct?

Comment: Potentially, while you were developing the function, you were working on the pattern `Verbatim[SetDelayed][lhs_, rhs : HoldPattern[LetL[{__}, _]]]` on its own, and thus the `Verbatim` _was_ actually necessary to keep the expression as a pattern?

Comment: @bdforbes More precisely, `Verbatim` is used to escape the pattern-matcher. A typical use case would be e.g. `MatchQ[_Integer, Verbatim[_Integer]]` (gives `True`), where not using `Verbatim` would lead to `False`. If you want to prevent the evaluation of the pattern, you use `HoldPattern` (which sometimes is also used for escaping, where `Verbatim` should be used). In any case, I don't see now, why in this particular case `Verbatim` could've been useful.

Comment: I suggest the variant `LetL /: (assign : SetDelayed | RuleDelayed)[lhs_, rhs : HoldPattern[LetL[{__}, _]]] := Block[{With}, Attributes[With] = {HoldAll}; assign[lhs, Evaluate[rhs]]];`, so that one can also use it with `RuleDelayed` as in `Range[10] /. x_Integer :> LetL[{y = x}, -y /; y <= 5]`.

Comment: @Federico Thanks, good suggestion! Edited this in.

Comment: Is it possible to combine previously prepared lists with assignments with new variables, something like `newfun[$a_,$b_]:=LetL[{a=$a,b=$b}~Join~longHeldListOfSetDelayeds, rv]` and then compile newfun?

Comment: @ÅsmundHj Your question is not clear. I won't have the time to answer today anyway. You could ask on the main site as a separate question, to have more eyes on it.

Comment: I have asked in http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/109656/manual-common-subexpression-elimination-and-use-of-letl

Comment: One tutorial calls it [`IterateWith`](https://www.wolfram.com/mathematica/new-in-10/inactive-objects/transform-code.html), but their implementation with Inactivate is kinda broken, leaking some evaluations of heads: try `g = {1};IterateWith[{}, g[[1]] = 1]`

Comment: @masterxilo Yes, I am aware of that. My code also supports shared local variables in definitions, which that one doesn't.

Comment: I was just bitten by this implementation: Because the rest of WL is not aware of this new scoping construct, it doesn't behave perfectly: `With[{data = {a}}, With[{a = data}, data]]` and `With[{data = {a}}, LetL[{a = data}, data]]` give different results. I think I'll start using the extended `With` suggested below instead.

Comment: @masterxilo This is a problematic case indeed, and also something that no user-defined implementation can fight, because, as you noted, the outer scoping construct should be aware of the inner one to resolve the naming conflict right. That said, I would still think that this example is a pathology, rather than a typical use case. B.t.w., which extended `With` did you mean - the new extra built-in capabilities / syntax?

Comment: @LeonidShifrin big fan here (1) I'm using 13.1 in 2022. Is this still the best solution? (2) Why did you name it `LetL` and not just `Let'?

Comment: @JulesManson Not sure about best, but AFAIK there is still no built-in equivalent. `LetL` because IIRC `Let` was taken in the context where I first posted it.

Answer (score 51):

**Introduced in V10.4 or earlier, but after V10.1**

This functionality has snuck into `With` (ref: [Daniel's comment](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/109298/#comment296006_109298)).
Note the use of the braces.

```
With[{v1 = #}, {v2 = f[v1]}, g[v1, v2]]
(*  g[#1, f[#1]]  *)
```

The syntax coloring has not caught up yet:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

**In V10 --**

```
Needs["GeneralUtilities`"];
?GeneralUtilities`Where
```

> `Where[ass1, ass2, ..., expr]` is a version of With that supports multiple sequential assignments.

```
Needs["GeneralUtilities`"];
Where[v1 = #, v2 = f[v1], g[v1, v2]]

(* g[#1, f[#1]] *)

Where[x = 2, t = x^2, Hold[x + t]]

(* Hold[2 + 4] *)
```

Comment: This reminds me of a Q&A I've been meaning to post for years but I never get around to.  The basic code behind `Where` is one of the methods I was using.  Maybe I'll *finally* get around to that soon.   (+1 of course.)

Comment: I can't get `Where` to work in 10.4... am I alone?

Comment: @Mehrdad Likewise; see my answer for the old definition.

Comment: The undocumented With construct seems to be the way to go, so this should be the accepted answer IMO. It is the only variant that behaves correctly like nested ``With``s in the following case where `LetL` and `Where` fail: ``ClearAll@a;
{With[{data = {a}}, With[{a = data}, With[{b = a}, {data, b}]]],With[{data = {a}},With[{a = data}, {b = a}, {data, b}]](*same result, more concise*),
 With[{data = {a}}, 
  LetL[{a = data, b = a}, {data, b}]](*different result!*),
 Needs["GeneralUtilities`"];
 With[{data = {a}}, 
  Where[a = data, b = a, {data, b}]](*crashes because of recursion*)
 }``.

Comment: It looks like `Where` is more like Block since it can fail from recursions.

Comment: Nevermind about Where, it just isn't here anymore in 10.4, hence the recursion crash.

Comment: @masterxilo Yes, the `Where` functionality was incorporated into `With` and removed in V10.4, although it's still undocumented.

Comment: @MichaelE2 Did you mean **In V10.4 or *later***?  This syntax does not work in 10.1 for example.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I suppose I meant the `With` syntax worked in V10.4 and may have worked in V10.3, and maybe in V10.2, too.  I probably couldn't check versions before V10.4.  Daniel's comment was that it was introduced in "V10.*something*".  No one has come along and verified which version was the version in which it was first implemented.

Comment: Is there a way to fix the syntax highlights for `With` in v12? I tried `SyntaxInformation[With] = ...` after `Unprotect`, but it didn't work.

Comment: @JEM_Mosig This is mentioned in [Daniel's comment](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/109298/#comment296006_109298) and it's still not fixed. I don't know of a fix nor why you can't fix it with `SyntaxInformation`.

Answer (score 30):

`With` works by performing a substitution operation prior to executing its body, and likely it is only a single pass. So, inter-referencing the variables is not possible. Since `With` accepts the use of `SetDelayed` (`:=`), you might think that that could be used, instead. For example,

```
With[{v1 = #, v2 := f[v1]}, g[v1, v2]]& @ p
(* g[p, f[v1]] *)
```

which reveals the other use of `With`: localization. The `v1` in `f[v1]` is not the same as the `v1` used by `With`, so that method is out, also. The same problem exists for `Module` as it uses a similar form of localization.

However, `Block` works

```
Block[{v1 = #, v2 = f[v1]}, g[v1, v2]]& @ p
(* g[p, f[p]] *)
```

even though the syntax highlighting makes it appear that the `v1` inside `f` is not localized. But, `Block` has the attribute `HoldAll`, so `v2 = f[v1]` is not executed until `v1` has taken on its local definition, and, unlike in `With` and `Module`, it is not internally treated with `Unique[v1]`.

Comment: With the potential effects of these different attributes on the program unknown, I think I'd better just use `Module[{v1, v2}, v2=f[v1]; g[v1, v2]]`. Thanks!

Comment: +1 for some good points. However, my comment here is that `Block` solves an entirely different problem. `With` is unique in that it creates referentially-transparent code (no assignments to its "variables" in the body of `With` is possible), while `Block` allows the body to arbitrarily modify the variables it localizes.  Another big difference: (nested) `With` can inject into held expressions, something `Block` or `Module` can not.  So, I don't really view a replacement of (nested) `With` with `Block` or `Module` as a generally valid solution to the posed problem.

Comment: @LeonidShifrin absolutely. `With` because of its method of operation does things `Block` cannot do, and vice versa. But, the self-referential part, I thought, was essential to the problem. As long as the other parts of the operation of `With` are not needed, then `Block` should be a viable alternative. However, it is not a direct replacement.

Comment: @rcollyer Well, as long as the solution removes some defining properties of `With`, I would not consider it a general solution for `With` specifically. I would agree with you more (in that self-referential part is the main issue) if this was a question of nested `Block` or `Module`.

Comment: @LeonidShifrin except that it is well known that you can do `Scope[{x,y}, x = f[y]]` with either `Module` or `Block`, so I don't think that question would come up. Personally, I think the mutability of the variables in `Block` is the biggest issue with using as a replacement for `With`. The ability to use `With` to inject code into held expressions is less well known. But, for the OPs problem, it was the perfect fit, provided of course the representative example doesn't stray to far from the actual code. :)

Comment: @rcollyer I am a bit confused. If it's the case that `With`'s ability to inject values into held expressions isn't that widely known, what do most people use `With` for? Or is it the case that they simply don't use it at all? (IMO, `With` should be used with some circumspection, because it can potentially copy each expression many times. So, it is a rather specialized tool, not meant to be used as an ordinary scoping construct.)

Comment: @OleksandrR. I use `With` primarily to provide temporary named variables, usually in the case of nested pure functions, like `With[{f = #}, {#, f[#]}& /@ Range[5]]& @ {x, y, z}`, or similar. I avoid held expressions, if I can help it.

Comment: @OleksandrR. I actually use `With` the most in my code, much more often than `Module` or `Block`. Copying does not seem an issue, because I guess `With` does not perform a deep copy, since expression does not change.

Comment: @Leonid you are right--an experiment shows that `With` is actually much more conservative about copying than I had thought. Even though I use `With` a lot already, it looks like I've been avoiding it needlessly in some cases. Thanks!

Comment: @OleksandrR. Well, good to have another confirmation - I never did specialized tests. I like `With` (and particularly nested `With` or my `LetL`) because they allow to avoid side-effects and they clearly state so from the outset. I am trying to write my code in such a way that one can see at a glance whether or not the body of a given function contains any side effects. I generally try to avoid them.

Comment: @Leonid I also prefer the side-effect-free style. What I did not expect, though, is that given e.g. `data = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, 10^8]; f[tmp2_] := Total[tmp2 + tmp2 + tmp2]; g[data_] := With[{tmp2 = data}, Total[tmp2 + tmp2 + tmp2]]; h[data_] := With[{tmp1 = data}, With[{tmp2 = tmp1}, Total[tmp2 + tmp2 + tmp2]]];`, the memory consumption of `f[data]`, `g[data]`, and `h[data]` is identical. No unnecessary copies occur no matter how deeply `With` is nested. `LetL` looks even better in this light: not only clear and robust, but also highly efficient.

Comment: @OleksandrR. As to memory consumption, it seems that this is deeper than just `With`-related. Szabolcs gave a [nice answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8324571/does-passing-a-variable-with-a-large-amount-of-data-cost-a-lot-of-memory-and-tim/8324804#8324804), and I added a few further observations in comments to it. Whereas for `LetL`, it should be almost as fast as nested `With` entered directly, and also it disappears in function's definitions, since there it expands at definition-time (as a true self-respecting macro should). Glad that you liked it. I use it in my code all the time.

Comment: @Leonid I'm not sure that the internal structure is a directed *acyclic* graph as ``Internal`Bag``s can be self-referential--either bags are just one possible way of building an expression, or a DAG only gets built later on, either during parsing or as part of the evaluation process (so that the evaluator can know when to stop). In any case, I agree that this is a nice answer, and maybe I've been too pessimistic about `With`, given that it obviously behaves no less well in this respect than any other familiar function.

Comment: @OleksandrR. An interesting point about the `Bag`s, I wasn't aware of that. Still, I tend to think that they are an exception. They are probably as close to the lower-level references as one is allowed to get in Mathematica. My understanding is that the general absence of circular references is an essential feature of mma, which allows it to use a simpler reference - counting scheme in the garbage collector.

Answer (score 14):

Perhaps this will work:

```
SetAttributes[BetterWith, HoldAll]
BetterWith[{x_}, expr_] := With[{x}, expr];
BetterWith[{x_, rest__}, expr_] := BetterWith[{x}, BetterWith[{rest}, expr]]
BetterWith[{s:Verbatim[Set][x_List, y_], rest___}, expr_] := Quiet @ With[
        {x2 = Replace[Hold[x], z_Symbol :> Pattern[z, _], {2}]},
            Replace[y, {Apply[HoldPattern,x2] :> BetterWith[{rest}, expr], _ -> $Failed}]
] 

BetterWith[{y=x+1,x=1},y]     
(* gives 2 *)
```

Comment: Just hide the nested `With[]` under hood of a new symbol?

Comment: @MaThEmAtika Exactly.

Answer (score 8):

**As of 10.4**

`Where` appears to no longer reside in `"GeneralUtilities'"` however I quite like its form so here is the <= 10.3 `Definition` (v. similar to M.R.'s answer) that can be placed in an `init.m` file.

```
SetAttributes[Where, HoldAll];

Where[s : Verbatim[Set][x_List, y_], rest___, expr_] := 
With[{x2 = Quiet[Replace[Hold[x], z_Symbol :> z_, {2}]]}, 
Replace[y, {HoldPattern @@ x2 :> Where[rest, expr], _ -> $Failed}]]

Where[expr_] := expr

Where[x_List, expr_] := With[x, expr]

Where[x_, expr_] := With[{x}, expr]

Where[x_, rest__, expr_] := Where[x, Where[rest, expr]]
```

Note that this slightly improves the previous `"GeneralUtilities'"` definition by giving effect to a "multiple set" presumably originally intended by the first  `Where[s:Verbatim[Set] ...` definition:

```
Where[
      {x, y} = {1, 3 + x},
       z = 2,
      {x, y, z}] 

(* {1, 3 + x, 2} *)
```

whereas

**In 10.3.1**

```
Needs["GeneralUtilities`"];

Where[
      {x, y} = {1, 3 + x},
       z = 2,
      {x, y, z}]

(* 
 With::lvset: Local variable specification {{x,y}={1,3+x}} contains {x,y}={1,3+x}, which is an assignment to {x,y}; only assignments to symbols are allowed. >>

 With[{{x, y} = {1, 3 + x}}, Where[z = 2, {x, y, z}]]

*)
```

**Update** - turns out `Where` can (if rarely) let a few bullets through; To collate:

First, some compression helping:

```
SetAttributes[CompressCode,HoldAll];
CompressCode[code_] := Compress@Hold@code;
UncompressCode[compressed_] := ReleaseHold@Uncompress@compressed;
UncompressCode[compressed_List] := Scan[UncompressCode, compressed];
```

i.e. with the compressed strings coming from `CompressCode[(* defs *)]` with `defs` being substituted by the code that defines `Where`, [`LetL`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/10451/2249) and [`Let`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/64944/2249) (the latter two due to Leonid)

```
WhereDef = "1:eJytVNtOhDAQZUFdo9kH/QMTv8A/wFt8MEZ3E/e5SMk2Foq0TcCvt9NSunRhZY0vE2jPnDlnOu1VwpbZLAgCfqTCE6NpNoe/SxXuWF4yWaQPdVlhzgkrshD2FiqssIiFqEgihdo6VivrDVaoecsSU2rAZwZ8jylqcJpFsNbBDQRyXpEQuCq4lqKXjapTFd5xlSBBch4ZruGs2iQA9y1Fxac29Ez4CLzJgh58FwX5ypEwwAsLfJGUrvCXxMXHgH5Iwqpfg+ywuSZi4xru9LXeOPzUN87LmyTKcWTrLHFJkSrcO7LWv+Y5B5Ck2DZ80Py336sTqN7kCaNjCZ6fngOizyv0NLZtDne9DmoE7rgsaaO3wZYV0LakQ5lJs8fjWt5VAm5PsBZ2/YgItfW8wZwF+wdz5GC96h5p+AvpgXM7abgM6X/omnJBDpz1KeKmPBHTxLnbu7DAP95cN3ZbV23PLOoPeCl+APfNJQs=";

LetLDef = "1: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";

LetDef = "1: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";
```

and now some defining:

```
UncompressCode@{WhereDef, LetLDef, LetDef}
```

we get the following syntactic variants  (ordered by rough chronology) that all do the same thing:

```
With[{x = 1}, With[{y = x}, {x, y}]]
LetL[{x = 1, y = x}, {x, y}]
Where[x = 1, y = x, {x, y}]
Let[x = 1, y = x, {x, y}]
With[{x = 1}, {y = x}, {x, y}]

(* {1,1}  *)

(* For all of the above*)
```

`Where` and `Let` also permit threaded List Assignments

```
Where[{x, y} = {1, 1}, {x, y}]
Let[{x, y} = {1, 1}, {x, y}]

(* {1,1}  *)

(* For both*)
```

while noting users' potential scoping oversights

```
Where[{x, y} = {1, x}, {x, y}]
Let[{x, y} = {1, x}, {x, y}]

(* {1,x}  *)

(* For both*)
```

(but which I suspect differ in more involved scenarios that suggest `Let` is more robust)

I think it is important to have a succinct, natural, robust and efficient version of this scoping construct given its ubiquity.  My vote would be for `Let` based on how it satisfies the first two qualities while seeming to do likewise for the latter two.

Answer (score 5):

Let's create nested `With` with [knowledge about `RawBoxes`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/83129/5478). I'd not use this method in this case, due to the performance but it is a good exercise:

```
SetAttributes[myWith, HoldAll];

myWith[{spec___}, body_] := ToExpression @@ Fold[
  RawBoxes @ MakeBoxes[With[{#2}, #]] &, 
  RawBoxes @ MakeBoxes @ body, 
  RawBoxes /@ MakeBoxes /@ Unevaluated[{spec}] // Reverse
]
```

It is handy to nest with `RawBoxes` but we have to get rid of the very outer `RawBoxes` at the end. Notice that I'm doing this with `ToExpression @@` which also make expression from what is left:

```
a = b = 4;
myWith[{a = 1, b = a + 1}, {a + b, Hold[a, b]}]
a
b
```

> ```
> {3, Hold[1, 2]}
> 4
> 4
> ```