# What's the best practice for nested local constants?

Tags: variable-definitions, scoping

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to avoid nested With[]?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/10432/how-to-avoid-nested-with)

I have many situations where I have a constant that is local to a function, with other constants that are computed from it. I see that I can implement this using nested `With` statements, like

```
leapSeconds = With[{
   usnoData = 
    Import["http://maia.usno.navy.mil/ser7/tai-utc.dat", "Text", 
     CharacterEncoding -> "UTF8"]},
  With[{
    lineLength = StringPosition[usnoData, "\n"][[1, 1]],
    lsCount = Length[StringCases[usnoData, "\n"]] + 1},
   DateList[#] & /@ (StringTake[
        usnoData, {2 + #*lineLength, 9 + #*lineLength}] & /@ 
      Range[0, lsCount - 1])]]
```

but this seems cumbersome. Is there a better way to do this sort of thing (I know that for this example I could dispense with the constants, but assume for the exercise that I do indeed need the constants)? Is nesting `With` statments a reasonable approach, or something I've just come up with by not understanding *Mathematica* very well?

Comment: Yes, duplicate question. Though the answers there don't really address the point.

Comment: Then I don't see what the question is. My answer is this: yes, this situation is very common in practice, and then I use `LetL`, described in my answer to that question. The only other option is to separate every single constant's computation into a separate function, and then chain those functions, but often this may not be desirable, both because of extra boilerplate of parameter-passing, and because those new functions may not be general enough to justify their existence.

Comment: Yes, sorry, I wasn't clear: closing is fine.

Comment: I think this could probably be reformulated in a way which would emphasize that you are looking for alternative solutions. If that's so, it does not have to be closed.

Comment: @LeonidShifrin: Actually, it's more the opposite: I'm interested in whether this is what the community commonly does in this such situations.

Comment: I would say yes, although this is based on my personal perception and may be not entirely correct.

Comment: @LeonidShifrin: Well. I'd accept that (from an experienced user) as a valid answer to this question. (The other question seems more focused on some alternatives.)