# Why can't I change the value of MaxRecursion in NIntegrate when integrating BesselJ?

Tags: numerical-integration, numerics, bugs, special-functions

**Bug introduced in 8.0.4 or earlier and persisting through 11.0.1 or later**

---

I am trying to evaluate this integral numerically
$$
\int_0^{\infty } J_0(q R)  \tanh(q) \, \mathrm{d}q
$$
for large values of $R$. This makes the integrand oscillate more quickly and *Mathematica* gives incorrect answers. To deal with this I am trying to increase `MaxRecursion` in `NIntegrate`. Simply coding

```
 With[{R = 50},  
      NIntegrate[BesselJ[0, q R ] Tanh[q], {q, 0, ∞}, 
                 AccuracyGoal -> 12, PrecisionGoal -> 4, 
                 MaxRecursion -> 100]
 ]
```

throws no errors but it also does not increase computation time or give the correct answer.

If I set `MinRecursion` to a large value (larger than 9 - the default value in `NIntegrate`) in an attempt, I see an increase in computation time

```
 With[{R = 50},  
      NIntegrate[BesselJ[0, q R ] Tanh[q], {q, 0, ∞}, 
                 AccuracyGoal -> 12, PrecisionGoal -> 4,
                 MinRecursion -> 20, MaxRecursion -> 100]
 ]
```

I get an error saying

> NIntegrate::minmax: MinRecursion (20) is greater than MaxRecursion (9).

I find this very confusing as I implicitly set the value of `MaxRecursion` in the code and it is not 9. *Mathematica* will allow my Min and Max Recursion if I delete the Bessel function and just have the `Tanh` in `NIntegrate`. My only thought is that this is some built-in property of `BesselJ`. *Mathematica* will also evaluate the `BesselJ` to arbitrary precision so I see no reason to limit the number of numerical subdivisions. Does anyone know a workaround?

P.S. Here is a some code which will quickly produce a plot of the integral as a function of $R$

```
 f[R_?NumericQ] := NIntegrate [BesselJ[0, q R ] Tanh[q], {q, 0, ∞}]

 LogLogPlot[
    f[R], {R, 1, 250}, PlotPoints -> 10, 
    MaxRecursion -> 1, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}]
```

The code works up until $R$ is about 15 then gibberish for anything larger.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE, and thank you for formatting the question for readability!  Please do not add the [bugs] tag to new questions.  It'll be added later if the consensus of the community is that this is indeed a bug.

Comment: I don't know what's happening here, but [this page](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/NIntegrateOverview.html) may be useful for you (if you're not yet aware of it).  It details the various method options.

Comment: Depending on your accuracy needs, approximate $\tanh(z)\approx 1$ for $z$ sufficiently large, such as $z\gg 20$. This works because $1 - \tanh(z)$ decays exponentially. The integral of $J_0$ can be evaluated in closed form, so numerical integration is needed only for the product of the Bessel function with $\tanh(z)-1$ from $0$ to this small threshold.

Comment: @whuber - Thanks. I have thought of this and for this $\tanh$ integral that approach works. I used $\tanh$ in my integral as it easily showcased the problem and I know the answer. My real interest, however, is the asymptotic behavior (in large $R$) for a Hankel transform of a much more complicated function than $\tanh$. My function has similar properties to $\tanh$ but it doesn't submit to that approximation. I have derived an asymptotic form of my Hankel transform but I can't check it because of poor numerics. I would like to get to the bottom of this BesselJ problem and see if that helps.

Comment: At least for your simpler problem, `"ExtrapolatingOscillatory"` (Longman's method) and `"DoubleExponentialOscillatory"` (Ooura-Mori method) both work well.

Comment: @szabolcs Let's start building community consensus about whether or not this is a bug. I'd say the error message itself is clearly erroneously (and I can reproduce it in both v8 and v9). What do you say?

Comment: @Sjoerd, added the tag.

Comment: I filed the issue that `Max-` and `MinRecusion` can not be set  simultaneously as a bug. For the issue at hand (oscillatory integrand) you may want to try the "LevinRule". `With[{R = 50}, 
     NIntegrate[BesselJ[0, q R] Tanh[q], {q, 0, \[Infinity]}, 
      AccuracyGoal -> 12, PrecisionGoal -> 4, Method -> "LevinRule"]]
    (*-1.72182*10^-15*)`. Another approach could be to increase the `WorkingPrecision`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As has been noted by ruebenko in the comments, there does seem to be a bug in the handling of infinite-range Bessel function integrals when `MinRecursion` and `MaxRecursion` are both set to non-default values. For instance, even the simple

```
NIntegrate[BesselJ[0, x], {x, 0, ∞}, MinRecursion -> 10, MaxRecursion -> 15]
```

chokes with a `NIntegrate::minmax` error.

In any event, for the slightly more complicated

$$\int_0^\infty J_0(50u)\tanh\,u\,\mathrm du$$

what you can do is to explicitly use a method for infinite-range oscillatory integrals, and crank up `WorkingPrecision` while you're at it. For example, using Longman's method:

```
NIntegrate[BesselJ[0, 50 q] Tanh[q], {q, 0, ∞},
           Method -> "ExtrapolatingOscillatory", WorkingPrecision -> 90]
   2.1950746252821515546830074912679107125599945310570775933×10⁻³⁵
```

Hmm, a bit tiny. Is it actually zero? Let's check with something slightly different.

Let's take whuber's splitting suggestion. Using the identity

$$\tanh\,u=1-\exp(-u)\;\mathrm{sech}\,u$$

and exploiting the Hankel transform identity

$$\int_0^\infty J_0(cu)\,\mathrm du=\frac1{c},\quad c>0$$

we start by integrating the integral with $\mathrm{sech}$, using again Longman's method:

```
NIntegrate[BesselJ[0, 50 q] Exp[-q] Sech[q], {q, 0, ∞},
           Method -> "ExtrapolatingOscillatory", WorkingPrecision -> 90]
   0.01999999999999999999999999999999997804925374717848445316992508732089287121184172744576
```

which can be seen to be quite close to $1/50$. Subtracting this quantity from $0.02$, yields a result that agrees with the earlier attempt, so we now have a bit more trust in the results.

I had used Longman's method in these examples, but one could also have chosen to use the methods of Ooura-Mori (`"DoubleExponentialOscillatory"`) or Levin ("`LevinRule`") instead.

Answer (score 0):

Today I believe I encountered the same problem when trying to reproduce the result of [this paper](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2Fs004660050441) about Lamb's problem and solutions mentioned above doesn't help in my specific case. After struggling for a while I managed to find a work-around and I think it's worth sharing.

**In short**, if the integrate contains singular point(s) in addition, you may need to set higher `WorkingPrecision` and `MaxRecursion`, exclude the singular point(s) with `Exclusions` and explicitly set `Method` to `"ExtrapolatingOscillatory"`. (Yeah, not one less.)

The following is the corresponding integral:

```
Clear[p, ξ, Nz, uztran]

(* the following is equation (16b) together with (11) etc. in the paper *)
Nz[p_] = With[{ν = 1/4, ρ = 7800, Ε = 210 10^9, r = 1, z = 0}, 
  With[{λ = (Ε ν)/((1 + ν) (1 - 2 ν)), μ = Ε/(2 (1 + ν))}, 
   With[{c = Piecewise[{{Sqrt[(λ + 2 μ)/ρ], # == 1}, {Sqrt[μ/ρ], # == 2}}] &}, 
    With[{k = p/c[#] &}, 
     With[{a = Sqrt[ξ^2 + k[#]^2]/k[2] &}, 
      With[{R = (2 ξ^2 + k[2]^2)^2 - 4 k[2]^2 a[1] a[2] ξ^2}, 
       (-(2 ξ^2 + k[2]^2) Exp[k[2] a[1] z] + 2 ξ^2 Exp[-k[2] a[2] z]) 
        (ξ k[2] a[1] BesselJ[0, ξ r])/R]]]]]];

(* the following is equation (15b) in the paper *)
uztran[p_, opt : OptionsPattern[]] := 
 (F gtran)/(2 π μ) NIntegrate[Rationalize[Nz[p], 0], {ξ, 0, ∞}, opt]

(* parameter that'll cause trouble, found by trial and error *)
specialp = 1.50026105063867726694999966600905294434039033506`12.86057158578721*^-10 - 
   1.67718225969505448435499738721675509494445398372`12.90898501143577*^-10 I;

uztran[specialp, 
  WorkingPrecision -> 64, 
  MaxRecursion -> 40, 
  Method -> "ExtrapolatingOscillatory", 
  Exclusions -> Denominator@Nz@specialp == 0] // AbsoluteTiming
```

> ```
> {6.372237, 
>   -(1/μ)(0.1193662073189147296405743133616902778179 + 
>      7.5708093349255506613916610*10^-15 I) F gtran}
> ```

You can try modifying those 4 options to see what will happen.

P.S. It's worth emphasizing the necessity of `Method -> "ExtrapolatingOscillatory"` is actually another **bug** (this has been conformed by WRI): when you add `Exclusions` option to this integral, `NIntegrate` will spit out `NIntegrate::bdmtd` and `NIntegrate::nsr` without `"ExtrapolatingOscillatory"`, at the moment it's the only work-around I found for this bug.

Comment: I dunno... the integrand seems to be qualitatively different enough to warrant a separate thread about this, rather than have it as this answer.

Comment: @J.M. I did hesitate for a while but finally decided to post this answer. Anyway this integral contains `BesselJ` and if you tried something like `uztran[specialp, WorkingPrecision -> 64, MinRecursion -> 20, MaxRecursion -> 40]` you'll see the same warning as that mentioned in the question.

Comment: So many `With[]` constructions. Is it a good habit to use this?

Comment: @ShutaoTANG Mainly because I'm still in v9 and want to make the post self-contained so not that willing to use `LetL` etc. in this sample. You can have a look at this post: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/54874/1871