# Why does the integral not converge?

Tags: equation-solving, calculus-and-analysis, numerical-integration, special-functions, physics

I am trying to solve for $\Omega$ this nonlinear integral equation:

$$1+\dfrac{z}{k^2}-\dfrac{z^2}{K_2(z)} \dfrac{\Omega}{k^3} \displaystyle\int_{1}^{\infty} \gamma^2\, \text{ArcTanh}  \left(\sqrt{\frac{\gamma ^2-1}{\gamma ^2}} \dfrac{k}{\Omega}\right)\, e^{-\text{z$\gamma $}} \, d\gamma=0$$

where $K_2(z)$ is the modified Bessel function of the second kind, $\Omega$ and $k$ are reals, $z> 0$.

The Mathematica input is:

```
f[Ω_?NumericQ, k_?NumericQ, z_?NumericQ] := 1 + (z/k^2) - (z^2/BesselK[2, z]) (Ω/k^3) 
    NIntegrate[γ^2 (ArcTanh[Sqrt[(γ^2 - 1)/γ^2] (k/Ω)]) Exp[-z γ], {γ, 1, Infinity}, 
    MaxRecursion -> 500]
```

The solutions $\Omega (k, z)$ are given by :

```
 W[k_,z_] := Re[Ω /. FindRoot[f[Ω, k, z], {Ω, .895}]]
```

I need to calculate all solutions $\Omega(k, z)$ for $k = 3$ when $0.1 <z <100$.

My problem is that I get accurate solutions for $1<z<100$ and inaccurate solutions for $0.1=<z<0.7$.

For example:

```
Block[{k=3},Table[{z, W[k,z]},{z,{100,10,5,1,0.5,0.1}}]]
```

`{{100, 1.139642672363642}, {10, 1.96313715768855}, {5, 2.393983432376982}, {1,  2.905633499901334}, {0.5, 202.5621368946721}, {0.1, 104.1929384069426}}`

The true values for $z=0.5$ and $0.1$ are:

`W[3,0.5]= 2.98 ;  W[3,0.1]= 2.99`

Please, why do the computations do not converge? Is there an easy way to resolve this problem ?

(I should mention that I'm using Mathematica 10.2.0.0.)

Comment: When k > omega, ArcTanh[Sqrt[(\[Gamma]^2 - 1)/\[Gamma]^2] (k/\[CapitalOmega])] seems to be indeterminate when gamma goes to infinity.  Is this correct?

Comment: @Vito Vanin `Limit[ArcTanh[Sqrt[([Gamma]^2 - 1)/[Gamma]^2] (x)],Gamma->Infinity] =1/2 (-I \[Pi] - Log[-1 + x] + Log[1 + x])` when gamma goes to infinity for all `x>1`.

Comment: I am not sure that any of the results in the Question are correct.  Applying `f[Last@#, 3, First@#] &` to them returns `{0.00299279 + 0.018689 I, 0.592512 + 0.194949 I, 
 0.733582 + 0.114397 I, 0.867595 + 0.0489768 I, 0.999996, 0.999997}`.

Comment: I do not understand this!

Comment: @bbgodfrey, I would like to say to you that the solution of the imaginary part normalized at the real part $\frac{\Omega_{im}(k, z)}{\Omega_{re}(k, z)}$ of my equation given in a scientific paper in _Physics of Plasmas_ at $k=3$ and $z=100$ is $\frac{\Omega_{im}(3, 100)}{\Omega_{re}(3, 100)} \approx -0.0075$. When i try to find it via the _input_ : `Wim[k_,z_]:=Im[\CapitalOmega]/.FindRoot[f[\[CapitalOmega],k,z],{\[CapitalOmega],0.895}]]`, I found a very small value for the same parameters of  $k$ and $z$. Please, Is there an easy way to find the same results?

Comment: For a fellow plasma physicist, I am happy to take another look.  Please provide the reference to the paper that you mentioned in your last comment.

Comment: @bbgodfrey, thank you. This is the paper : http://dx.doi.org/10.1063/1.4821606. Please, see Fig. 3-d for $\Omega_{i}(3, 100)/\Omega_{r}(3, 100) \approx -0.0075$, value that I have not found.

Comment: I now have the paper but have not found your dispersion relation in it.  Please point me to the equation number in the paper.  By the way, your integrand has a branch point on the real axis, which probably is causing many of the error messages.  .

Comment: As noted, please edit your question to include the reference, in particular where in the reference can your equation be found.

Comment: @bbgodfrey, please, the equation mentioned above in my question does not appear in the paper. I got it by another approach. Its solutions are necessarily the same as that of equation (28) in the paper.

Comment: @bbgodfrey, Thank you. Looking forward to see your answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Difficulties encountered in solving the dispersion relation in the Question are due not so much to convergence of the integral as to the branch point in complex `γ`- space, which occurs where the argument of `ArcTanh[]` is equal to `1`.  Based on the [related article](http://dx.doi.org/10.1063/1.4821606) cited in a comment above, the integration contour `{γ, 1, Infinity}` must pass below all non-analytic points in complex `γ`- space. Moreover, on both physical and mathematical grounds `Im[Ω] < 0`, which implies that the corresponding value of `γ` also has a negative imaginary part.  I had hoped to take the branch point into account in the same way that I did in answering [Question 113240](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/113936/1063), but this proved to be impractical, because the corresponding branch cut is not a straight line in complex `γ`- space.

Alternatively, the branch point, which is logarithmic, can be eliminated from the integrand

```
γ^2 (ArcTanh[Sqrt[(γ^2 - 1)/γ^2] (k/Ω)]) Exp[-z γ]
```

by means of integration by parts:

```
arg1 = Integrate[γ^2 Exp[-z γ], γ, Assumptions -> z > 0];
arg2 = Simplify[D[ArcTanh[Sqrt[(γ^2 - 1)/γ^2] (k/Ω)], γ], γ > 1];
arg = -arg1 arg2
(* (k*(2 + 2*z*γ + z^2*γ^2)*Ω)/(E^(z*γ)*z^3*Sqrt[γ^2 - 1]*(-(k^2*(-1 + γ^2)) + γ^2*Ω^2)) *)
```

Based on the discussion in the first paragraph, the dispersion relation becomes not just the first equation in the question with the new integrand, but also the `Residue` of the `pole`.

```
pole = Solve[Denominator[arg] == 0, γ] // Last
(* {γ -> k/Sqrt[k^2 - Ω^2]} *)
res = FullSimplify[Residue[arg, {γ, γ /. pole}]]
(* (-(k^2*(2 + z^2)*Ω) + 2*Ω^3 - 2*k*z*Ω*Sqrt[(k - Ω)*(k + Ω)])/
(2*E^((k*z)/Sqrt[k^2 - Ω^2])*z^3*((k - Ω)*(k + Ω))^(3/2)*Sqrt[Ω^2/(k^2 - Ω^2)]) *)
```

Inserting this term, along with the new integrand given above, into the definition of `f` from the Question yields the new dispersion function,

```
h[Ω_?NumericQ, k_?NumericQ, z_?NumericQ] := 
    1 + (z/k^2) - (z^2/BesselK[2, z]) (Ω/k^3) (NIntegrate[(E^(-z γ)
    k (2 + 2 z γ + z^2 γ^2) Ω)/(z^3 Sqrt[-1 + γ^2] (-k^2 (-1 + γ^2) + γ^2 Ω^2)), 
    {γ, 1, Infinity}] + 2 Pi I (E^(-((k z)/Sqrt[k^2 - Ω^2])) Ω (-2 k^3 z + 2 k z Ω^2 - 
    k^2 (2 + z^2) Sqrt[k^2 - Ω^2] + 2 Ω^2 Sqrt[k^2 - Ω^2]))/(2 z^3 Sqrt[Ω^2/(k^2 - Ω^2)] 
    (k^2 - Ω^2)^2))
```

A comment above by [Betatron](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/10158/betatron) estimates that `h[Ω, 3, 100]` is satisfied by `Ω` such that `Im[Ω]/Re[Ω]` is of order `-0.0075`.  The new dispersion relation yields,

```
Ω /. Last@FindRoot[h[Ω, 3, 100], {Ω, 1.1 - .1 I}]
(* 1.13917 - 0.0075706 I *)
Im[%]/Re[%]
(* -0.0066457 *)
```

In contrast, the original dispersion relation yielded `1.1397 + 4.04927*10^-11 I`, along with error messages.  A few minutes of computation are sufficient to generate the following plots.

[image]

[image]

As requested in the Question, the new dispersion relation gives credible solutions for small `z`, and credible values for `Im[Ω]` throughout.

**Addendum**

As requested by Betatron in a Chat Room conversation, the code used to create the two plots above is

```
t1 = Table[{i, Ω /. FindRoot[h[Ω, 3, i], {Ω, 3 - I/1000}]}, {i, 1/10, 1, 1/10}];
t2 = Table[{i, Ω /. FindRoot[h[Ω, 3, i], {Ω, 2.5 - .3 I}]}, {i, 1, 3, 1/10}];
t3 = Table[{i, Ω /. FindRoot[h[Ω, 3, i], {Ω, 2. - .3 I}]}, {i, 4, 20}];
ListLogLinearPlot[Union[Re[t1], Re[t2], Re[t3]], AxesLabel -> {z, "Re[Ω]"}]
ListLogLinearPlot[{First@#, Im[Last@#]/Re[Last@#]} & /@ 
    Union[t1, t2, t3], PlotRange -> All, AxesLabel -> {z, "Im[Ω]/Re[Ω]"}]
```

Comment: Thank you so much Professor, but If i try for `z=0.5` :`\[CapitalOmega] /. 
 Last@FindRoot[
   h[\[CapitalOmega], 3, 0.5], {\[CapitalOmega], 1 - .1 I}]` I get : `3.155443621*10^-29 + 16.23354888 I` and `Im[%]/Re[%]` give `5.144616994*10^29` ?

Comment: @Betatron  Try a better initial guess, for instance, `Ω /. 
    FindRoot[h[Ω, 3, 1/2], {Ω, 3 - I/1000}]`.

Comment: Please, How did you find `arg = -arg1 arg2` in the integration by part of `γ^2 (ArcTanh[Sqrt[(γ^2 - 1)/γ^2] (k/Ω)]) Exp[-z γ]`?

Comment: @Betatron I differentiated `ArcTanh[]`  to eliminate the branch point and, consequently, had to integrate the rest.  Fortunately, the endpoints vanished.  If your question is about how integration by parts itself works, see for instance [Wolfram MathWorld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/IntegrationbyParts.html).

Comment: For `h[Ω,0.2,100]`,`Re[Ω]=0.99` from the graph, value that I can't find whatever the initial guess of omega, for example I get this : `Re[Ω /. FindRoot[h[Ω,0.2,100], {Ω,0.985 - I/1000}] = 0.09375544601]`. Therefore, to find all solutions`Re[Ω]` for `k∈[0,3]`, I'll have to fix for each `k` a different initial value of `Ω`. Please, how to get the better initial guess of omega for full range of `k`? Thank's

Comment: @Betatron I used `{Ω, 3 - I/1000}` for `z` between `1/10` and `1`, {Ω, 2.5 - .3 I}` for `z` between `1` and `3`, and `{Ω, 2. - .3 I}]}` for `z` between `4` and `20`.  It is not uncommon to vary initial guesses with parameters.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/39863/discussion-between-betatron-and-bbgodfrey).

Comment: When I solve the dispersion relation (Eq 28) in the paper to verify their results, I don't find the results plotted in figures, it's weird !! This is the input of their dispersion relation :

Comment: `epsilon[[CapitalOmega]_?NumericQ,[Kappa]_?NumericQ,z_?NumericQ]:= 1+z/[Kappa]^2 (1-((Pi z Exp[-z])/BesselK[1,z] [CapitalOmega]^2/[Kappa]^2 NIntegrate[((1-4/z Log[Sin[(3.14r)/2]])^3 (Sin[(3.14 r)/2])^2 Sin[3.14 r])/(z Sqrt[(1-4/z Log[Sin[(3.14 r)/2]])^2-1]((1-4/z Log[Sin[(3.14 r)/2]])^2([CapitalOmega]^2/[Kappa]^2-1)+1)),{r,0,1},MaxRecursion->1000]))+I (Pi [CapitalOmega] z Exp[-z/Sqrt[(1-[CapitalOmega]^2/[Kappa]^2)]])/(2BesselK[1,z] (1-[CapitalOmega]^2/[Kappa]^2)^(3/2)[Kappa]^3)` with `Kappa=k`

Comment: and
`\[CapitalOmega] /.
FindRoot[epsilonzhang[\[CapitalOmega], 3, 100], {\[CapitalOmega],
1.1 - .1 I}, MaxIterations -> 1000]` give `1.928208435 - I 1.288999892` and 
`Im[%]/Re[%]= -0.6684961382`,  why is that ?

Comment: @Betatron  Using your code, I obtain the same result.  It is possible that the formula published in the paper is incorrect.  For instance, your formula contains `BesselK[2, z]`, and the paper's formula contains `BesselK[1, z]`.  Why do you think that the two are equivalent?  Can you derive one from the other?