# How to compute this integral?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, symbolic, complex

I'm trying to calculate this integral :

$$I(z,k,a)= \displaystyle\int_{1}^{\infty} t^2\, \text{ArcTanh}  \left(\sqrt{\frac{t^2-1}{t^2}} \dfrac{k}{z}\right)\, e^{-a\,t} \, dt$$

Where :

- $\textrm{ArcTanh(...)}$ : is the inverse hyperbolic tangent function.
- $z=x+i\,y$ : is a complex with the assymption $y<<<x$.
- $k$ and $a$ are reals $>0$.

Mathematica didn't calculate it. Maybe it is too complicated to be done.

In Mathematica *input* form :

```
Assuming[{a>0&&k>0},Integrate[t^2 (ArcTanh[Sqrt[(t^2-1)/t^2](k/z)])Exp[-a t],{t,1,Infinity}]]
```

If I simply enter that into Mathematica, it instantly returns the same expression.

Please, how do I go about this ? Is there any tricks that can be applied ?

Is there a way to get the symbolic result ?

Thank's.

Comment: i like to start by considering a particular case, say `a=k=z=1`. In this case even that does not yield a closed form result, so I'd call to prospect of obtaining a result for the general case doubtful.

Comment: Is a symbolic solution absolutely necessary, or could you get away with calculating values of this integral numerically after assigning specific values to the parameters?

Comment: @MarcoB Numerical solutions are already calculated, but I would like to calculate the symbolic solution for solving a non linear equation and discuss the analytical solutions.

Comment: @Betatron Then this may not be a *Mathematica* problem, but a mathematical one, i.e. the existence of a closed-form antiderivative is doubtful. Notice also that, for what it's worth, your `Assuming[...]` expression evaluates for close to 30 s then returns the expression unevaluated in MMA 10.4.0.

Comment: If you are sure that analytic solution exists please provide some background and preceding steps of your derivation.

Comment: @yarchik, the integral that I'm trying to calculate is a portion of an integral equation previously posted at http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/114176/why-integral-does-not-converge. For obtaining the accurate imaginary solutions of this equation for which the integral diverges, I think that I will need to transform it in a form of _Dirac-Plemelj Formula_ : `Principale value of integral +/- Pi i (...)`.

Comment: Please, What's strategy is used by Mathematica to calculate `ArcTanh(z)` for `0 < z < 1` and for `z > 1` ?

Comment: For k/z = 1 there is a closed form  result: I[1,1,a]=((4 + a^2) BesselK[0, a] + 
 a (4 BesselK[1, a] + a BesselK[2, a]))/(2 a^3)

Comment: +1 because it gives a good example of cooperation of user and Mathematica.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Preliminary post**

For k/z = 1 there is a closed form result:

```
I[1,1,a]=((4 + a^2) BesselK[0, a] + a (4 BesselK[1, a] + a BesselK[2, a]))/(2 a^3)
```

The derivation and the extension to k/z != 1 requires some manual interaction to help Mathematica which we will show in the following.

**Solution**

*Summary*

As the integral to be calculated is returned unevaluated by Mathematica we show here to get useful partial results by using a method I like to call "man-machine-interaction". This means we carry out a joint work with paper and pencil on one side and Mathematica on the other side.

The case m = k/z == 1 can be solved symbolically.
If m < 1 we show how to get the symbolic soluton to aribtrary precision as a power series in (1-m).

*Preliminary remarks*

1) The integral to be calculated is

```
fI := Integrate[
  t^2 (ArcTanh[m Sqrt[(t^2 - 1)/t^2]]) Exp[-a t], {t, 1, Infinity}, 
  Assumptions -> {a > 0, 0 < m < 1}]
```

The numerical integral presents, however, no problem

```
fN[a_, m_] := 
 NIntegrate[t^2 (ArcTanh[m Sqrt[(t^2 - 1)/t^2]]) Exp[-a t], {t, 1, Infinity}]
```

2) Here we have set m = k/z, because k and z enter only as a quotient.

3) Also we have introduced natural restrictions on the parameters "a" and "m". The restriction for m comes from the requirement that fI be a real quantity. This in turn requires the argument of the ArcTanh to be between 0 and 1 if we keep the upper limit of integration of t at infinity.

4) The factor t^2 in the integrand can be generated by differentiating twice with respect to "a". Hence it is sufficient to study the simpler intergral without the factor t^2.

Hence the integrand to be studied becomes

```
fi = Exp[-a t] ArcTanh[m Sqrt[(-1 + t^2)/t^2]];
```

*Step by step solution*

The first step will be a partial integration.
This step is not done automatically by Mathematica, hence we do it manually.

fi can be written as

```
fi = fid + fi1
```

where

```
fid1 = -(1/a) Exp[-a t] ArcTanh[m Sqrt[(-1 + t^2)/t^2]];

fid = D[fid1, t];
```

and

```
fi1 = Simplify[ (E^(-a t) m (2/t - (2 (-1 + t^2))/t^3))/(
  2 a Sqrt[(-1 + t^2)/t^2] (1 - (m^2 (-1 + t^2))/t^2)), {a > 0, t > 0, 
   0 < m < 1}]

(*
Out[99]= (E^(-a t) m)/(a Sqrt[-1 + t^2] (t^2 - m^2 (-1 + t^2)))
*)
```

Indeed

```
Simplify[fi == fid + fi1, {a > 0, t > 0, 0 < m < 1}]

(* Out[101]= True *)
```

Because

```
fid1 /. t -> 1

(* Out[102]= 0 *)

Limit[fid1, t -> \[Infinity], Assumptions -> a > 0]

(* Out[103]= 0 *)
```

the integral becomes

```
fI2 := Integrate[(E^(-a t) m)/(
  a Sqrt[t^2 - 1] (t^2 + m^2 (1 - t^2))), {t, 1, \[Infinity]}, 
  Assumptions -> {a > 0, 0 < m < 1}]
```

This integral is also returned unevaluated by Mathematica.
Hence we look first at a special case.

*The case m = 1*

If m = 1 the integrand simplifies and the integral can be done expicitly

```
(E^(-a t) m)/(a Sqrt[t^2 - 1] (t^2 + m^2 (1 - t^2))) /. m -> 1

(* Out[125]= E^(-a t)/(a Sqrt[-1 + t^2]) *)

fI3 = Integrate[%, {t, 1, \[Infinity]}, Assumptions -> a > 0]

(* Out[126]= BesselK[0, a]/a *)
```

In order to find the original integral we need to differentiate this expression twice

```
fI4 = D[fI3, {a, 2}] // Simplify

(*
Out[127]= ((4 + a^2) BesselK[0, a] + a (4 BesselK[1, a] + a BesselK[2, a]))/(2 a^3)
*)
```

The result in the original designation

$$I(1,1,a)=\frac{\left(a^2+4\right) K_0(a)+a (4 K_1(a)+a K_2(a))}{2 a^3}$$

The numerical agreement is excellent:

```
Plot[fN[a, 1]/fI4, {a, 0.1, 2}, PlotRange -> {{0, 2}, {0.99, 1.01}}, 
 PlotLabel -> 
  "Integral for m = 1\nComparison of symbolical and numerical solution", 
 AxesLabel -> {"a", "fN/fI4"}]
```

[image]

*Series expansion*

Now we can proceed further developing the integrand of fi1 into a power series about m = 1.

Remark: Although it leads to cumbersome expressions I took four terms in order to possibly find a rule in the result (but, alas, I didn't)

```
Series[fi1, {m, 1, 4}] // Normal

(* 
Out[122]= E^(-a t)/(a Sqrt[-1 + t^2]) + (E^(-a t) (-1 + m) (-1 + 2 t^2))/(
 a Sqrt[-1 + t^2]) + (E^(-a t) (-1 + m)^2 (1 - 5 t^2 + 4 t^4))/(
 a Sqrt[-1 + t^2]) + (
 E^(-a t) (-1 + m)^4 (-1 + t^2)^(3/2) (1 - 12 t^2 + 16 t^4))/a + (
 E^(-a t) (-1 + m)^3 (-1 + 9 t^2 - 16 t^4 + 8 t^6))/(a Sqrt[-1 + t^2])
*)

fis = List @@ %;

Timing[Integrate[fis, {t, 1, \[Infinity]}, Assumptions -> {a > 0}]]

(*
{1233.4843069`, {BesselK[0, a]/a, ((-1 + m) BesselK[2, a])/a, (
  3 (-1 + m)^2 (4 a BesselK[0, a] + (8 + a^2) BesselK[1, a]))/a^4, (
  15 (-1 + m)^4 (a (112 + a^2) BesselK[2, a] + 
     4 (168 + 5 a^2) BesselK[3, a]))/
  a^6, ((-1 + 
     m)^3 (24 a (20 + a^2) BesselK[0, a] + (960 + 168 a^2 + a^4) BesselK[1, 
       a]))/a^6}}
*)
```

Finally, we need the second derivative with respect to a:

```
D[%[[2]], {a, 2}] // Simplify

(*
{((4 + a^2) BesselK[0, a] + a (4 BesselK[1, a] + a BesselK[2, a]))/(
 2 a^3), ((-1 + m) (a^2 BesselK[0, a] + 4 a BesselK[1, a] + 
    8 BesselK[2, a] + 2 a^2 BesselK[2, a] + 4 a BesselK[3, a] + 
    a^2 BesselK[4, a]))/(4 a^3), (
 3 (-1 + m)^2 (16 a (20 + a^2) BesselK[0, 
      a] + (640 + 144 a^2 + 3 a^4) BesselK[1, a] + 
    a (8 + a^2) (16 BesselK[2, a] + a BesselK[3, a])))/(4 a^6), (1/(
 4 a^8))15 (-1 + m)^4 (a^3 (112 + a^2) BesselK[0, a] + 
    32 a^2 (91 + a^2) BesselK[1, a] + 29568 a BesselK[2, a] + 
    592 a^3 BesselK[2, a] + 2 a^5 BesselK[2, a] + 
    112896 BesselK[3, a] + 5184 a^2 BesselK[3, a] + 
    52 a^4 BesselK[3, a] + 16128 a BesselK[4, a] + 
    432 a^3 BesselK[4, a] + a^5 BesselK[4, a] + 
    672 a^2 BesselK[5, a] + 20 a^4 BesselK[5, a]), (1/(
 4 a^8))(-1 + m)^3 (8 a (10080 + 600 a^2 + 7 a^4) BesselK[0, a] + 
    3 (53760 + 11840 a^2 + 368 a^4 + a^6) BesselK[1, a] + 
    a (8 (2880 + 456 a^2 + 7 a^4) BesselK[2, a] + 
       a (960 + 168 a^2 + a^4) BesselK[3, a]))}
*)
```

*Observation*

Related simpler example where Mathematica needs some help

This integral is returned unevaluated

```
Integrate[Exp[-a Cosh[u]], {u, 0, \[Infinity]}, Assumptions -> a > 0]

(*
Out[124]= Integrate[E^(-a Cosh[u]), {u, 0, \[Infinity]}, Assumptions -> a > 0] *)
```

But with the substitution `Cosh[u] -> t` we obtain an eqivalent expression of the integral which now is deone by Mathematica:

```
Integrate[Exp[-a t]/Sqrt[t^2 - 1], {t, 1, \[Infinity]}, Assumptions -> a > 0]

(* Out[142]= BesselK[0, a] *)
```

Comment: "[...] I'll show it later." -- Looking forward to see it! :)

Comment: @Dr. Wolfgang Hintze, If I simply enter into Mathematica `I[1,1,a]` it instantly returns the same expression. Please, How did you get the  closed form `I[1,1,a]=((4 + a^2) BesselK[0, a] + a (4 BesselK[1, a] + a BesselK[2, a]))/(2 a^3)` ? Thanks

Answer (score 3):

For k/z = 1, and
integrating by parts:

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]
Iv[t_] := Exp[-a*t]*t^2;
u[t_] := ArcTanh[Sqrt[(t^2 - 1)/t^2]];
v = Integrate[Iv[t], t];
Du = Simplify@D[u[t], t];
Int == u[t]*v - Integrate[Du*v, t]

HoldForm[Integrate[Exp[-a*t]*t^2*ArcTanh[Sqrt[(t^2 - 1)/t^2]], {t, 1, Infinity}] == 
Limit[-((E^(-a t) (2 + 2 a t + a^2 t^2) ArcTanh[Sqrt[(-1 + t^2)/
   t^2]])/a^3), t -> Infinity] - 
Limit[-((
 E^(-a t) (2 + 2 a t + a^2 t^2) ArcTanh[Sqrt[(-1 + t^2)/t^2]])/
 a^3), t -> 1] + 
Integrate[(E^(-a t) (2 + 2 a t + a^2 t^2))/(
Sqrt[1 - 1/t^2] t), {t, 1, Infinity}]/a^3]
```

> $\int_1^{\infty } \exp (-a t) t^2 \tanh ^{-1}\left(\sqrt{\frac{t^2-1}{t^2}}\right) \, dt=\lim_{t\to \infty } \, -\frac{e^{-a t}
>    \left(2+2 a t+a^2 t^2\right) \tanh ^{-1}\left(\sqrt{\frac{-1+t^2}{t^2}}\right)}{a^3}-\lim_{t\to 1} \, -\frac{e^{-a t}
>    \left(2+2 a t+a^2 t^2\right) \tanh ^{-1}\left(\sqrt{\frac{-1+t^2}{t^2}}\right)}{a^3}+\frac{\int_1^{\infty } \frac{e^{-a t}
>    \left(2+2 a t+a^2 t^2\right)}{\sqrt{1-\frac{1}{t^2}} t} \, dt}{a^3}$

```
Limit[u[t]*v, t -> Infinity, Assumptions -> a > 0] - 
Limit[u[t]*v, t -> 1, Assumptions -> a > 0]
```

> $0$

```
ExpandAll@Simplify[Du*v, t > 0]

in1 = Assuming[{a > 0, t > 0}, Integrate[-((2 E^(-a t))/(a^3 Sqrt[-1 + t^2])), {t, 1, Infinity}]];
in2 = Assuming[{a > 0, t > 0}, Integrate[-((2 E^(-a t) t)/(a^2 Sqrt[-1 + t^2])), {t, 1, 
 Infinity}]];
in3 = Assuming[{a > 0, t > 0}, Integrate[(-E^(-a t) t^2)/(a Sqrt[-1 + t^2]), {t, 1, Infinity}]];
HoldForm[Integrate[Exp[-a*t]*t^2*ArcTanh[Sqrt[(t^2 - 1)/t^2]], {t, 1, 
Infinity}]] == -(in1 + in2 + in3)
```

> $\int_1^{\infty } \exp (-a t) t^2 \tanh ^{-1}\left(\sqrt{\frac{t^2-1}{t^2}}\right) \, dt=\frac{2 K_0(a)}{a^3}+\frac{2
>    K_1(a)}{a^2}+\frac{a K_0(a)+K_1(a)}{a^2}$

where: $K_0(a)$ and $K_1(a)$ the modified Bessel function of the second kind.