# x DiracDelta[x] simplifies to 0, desired or a bug?

Tags: bugs, simplifying-expressions, generalized-function

**Bug introduced in 5.0 or earlier, persisting through 13.0.**

---

I encountered this when trying to answer [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/127081/1871):

```
x DiracDelta[x] // Simplify
(* 0 *)
```

Is this a bug or desired? If it's desired, what's the meaning of it? Well, this behavior indeed causes trouble in certain cases, here is a minimal example:

```
test = ( I + ζ DiracDelta[ζ])/  ζ;
InverseFourierTransform[#@test, ζ, z] & /@ {Identity, Simplify}
(* {(1 + π Sign[z])/Sqrt[2 π], Sqrt[π/2] Sign[z]} *)
```

Comment: delta is only defined in terms of its integral, and this result will give the correct integral value. In what sense is it wrong?

Comment: From the documentation:  "`DiracDelta[x]` returns 0 for all real numeric x other than 0."  Since `x DiracDelta[x]` is zero at `x = 0` then `x DiracDelta[x]` is zero for all real `x`.  `DiracDelta` is a generalized function and is only fully defined in the context of an integral ("`DiracDelta` can be used in integrals, integral transforms, and differential equations").

Comment: @george2079 I've added a minimal example to the question.

Comment: It seems more generally that for a numeric function `f`, `Simplify[f[x] DiracDelta[x]]` yields `f[0] DiracDelta[x]`.

Comment: @MichaelE2 Not necessarily. If you shift the expression, it doesn't work: `Simplify[Abs[x-x1]DiracDelta[x-x1]]`. This would also be a potential workaround for this Q: just shift everything: `(x - x1) DiracDelta[x - x1] // Simplify` is not zero.

Comment: @Jens OK. I was thinking of `x` as a symbol, not a general expression.

Comment: You might want to consider these, too: `(I + Sin[ζ] DiracDelta[ζ])/ζ` and `(I/ζ + Sinc[ζ] DiracDelta[ζ])`, which give different results for `InverseFourierTransform[]`, even without simplification.

Comment: @MichaelE2 In v9 the result is the same: ![Mathematica graphics](http://i.stack.imgur.com/bclvF.png) Seems to be a bug in v11. (Don't have v10 installed so can't test. )

Comment: For what it's worth, I don't see a bug in all this. The example is playing with a hidden zero. If it gets exposed at an inopportune time, e.g. before a division can occur that removes the zero, that's unfortunate but not necessarily a bug. Arguably `Simplify` should not mess with distributions because they do not follow the same rules as analytic functions. But that would bring on problems of its own I suspect.

Comment: Same thing happens with `x*UnitStep[x]*UnitStep[-x] // Simplify`.

Comment: `test = (I + (\[Zeta] - \[Zeta]1) DiracDelta[\[Zeta] - \[Zeta]1])/(\
\[Zeta] - \[Zeta]1);test = (I + (\[Zeta] - \[Zeta]1) DiracDelta[\[Zeta] - \[Zeta]1])/(\
\[Zeta] - \[Zeta]1)` returns the input in 13 on Windows 10, as well as `FourierTransform[test, \[Zeta], z, Assumptions -> \[Xi]1 > 0]`. Both executions take a long time.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The first line in your question is simplified correctly, but the added example shows that the simplification of the second line is in fact wrong because the denominator is ignored for too long.

To work around this, you could shift the variable like this:

```
test=(I+(ζ-ζ1) DiracDelta[ζ-ζ1])/(ζ-ζ1);
InverseFourierTransform[#@test,ζ,z]&/@{Identity,Simplify}
```

Then the results agree:

```
SameQ@@%
```

> `True`

Therefore, to get the desired result, I tried this:

```
test = (I + (ζ - ζ1) DiracDelta[ζ - ζ1])/(ζ - ζ1);
(InverseFourierTransform[#@test, ζ, z] & /@ {Identity, Simplify}) /. ζ1 -> 0
```

> `{Sqrt[2 Pi] DiracDelta[0] DiracDelta[z] + Sqrt[Pi/2] Sign[z], 
>        Sqrt[2 Pi] DiracDelta[0] DiracDelta[z] + Sqrt[Pi/2] Sign[z]}`

However, this doesn't quite work because there is a delta function of `0`.

The best I could do with this shift trick is to prevent the simplification like this:

```
test = (I + ζ DiracDelta[ζ])/ζ;
InverseFourierTransform[#[test /. ζ -> (ζ - ζ1)] /. ζ1 -> 0, 
 ζ, z] & /@ {Identity, Simplify}
```

> `{(1 + Pi Sign[z])/Sqrt[2 Pi], (1 + Pi Sign[z])/Sqrt[2 Pi]}`

Comment: In v9 your first approach already works: [Mathematica graphics](http://i.stack.imgur.com/Fqibr.png) :D

Comment: And things seem to be even worse in v11: http://i.stack.imgur.com/EAhvT.png

Comment: My results are for version 11 on OS X. Good to know that it can always get worse...