# Analytic solution for 1D heat equation

Tags: differential-equations, heat-equation

I would like to use *Mathematica* to solve a simple heat equation model analytically.

I have an insulated rod, it's 1 unit long.

- At x = 0, there is a Neumann boundary condition where the temperature gradient is fixed to be 1. This is to simulate constant heat flux.
- At x = 1, there is a Dirichlet boundary condition where the temperature is fixed at 25.
- The initial temperature of the rod is 25.

  ```
  heqn = D[u[x, t], t] == D[u[x, t], {x, 2}];
  ic = u[x, 0] == 25;
  bc1 = u[1,t] == 25;
  bc2 = D[u[0,t]]==1;
  DSolve[{heqn, ic, bc1, bc2},u[x,t], {x,t}]
  ```

This doesn't appear to do what I want, where have I gone wrong?

Comment: You can format inline code and code blocks by selecting the code and clicking the `{}` button above the edit window. The edit window help button `?` is also useful for learning how to format your questions and answers. You may also find [this meta Q&A](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1584) helpful

Comment: Thank you for the advice, I believe I have correctly formatted the code segment now.

Comment: You have an error in `bc2`: It should be `D[u[0,t], t]==1`. In addition, *Mathematica* will not find an analytic solution for this situation. You should try `NDSolve` instead.

Comment: @march I think he wants `Derivative[1, 0][u][0, t]` as the boundary condition. But you're right about not finding a solution to the  PDE even after the correction.

Comment: @Jens. Right, got the derivatives backward.

Comment: I was hoping that I would be able to get an analytic solution, what combination of BCs and ICs would give me an analytic solution? Ideally one of the BCs would be a Neumann condition.

Comment: Your initial condition isn't consistent with the Neumann condition.

Comment: `This doesn't appear to do what I want` it will help to show what you obtained as answer, and what you expected. in version 11 your code above gives ![Mathematica graphics](http://i.stack.imgur.com/ERr4V.png)

Comment: @Nasser  Your solution is valid for `bc2 = u[0, t] == 1`, but not for the `bc2` in the question.

Comment: @bbgodfrey Yes. But I just copied and pasted the code as is. OP put the wrong boundary conditions.  Also the initial and boundary conditions are not consistent.

Comment: @Jens When the i.c. and b.c. are inconsistent, a weak solution (well, is it the correct terminology?) can still be obtained, see my answer below.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here's a analytic solution based on `LaplaceTransform`, involving an `InverseLaplaceTransform`.

We first correct the trivial syntax mistake in `bc2`:

```
heqn = D[u[x, t], t] == D[u[x, t], {x, 2}];
ic = u[x, 0] == 25;
bc1 = u[1, t] == 25;
bc2 = D[u[x, t], x] == 1 /. x -> 0;
```

Then do a `LaplaceTransform` on the equation set and solve the obtained ODE set with `DSolve`:

```
tset = LaplaceTransform[{heqn, bc1, bc2}, t, s] /. Rule @@ ic /. 
  HoldPattern@LaplaceTransform[a_, __] :> a

tsol[x_, s_] = u[x, t] /. First@DSolve[tset, u[x, t], x]
```

Notice I've made a replacement `HoldPattern@LaplaceTransform[a_, __] :> a` because `DSolve` has difficulty in handling those `LaplaceTransform[__]`s, just keep in mind that the `u[x, t]` inside `DSolve` is actually `LaplaceTransform[u[x, t], t, s]`.

OK, the final step is to do a `InverseLaplaceTransform` on `tsol[x, s]`, but sadly, `InverseLaplaceTransform` gives back the input formula. Anyway, the goal of your question has been achieved, we've obtained an analytic solution, involving an integral. (Don't forget `InverseLaplaceTransform` is just an <strike>sometimes very hard to calculate</strike> integral. ) Here's the solution, in traditional math notation:

$$u(x,t)=\frac{1}{2 \pi  i}\int _{\gamma -i \infty }^{\gamma +i \infty }\frac{ e^{-\sqrt{s} x} \left(25 \sqrt{s} e^{\sqrt{s} x}+25 \sqrt{s} e^{\sqrt{s} x+2 \sqrt{s}}+e^{2 \sqrt{s} x}-e^{2 \sqrt{s}}\right)}{\left(e^{2 \sqrt{s}}+1\right) s^{3/2}} e^{s t} d s$$

The solution can be used for evaluation, with the help of packages for numeric Laplace transform, I'll use [this package](http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/MathSource/5026/) as an example:

```
plotlst = Table[
   ListLinePlot[(Compile[{{x, _Real, 1}}, #] &@FT[tsol[x, #1] &, t])@Range[0, 1, 1/50], 
    DataRange -> {0, 1}, PlotRange -> {24, 25.1}], {t, 10^-3, 1, 1/50}];

plotlst // ListAnimate
(* Export["a.gif", plotlst] *)
```

[image]

Finally I'd like to say something about the failure of direct usage of `DSolve`. Personally, I think it's just because `DSolve` is still not strong enough even after the improvement in *v10.3*. One may think, it's the inconsistent i.c. and b.c. that stops `DSolve` from solving the problem, but it's not true, because even if we change the `bc2` to

```
bc2 = D[u[x, t], x] == 1 - Exp[-1000 t] /. x -> 0;
```

`DSolve` still returns the input.

Comment: Can you explain why this method was necessary? What is the issue behind trying to use `DSolve`?

Comment: @Myridium My guess is `DSolve` is still not strong enough even after the improvement in _v10.3_. ([Here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/127151/1871)'s another example that I think `DSolve` should handle. )

Comment: @Myridium Finally, `DSolve` can handle the problem now. (Not sure when the improvement is introduced, at least since _v12.3_. )

Answer (score 11):

Here is a full analytical solution derived by hand calculation

$$
u\left(  x,t\right)  =x+24+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{8}{\left(  1-2n\right)
^{2}\pi^{2}}\cos\left(  \left(  n-\frac{1}{2}\right)  \pi x\right)
e^{-\left(  \left(  n-\frac{1}{2}\right)  \pi\right)  ^{2}t}
$$

[image]

And compared to Mathematica's above solution by xzczd result, and they agree.

DSolve does not seem to like the non-homogenous Neumann boundary conditions in this problem. The idea to
solve this analytically is to break the problem in two stages. Solve for
steady state first, which make the PDE an ODE, but now the ODE with
nonhomogeneous B.C. is easily solved. Then use the solution at steady state
$u_{E}$ to find the difference solution $v\left(  x,t\right)  =u\left(
x,t\right)  -u_{E}$ but now this has a homogeneous B.C. which is easily solved
by separation of variables method.

Problem:

\begin{align*}
\frac{\partial u\left(  x,t\right)  }{\partial t}  & =k\frac{\partial
^{2}u\left(  x,t\right)  }{\partial x^{2}}\\
\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}\left(  0,t\right)    & =A\\
u\left(  L,t\right)    & =B\\
u\left(  x,0\right)    & =f\left(  x\right)
\end{align*}
In this problem $L=1,A=1,B=25,f\left(  x\right)  =25,k=1$ (thermal
diffusivity). But the problem is solved in symbols and only at the very end
these numerical values are used in animation.

Assuming the solution at steady state is $u_{E}\left(  x\right)  $, hence
$u_{E}\left(  x\right)  $ is the solution to $\frac{\partial^{2}u\left(
x,t\right)  }{\partial x^{2}}=0$, or since now it is time independent, it
becomes
$$
u_{E}^{\prime\prime}=0
$$
With
\begin{align*}
u_{E}^{\prime}\left(  0\right)    & =A\\
u_{E}\left(  L\right)    & =B
\end{align*}
This has the solution
$$
u_{E}=c_{1}x+c_{2}
$$
After applying the boundary conditions, the solution becomes
\begin{equation}
u_{E}=A\left(  x-L\right)  +B\tag{1}
\end{equation}
The difference solution is
\begin{equation}
v\left(  x,t\right)  =u\left(  x,t\right)  -u_{E}\left(  x\right)  \tag{2}
\end{equation}
With $v\left(  x,t\right)  $ now satisfying
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial v\left(  x,t\right)  }{\partial t}  & =k\frac{\partial
^{2}v\left(  x,t\right)  }{\partial x^{2}}\tag{3}\\
\frac{\partial v}{\partial x}\left(  0,t\right)    & =0\nonumber\\
v\left(  L,t\right)    & =0\nonumber\\
v\left(  x,0\right)    & =f\left(  x\right)  -u_{E}\nonumber
\end{align}
PDE (3) is solved now by separation of variables. Let $v=X\left(  x\right)
T\left(  t\right)  $. Substituting this into (3) gives
$$
\frac{1}{k}\frac{T^{\prime}}{T}=\frac{X^{\prime\prime}}{X}
$$
These must be equal to same constant, say $-\lambda$, giving two ODE's to
solve, with corresponding B.C.
\begin{align*}
X^{\prime\prime}+\lambda X  & =0\\
X^{\prime}\left(  0\right)    & =0\\
X\left(  L\right)    & =0
\end{align*}
And
$$
T^{\prime}=k\lambda T
$$
The solution to the space $X\left(  x\right)  $ ODE above is solved.

Case $\lambda<0$

The solution in this case is $X=c_{1}\cosh\left(  \sqrt{\lambda}x\right)
+c_{2}\sinh\left(  \sqrt{\lambda}x\right)  $. And $X^{\prime}=\sqrt{\lambda
}c_{1}\sinh\left(  \sqrt{\lambda}x\right)  +\sqrt{\lambda}c_{2}\cosh\left(
\sqrt{\lambda}x\right)  .$ Applying first B.C. gives $0=\sqrt{\lambda}c_{2}$.
Hence $c_{2}=0$. The solution becomes $X\left(  x\right)  =c_{1}\cosh\left(
\sqrt{\lambda}x\right)  $. Applying second B.C. gives $0=c_{2}\cosh\left(
\sqrt{\lambda}L\right)  $. But $\cosh$ is never zero, hence $c_{2}=0$ and
solution is trivial. Therefore $\lambda<0$ is not an eigenvalue.

Case $\lambda=0$

ODE\ becomes $X^{\prime\prime}=0$. Solution is $X\left(  x\right)
=c_{1}x+c_{2}$. And $X^{\prime}=c_{1}$. First B.C. gives $0=c_{1}$. Solution
becomes $X=c_{2}$. Applying second B.C. gives $0=c_{2}$. Hence $c_{2}=0$ and
trivial solution. Therefore $\lambda=0$ is not an eigenvalue.

Case $\lambda>0$

Solution is $X=c_{1}\cos\left(  \sqrt{\lambda}x\right)  +c_{2}\sin\left(
\sqrt{\lambda}x\right)  $. And $X^{\prime}=-\sqrt{\lambda}c_{1}\sin\left(
\sqrt{\lambda}x\right)  +\sqrt{\lambda}c_{2}\cos\left(  \sqrt{\lambda
}x\right)  $. First B.C. gives $0=-\sqrt{\lambda}c_{2}$ or $c_{2}=0$. Solution
becomes $X=c_{1}\cos\left(  \sqrt{\lambda}x\right)  $. Second B.C. gives
$0=c_{2}\cos\left(  \sqrt{\lambda}L\right)  $. Non trivial solution implies
$\cos\left(  \sqrt{\lambda}L\right)  =0$ or
\begin{align*}
\sqrt{\lambda_{n}}  & =\left(  n-\frac{1}{2}\right)  \frac{\pi}{L}\qquad
n=1,2,3,\cdots\\
\lambda_{n}  & =\left(  \left(  n-\frac{1}{2}\right)  \frac{\pi}{L}\right)
^{2}\qquad n=1,2,3,\cdots
\end{align*}
Giving the eigenfunctions
$$
X\left(  x\right)  =\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}C_{n}\cos\left(  \sqrt{\lambda_{n}
}x\right)
$$
The corresponding time solution for same set of eigenvalues is
$$
T\left(  t\right)  =\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}D_{n}e^{-\lambda_{n}kt}
$$
Therefore
\begin{align}
v\left(  x,t\right)    & =XT\nonumber\\
& =\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}E_{n}\cos\left(  \sqrt{\lambda_{n}}x\right)
e^{-\lambda_{n}kt}\tag{4}
\end{align}
Where $E_{n}=C_{n}D_{n}$. Now $E_{n}$ is found from initial conditions. From
(3) $v\left(  x,0\right)  =f\left(  x\right)  -u_{E}$, therefore
$$
f\left(  x\right)  -u_{E}=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}E_{n}\cos\left(  \left(
n-\frac{1}{2}\right)  \frac{\pi}{L}x\right)
$$
Multiplying both sides by $\cos\left(  \left(  m-\frac{1}{2}\right)  \frac
{\pi}{L}x\right)  $ and integrating gives
$$
\int_{0}^{L}\left(  f\left(  x\right)  -u_{E}\right)  \cos\left(  \left(
m-\frac{1}{2}\right)  \frac{\pi}{L}x\right)  dx=\int_{0}^{L}\cos\left(
\left(  m-\frac{1}{2}\right)  \frac{\pi}{L}x\right)  \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}
E_{n}\cos\left(  \left(  n-\frac{1}{2}\right)  \frac{\pi}{L}x\right)  dx
$$
Exchanging order of integration and summation
$$
\int_{0}^{L}\left(  f\left(  x\right)  -u_{E}\right)  \cos\left(  \left(
m-\frac{1}{2}\right)  \frac{\pi}{L}x\right)  dx=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}E_{n}
\int_{0}^{L}\cos\left(  \left(  m-\frac{1}{2}\right)  \frac{\pi}{L}x\right)
\cos\left(  \left(  n-\frac{1}{2}\right)  \frac{\pi}{L}x\right)  dx
$$
By orthogonality, $\int_{0}^{L}\cos\left(  \left(  m-\frac{1}{2}\right)
\frac{\pi}{L}x\right)  \cos\left(  \left(  n-\frac{1}{2}\right)  \frac{\pi}
{L}x\right)  dx=\frac{L}{2}$ for $m=n$ and zero otherwise, and the above
simplifies to
$$
\int_{0}^{L}\left(  f\left(  x\right)  -u_{E}\right)  \cos\left(
\sqrt{\lambda_{n}}x\right)  dx=\frac{L}{2}E_{m}
$$
Solving for $B_{m}$ and renaming to $n$ gives
\begin{align*}
E_{n}  & =\frac{2}{L}\int_{0}^{L}\left(  f\left(  x\right)  -u_{E}\right)
\cos\left(  \sqrt{\lambda_{n}}x\right)  dx\\
& =\frac{2}{L}\int_{0}^{L}\left(  f\left(  x\right)  -\left(  A\left(
x-L\right)  +B\right)  \right)  \cos\left(  \sqrt{\lambda_{n}}x\right)  dx
\end{align*}
Hence the solution (4) becomes
$$
v\left(  x,t\right)  =\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}E_{n}\cos\left(  \sqrt{\lambda_{n}
}x\right)  e^{-\lambda_{n}kt}
$$
Therefore from $u\left(  x,t\right)  =u_{E}\left(  x\right)  +v\left(
x,t\right)  $ the final solution is
\begin{align}
u\left(  x,t\right)    & =u_{E}\left(  x\right)  +\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}E_{n}
\cos\left(  \sqrt{\lambda_{n}}x\right)  e^{-\lambda_{n}kt}\tag{5}\\
& =A\left(  x-L\right)  +B+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}E_{n}\cos\left(  \sqrt
{\lambda_{n}}x\right)  e^{-\lambda_{n}kt}\nonumber
\end{align}
Now for $A=1,B=25,f\left(  x\right)  =25$,$k=1,L=1$ then
\begin{align*}
E_{n}  & =\frac{2}{L}\int_{0}^{L}\left(  f\left(  x\right)  -\left(  A\left(
x-L\right)  +B\right)  \right)  \cos\left(  \left(  n-\frac{1}{2}\right)
\frac{\pi}{L}x\right)  dx\\
& =2\int_{0}^{1}\left(  1-\left(  \left(  x-1\right)  +25\right)  \right)
\cos\left(  \left(  n-\frac{1}{2}\right)  \frac{\pi}{L}x\right)  dx\\
& =\frac{8}{\left(  1-2n\right)  ^{2}\pi^{2}}
\end{align*}
Hence the solution is
$$
u\left(  x,t\right)  =x+24+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{8}{\left(  1-2n\right)
^{2}\pi^{2}}\cos\left(  \left(  n-\frac{1}{2}\right)  \pi x\right)
e^{-\left(  \left(  n-\frac{1}{2}\right)  \pi\right)  ^{2}t}
$$

Here is the Manipulate code:

```
ClearAll[u]
A0 = 1; B0 = 25; L0 = 1; k = 1; f = 25; tmax = 1;
En = (2/L0) Assuming[Element[n, Integers] && n > 0,
   Simplify[
    Integrate[ (f - (A0 (x - L0) + B0)) Cos[(n - 1/2) Pi/L0 x], {x, 0,
       L0}]]]
uME[x_, t_, k_, A0_, B0_, L0_] := 
  A0 (x - L0) + B0 + 
   Sum[En  Cos[(n - 1/2) Pi/L0 x] Exp[-((n - 1/2) Pi/L0)^2 k t], {n, 
     1, 50}];
Manipulate[
 Plot[uME[x, t, k, A0, B0, L0], {x, 0, L0}, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}, 
  PlotRange -> {All, {23.8, 25.4}}, Frame -> True, 
  FrameLabel -> {{"u(t)", None}, {"x", Row[{"time ", t}]}}, 
  GridLines -> Automatic, GridLinesStyle -> LightGray, 
  PlotStyle -> Red, BaseStyle -> 14],
 {t, 0, 1, .01}]
```

### **Update**

I wanted to add this before but had no time. This below is the analytical solution to this problem using `DSolve`. By breaking the problem as above, into steady state and transient parts.  This is temporary solution for solving such problems with `DSolve` until it can add support for non homogeneous Neumann boundary conditions (version 12 may be?), which seems the reason why it can not solve it in one shot.

```
A0 = 1; B0 = 25; L0 = 1; k = 1; f = 25; tmax = 1;
(*solve steady state*)
uE = u[x] /. 
   First@DSolve[{u''[x] == 0, u[L0] == B0, u'[0] == A0}, u[x], x];

(*solve trasnient state*)
ic = v[x, 0] == f - uE;
bc1 = v[L0, t] == 0;
bc2 = Derivative[1, 0][v][0, t] == 0;
sol = v[x, t] /. 
   First@DSolve[{ D[v[x, t], t] == k D[v[x, t], {x, 2}], ic, bc1, 
      bc2}, v[x, t], {x, t}];
sol = sol /. {K[1] -> n, Infinity -> 40}; (*40 terms seems enough*)

(*add solutions*)
sol = sol + uE
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Here is animation of the above

```
Animate[Plot[Activate[sol] /. t -> i, {x, 0, L0}, 
  PlotRange -> {All, {23.8, 25.4}}, Frame -> True, 
  FrameLabel -> {{"u(t)", None}, {"x", Row[{"time ", i}]}}, 
  GridLines -> Automatic, GridLinesStyle -> LightGray, 
  PlotStyle -> Red, BaseStyle -> 14], {i, 0, 1, .01}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

In version 13 on Windows 10

```
heqn = D[u[x, t], t] == D[u[x, t], {x, 2}];
ic = u[x, 0] == 25;bc1 = u[1, t] == 25;
bc2 = D[u[x, t], x] == 1 /. x -> 0;
DSolve[{heqn, ic, bc1, bc2}, u[x, t], {x, t}]
```

$$\left\{\left\{u(x,t)\to \underset{K[1]=1}{\overset{\infty }{\sum }}\frac{8 e^{-\frac{1}{4} \pi ^2 t (2 K[1]-1)^2} \cos \left(\frac{1}{2} \pi  x (2 K[1]-1)\right)}{\pi ^2 (1-2 K[1])^2}+x+24\right\}\right\} $$

> ```
> {{u[x, t] -> 24 + x + Inactive[Sum][(8 E^(-(1/4) π^2 t (-1 + 2 K[1])^2) 
>         Cos[1/2 π x (-1 + 2 K[1])])/(π^2 (1 - 2 K[1])^2), {K[1], 1, ∞}]}}
> ```

Comment: Side note: same result is obtained in _v12.3.1_.

Comment: Its worth noting the answer does not come instantaneously!  Mathematica seems to  be doing a lot of thinking.