# Solve and plot PDE on restricted domain

Tags: plotting, differential-equations

I want Mathematica to solve
[image]

(I used a picture since when I use mathjax code the editor here says I might be using wrongly formatted code...)

So far, I have

```
pde = D[f[x,t], t] - D[f[x,t], {x,2}] == 0
sol = DSolve[{pde, f[x,0] == Min[x , 1 - x], f[0,t] == 0, f[1,t] == 0}, f[x,t], {x,0,1},{t,0,Infinity}]
```

But I am not sure if it is taken in account that $x \in (0,1)$ and $t > 0$.
Do I have to somehow use the Piecewise function as they do [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/147388/66744)?

My second question concerns plotting the solution.
The output of the above code snippet is

[image]

This is a function of two variables with values in $\mathbb{R}$, so it should easily be plottable. But when I use

```
Plot3D[f[x, t] /. sol, {x, 0, 1}, {t, 0, 4}]
```

as suggested [here](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/howto/SolveAPartialDifferentialEquation.html), I just get an empty 3d box.

Comment: Also, when using `DSolve`, Why do you write `f[x,t], {x,0,1},{t,0,Infinity}]`, instead of `f[x,t], {x,t}]` ?

Comment: @Nasser Because I want the solution only to be for $x \in (0,1)$ and $t > 0$.

Comment: You can add assumptions `DSolve[..., Assumptions -> {t > 0, 0 < x < 1}]` but it will not make any difference to the solution. It is analytical solution. You decide when running the solution, what range and time you can to look at.  This is different from `NDSolve`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try

```
ClearAll[f, x, t];
pde = D[f[x, t], t] - D[f[x, t], {x, 2}] == 0
bc  = {f[0, t] == 0, f[1, t] == 0};
ic  = {f[x, 0] == Min[x, 1 - x]};
sol = f[x, t] /. First@DSolve[{pde, ic, bc}, f[x, t], {x, t}];
sol = Activate[sol /. Infinity -> 20];

Manipulate[
 Quiet@Plot[sol /. t -> time, {x, 0, 1},PlotRange -> {Automatic, {0, .5}}],
 {{time, 0, "time"}, 0, .51, .01}
 ]
```

[image]

**Update**
Here is 3D plot requested

```
Plot3D[sol, {t, 0, .5}, {x, 0, 1}, PlotRange -> All, 
 AxesLabel -> {"time", "space", "f(x,t)"}, BaseStyle -> 14]
```

PLotted for $0<x<1$ and up to $t=0.5$ seconds.

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: @ViktorGlombik if you mean 3D? Yes. But you can see that it decays to zero after 0.5 seconds. Will add 3D soon. I use LICEcap program to export animation from Mathematica to gif file.

Comment: What does ```First@DSolve``` do?