# Solving a 1D diffusion equation

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving

I am new to Mathematica and I'm trying to find the analytical solution to the diffusion of excess pore pressure in a porous media using this equation:
$$
\frac{\partial P}{\partial t} - \alpha \nabla^2 P=0
$$
but at the base of the domain, where there is no flux. We assume the P(h) is linear at all times.

The domain is of unit length h[0,1]. The pressure P is dimensionless by scaling it with lithostatic weight at base. Thus P[0,1] across the entire domain.
At t=0, the pressure profile P is linear with a value of P(h=0) = 0 and at the bottom P(h=1)=1
I would like to get the analytical solution for the equation at the height h=0 (basal pressure).
BC are: at h=1, P=0 at all time, and at the lower BC (h=0), there is no flux.

How would one find the solution with Matematica (v12.2 for instance)

Thanks so much for the help!

Based on ([Analytic solution for 1D heat equation](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/127334/analytic-solution-for-1d-heat-equation))

I tried:

```
heqn=D[u[x,t],t]==a*D[u[x,t],{x,2}];
ic=u[x,0]==1-x;
bc1=u[1,t]==0;
bc2=D[u[x,t],x]==0/. x->0;
a=0.01; 
thisDir=ToFileName[
("FileName"/.NotebookInformation[EvaluationNotebook[]])
[[1]]];
SetDirectory[thisDir];

tset = LaplaceTransform[{heqn, bc1, bc2}, t, s] /. Rule @@ ic /. 
  HoldPattern@LaplaceTransform[a_, __] :> a

tsol[x_, s_] = u[x, t] /. First@DSolve[tset, u[x, t], x]

plotlst=Table[
  ListLinePlot[
   (Compile[{{x,_Real,1}},#]&@FT[tsol[x,#1]&,t])@Range[0,1,1/50],
   DataRange->{0,1},PlotRange->{0,1}],{t,10^-3,10,1/50}];

plotlst//ListAnimate
(*Export["a.gif",plotlst]*)
```

which requires an AddOn to be placed in AddOns/Application
(https://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/MathSource/5026/#downloads)

This seems to work to give a numerical solution. But I don't know how to get an analytical solution.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. What have you tried?

Comment: Please edit your question and add what you tried. Better to have all the information in the question rather than in the comments.

Comment: "This seems to work to give a numerical solution…" As mentioned in the linked post, what you've obtained here is already an analytic solution, it just involves an integral. (Don't forget `InverseLaplaceTransform` is an integral. )

Comment: Also, as shown in [Nasser's answer therein](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/127425/1871), `DSolve` can directly handle this problem. Please check the **Update** carefully.

Comment: I see. How can I specify that I want the analytical solution calculated only for a value of x, say x=0?

Comment: You need to add @xzczd in my comment or I won't get the reminder. You may want to read [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/43020/284701) to learn more about @. Then, please check the document of `ReplaceAll` (`/.`) carefully by pressing  **F1**.

Comment: @xzczd Thanks a lot; what does the "2" refer to in there: heqn=D[u[x,t],t]==a*D[u[x,t],{x,2}];

Comment: Please check the document of `D` carefully by pressing **F1**. BTW, if you can read Chinese, check this: https://note.youdao.com/ynoteshare/index.html?id=abd51087f44c0b6a41ff6022d549dc41

Comment: It's better to show us the specific equation. Generally speaking, analytic solution of PDE is hard to achieve, at least the methods in the linked post won't work on PDE whose diffusion coefficient, etc. are function of t, I'm afraid. Using `NDSolve` to obtain a numeric solution is more practical. Is analytic solution necessary for you?

Comment: @xzczd. I suppose the first step is to be sure there is no analytical solution, then if not a numerical one would be very useful too; should I edit this topic or make a new one? (cannot use the chat since I am too new apparently)

Comment: Since the new PDE is quite different from the one in this post, I think it's better to post a new question.