# Numerically solving a PDE set with a finiteness condition

Tags: differential-equations

The equations I am trying to solve are

1. $\frac{\partial (xu)}{\partial t} = \frac{\partial^2 (xu)}{\partial x^2}$
2. $\frac{\partial (xv)}{\partial t} = \frac{\partial^2 (xv)}{\partial x^2}$

Initial conditions:

1. $u(x,0)=1$
2. $v(x,0)=0$
3. $w(0)=0$

Boundary conditions:

1. $u(0,t)$ is finite
2. $v(g,t)=u(g,t)$
3. $(\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}) _{x\to g} = (\frac{\partial v}{\partial x})_{x\to g}$
4. $v(g,t)=w(t)$
5. $(\frac{\partial v}{\partial x}) _{x\to g} =\frac{\partial w}{\partial t}$

Where $g=1.1$.

The following is what I've tried so far:

```
g = 1.1; 
NDSolve[{D[u[x, t] x, t] == D[u[x, t] x, x, x], 
     D[v[x, t] x, t] == D[v[x, t] x, x, x], u[x, 0] == 1, v[x, 0] == 0, 
     w[0] == 0, u[g, t] == v[g, t], D[u[x, t], x] == D[v[x, t], x] /. 
       x -> g, w[t] == v[g, t], D[v[x, t], x] == D[w[t], t] /. x -> g}, 
   {u, v, w}, {t, 0, 10}, {x, 0, g}]
```

But it doesn't work. How can I solve the equations with *Mathematica*?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) and check the [faqs](http://goo.gl/kQNRaS)!   3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll show you a `LaplaceTransform`-based solution, mainly because it's the only approach I can think out that takes the finiteness condition into account properly.

First, by eliminating the intermediate variable $w$, the equation set becomes:

$$\frac{\partial (xu)}{\partial t} = \frac{\partial^2 (xu)}{\partial x^2}$$

$$\frac{\partial (xv)}{\partial t} = \frac{\partial^2 (xv)}{\partial x^2}$$

$$u(x,0)=1,\ v(x,0)=0$$

$$u(0,t)\ \text{is finite},\ v(g,t)=u(g,t),\ \frac{\partial u}{\partial x}\bigg| _{x= g} = \frac{\partial v}{\partial x}\bigg| _{x= g},\ \frac{\partial v}{\partial x}\bigg| _{x= g} =\frac{\partial v}{\partial t}\bigg| _{x= g}$$

Then we eliminate the derivatives of $t$ with `LaplaceTransform` and solve the obtained ODE set with `DSolve`:

```
eqn = {D[u[t, x] x, t] == D[u[t, x] x, x, x], 
      D[v[t, x] x, t] == D[v[t, x] x, x, x]};
ic = {u[0, _]  -> 1, v[0, _] -> 0};
bc = {u[t, g] == v[t, g], 
   D[u[t, x], x] == D[v[t, x], x] /. x -> g, 
      D[v[t, x], x] == D[v[t, x], t] /. x -> g};

teqn = LaplaceTransform[{eqn, bc}, t, s] /. ic /. 
  HoldPattern@LaplaceTransform[a_, __] :> a

tsol = {u[t, x], v[t, x]} /. First@DSolve[teqn, {u[t, x], v[t, x]}, x] // Simplify
(* tsol =     
     {(E^(-Sqrt[s] (2 g + x)) (-E^(Sqrt[s] (g + 2 x)) (1 + g s + g^2 (-1 + Sqrt[s]) s) + 
      E^(3 g Sqrt[s]) (1 + g (-2 Sqrt[s] + s) + g^2 (s - s^(3/2))) + 
      2 E^(Sqrt[s] (2 g + x)) Sqrt[s] (1 + g (-Sqrt[s] + s)) x + 
      2 E^(2 g Sqrt[s]) s^(3/2) (1 + g (-Sqrt[s] + s)) C[3] - 
      2 E^(2 Sqrt[s] x) s^(3/2) (1 + g (Sqrt[s] + s)) C[3]))/(2 s^(
    3/2) (1 + g (-Sqrt[s] + s)) x), (
 E^(-Sqrt[s] (2 g + x)) (E^(2 g Sqrt[s]) (1 + g (-Sqrt[s] + s)) - 
    E^(2 Sqrt[s] x) (1 + g (Sqrt[s] + s))) C[3])/((1 + g (-Sqrt[s] + s)) x)}; *)
```

> **Remark**
>
> `HoldPattern@LaplaceTransform[a_, __] :> a` is needed because `DSolve`
>   can't handle expression containing `LaplaceTransform` properly. Just
>   remember `u[t, x]` etc. in `teqn` actually represents
>   `LaplaceTransform[u[t, x], t, s]`.

As expected, `tsol` still contains a constant `C[3]` because we haven't impose the finiteness condition for $u(0,t)$, and this is the first obstacle.

How to overcome?

Let's observe the form of `tsol`. We'll easily find that it involves `1/x` term. Apparently **it should not exist in a solution that is bounded at $x=0$**, so the coefficient of it should be `0` at $x=0$. By `Collect`ing the `1/x` term:

```
Collect[tsol, 1/x, FullSimplify]
(* {1/s + (E^(-Sqrt[s] (2 g + x)) (-E^(Sqrt[s] (g + 2 x)) (1 + g (1 + g (-1 + Sqrt[s]))s)-
        E^(3 g Sqrt[s]) (-1 + g Sqrt[s]) (1 + g (-Sqrt[s] + s)) + 
       2 E^(2 g Sqrt[s]) s^(3/2) (1 + g (-Sqrt[s] + s)) C[3] - 
       2 E^(2 Sqrt[s] x) s^(3/2) (1 + g (Sqrt[s] + s)) C[3]))/(2 s^(
     3/2) (1 + g (-Sqrt[s] + s)) x), (
 E^(-Sqrt[s] (2 g + x)) (E^(2 g Sqrt[s]) (1 + g (-Sqrt[s] + s)) - 
    E^(2 Sqrt[s] x) (1 + g (Sqrt[s] + s))) C[3])/((1 + g (-Sqrt[s] + s)) x)} *)
```

The coefficient becomes clear, so does the value of `C[3]`:

```
solC = First@
  Solve[0 == (E^(-Sqrt[
         s] (2 g + x)) (-E^(Sqrt[s] (g + 2 x)) (1 + g (1 + g (-1 + Sqrt[s])) s) - 
         E^(3 g Sqrt[s]) (-1 + g Sqrt[s]) (1 + g (-Sqrt[s] + s)) + 
         2 E^(2 g Sqrt[s]) s^(3/2) (1 + g (-Sqrt[s] + s)) C[3] - 
         2 E^(2 Sqrt[s] x) s^(3/2) (1 + g (Sqrt[s] + s)) C[3])) /. x -> 0, C[3]]
```

Substitute `C[3]` to `tsol`, we obtain the transformed solution of $u$ and $v$:

```
{utfunc[s_, x_], vtfunc[s_, x_]} = Simplify[tsol /. solC] /. g -> 11/10
```

The final step is to transform the solution back, but a naive utilization of `InverseLaplaceTransform` fails,  so we encounter another obstacle and need to overcome it with numeric inverse Laplace transform. Here I'll use the `FT` function in [this package](http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/MathSource/5026/):

```
ufuncgenerator[x_] := 
 ufuncgenerator[x] = Module[{t}, Compile[#, #2] &[t, FT[utfunc[#, x] &, t]]]
vfuncgenerator[x_] := 
 vfuncgenerator[x] = Module[{t}, Compile[#, #2] &[t, FT[vtfunc[#, x] &, t]]]

ufunc = Function[{t, x}, ufuncgenerator[x][t]]
vfunc = Function[{t, x}, vfuncgenerator[x][t]]
```

> **Remark**
>
> A somewhat advanced function `Compile` is used for speeding up. Here
>   you can simply understand it as a fast `Function`. If you're not that
>   familiar with *Mathematica*, I don't recommend you to look into it.

Now $u$ can be easily calculated:

```
Plot3D[ufunc[t, x], {t, 0, 1}, {x, -1, 11/10}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

However, $v$ seems to be a little troublesome when $t$ is small:

```
Plot3D[vfunc[t, x], {t, 0, 1}, {x, -1, 11/10}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

But wait, isn't the solution of $v$ a bit too similar to $u$? Indeed, 2nd and 3rd b.c. indicate that the b.c. for $u$ and $v$ is the same, though their i.c.s are different, it's not strange that an inconsistent i.c. is largely (or even totally) ignored in the final solution. Can they be the same? To examine this guess, let's make the inverse transform with `NIntegrate`, thus we encountered the 3rd obstacle because   `NIntegrate` can't calculate [Bromwich integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_Laplace_transform#Mellin.27s_inverse_formula) properly if we naively choose something like $(1-i\infty)\to(1+i\infty)$ as the integrating path. Based on the experience in [this post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/113936/1871), I choose the path $(-\infty-i\infty)\to(-\infty-i\epsilon)\to(\epsilon-i\epsilon)\to(\epsilon+i\epsilon)\to(-\infty+i\epsilon)\to(-\infty+i\infty)$ where $\epsilon$ is a positive number:

```
nil[f_, t_, eps_: 10^-6, prec_: MachinePrecision] := 
 2 Re[1/(2 π I) NIntegrate[f@s Exp[s t], {s, -Infinity - eps I, eps - eps I}, 
      MaxRecursion -> 100, WorkingPrecision -> prec]] + 
  1/(2 π I) NIntegrate[f@s Exp[s t], {s, eps - eps I, eps + eps I}, 
    MaxRecursion -> 100, WorkingPrecision -> prec]

Plot3D[nil[(vtfunc[#1, x] &), t] // Re, {t, 0, 1}, {x, -1, 11/10}, 
  PlotRange -> All] // AbsoluteTiming
(* 1075.172149 <- a bit time consuming *)
```

> **Remark**
>
> `// Re` is added to remove the small imaginary part produced by
>   numeric error.

[image: Mathematica graphics]

OK, though the error near $t=0$ is still a little significant, it's much better.

Now we can slice at a small $t$ and compare:

```
dat = With[{t = 10^-3}, 
    ParallelTable[{ufunc[t, x], nil[(vtfunc[#1, x] &), t] // Re} // Quiet, {x, -1, 11/10,
       21/10/100}, DistributedContexts -> All]]; // AbsoluteTiming

(* {36.362744, Null} *)

ListLinePlot[dat // Transpose, PlotRange -> {0, 2}, 
 PlotStyle -> {{Thin}, {Dashed, Thick}}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Given that the solution matches well even at a small $t$ and the b.c. of $u$ and $v$ is the same, I think it's safe to say $u$ and $v$ is (at least almost) identical in this case.

Comment: Thank you for the solution. This will be very helpful for me. Thank you once again for your kind help.

Comment: @SAI You're welcome :) . Actually you don't need to accept the answer that fast, you can wait for 24 hours or even longer to see if someone has a better answer.