# Multiply integrand with -1, and the precision changes?

Tags: numerical-integration, numerics, precision-and-accuracy, implementation-details

"After multiplying the integrand of `NIntegrate` with `-1`, the `Precision` of the output will change." ← Sounds silly, huh? But this seems to be true at least for numerical integral internally using `"ExtrapolatingOscillatory"` method. Just try the following example:

```
Precision /@ 
 NIntegrate[{1, -1} BesselJ[0, x], {x, 0, ∞}, WorkingPrecision -> 32, 
  Method -> "ExtrapolatingOscillatory"]
```

> ```
> {31.0265, 25.0279}
> ```

*It's not necessary to set `Method -> "ExtrapolatingOscillatory"` manually in this sample, I added the option just to emphasize.*

Of course in the above example the difference of precision is small and isn't a big deal, but in some cases the difference can be drastic, for example the following I encountered in [this problem](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/113240/1871):

```
f[p_, ξ_] = -(5 p Sqrt[(5 p^2)/6 + ξ^2] )/(
  4 (-4 ξ^2 Sqrt[(5 p^2)/6 + ξ^2] Sqrt[(5 p^2)/2 + ξ^2] + ((5 p^2)/2 + 2 ξ^2)^2));

pmhankel[p_, sign_: 1, prec_: 32] := 
 NIntegrate[sign ξ BesselJ[0, ξ] f[p, ξ], {ξ, 0, ∞}, 
  WorkingPrecision -> prec, Method -> "ExtrapolatingOscillatory"]

preclst = Table[Precision@pmhankel[#, sign] & /@ Range@32, {sign, {1, -1}}]

ListLinePlot[preclst, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

*It's not necessary to set `Method -> "ExtrapolatingOscillatory"` manually in this sample, I added the option just to emphasize.*

How to understand the behavior? Except for calculating every integral twice and choosing the better one, how to circumvent the problem?

Comment: No. Doesn't sound silly to me. (1) NIntegrate does some symbolic pre-processing and anything you do you might affect that. That is reason enough to not find this surprising. If you haven't already, try ("SymbolicProcessing"->0). (2) And are you absolutely sure that changing the sign wouldn't significantly affect the evaluation for the numerical method you chose? That isn't obvious to me either. (https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/NIntegrateIntegrationStrategies.html#50593814)

Comment: Yes, I wouldn't expect `"ExtrapolatingOscillatory"` to work without preliminary symbolic processing, how else can the zeroes where the integrand will be split at be determined?

Comment: @Searke Thanks for the response. (1) With `"SymbolicProcessing->0"` the problem remains: `pmhankelTest[p_, sign_: 1, prec_: 16] := 
 NIntegrate[sign ξ BesselJ[0, ξ] f[p, ξ], {ξ, 0, ∞}, 
  WorkingPrecision -> prec, 
  Method -> {"ExtrapolatingOscillatory", "SymbolicProcessing" -> 0}];pmhankelTest[32, #, 32] & /@ {-1, 1}
` (2)  I tried `IntegrationMonitor` mentioned in [this answer](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/96663/1871), the `{"Boundaries", "Dimension", "Error", "GetRule", "Integrand"}` etc. seems to be all the same, and the only difference between `"Integral"` is the sign.

Comment: @J.M. I also tried manually implement `"ExtrapolatingOscillatory"`, and the problem doesn't show up in my (much slower) implementation: `zero[i_] := Piecewise[{{BesselJZero[0, i], i > 0}}];separatepmhankel[p_?NumericQ, sign : 1 | -1, i_?NumericQ, prec_] := 
  NIntegrate[sign ξ BesselJ[0, ξ] f[p, ξ], {ξ, zero@i, zero[i + 1]}, 
   WorkingPrecision -> prec, MaxRecursion -> 40];
manualpmhankel[p_, sign_: 1, prec_: 16] := 
 NSum[separatepmhankel[p, sign, i, prec], {i, 0, Infinity}, Method -> "AlternatingSigns",
   WorkingPrecision -> prec]; 
manualpmhankel[32, #, 32]&/@{1,-1} // AbsoluteTiming`

Comment: @xzczd Changing `BesselJ[0, x]` to `BesselJ[0, Re[x]]` solves the issue.

Comment: @Xavier Interesting. Using the code in the update of [this answer](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/96663/1871), I found that in this case `NIntegrate` internally switches to `"LevinRule"`, and the output is indeed the same as that with option `, Method -> "LevinRule"`. How about giving an answer?

Comment: @xzczd I was not sure why replacing `x` by `Re[x]` in your expression made it work, although I supposed this was related to some internal symbolic checks. The post you linked is interesting and your analysis provides the answer. Please feel free to answer your post, you've done all the work.

Comment: @Xavier OK, done.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The oddity in this case comes from `NSum` which is being called in a certain way from `NIntegrate`. This is a simple example that has roughly the same behavior (note in this case the exact result is known to be $\mp \ln 2$):

```
NSum[(-1)^n/n, {n, 1, Infinity}, 
          Method -> {"AlternatingSigns", Method -> "WynnEpsilon"}, WorkingPrecision -> 32]

(* -0.6931471805599453094172318803247 *)

NSum[-(-1)^n/n, {n, 1, Infinity}, 
          Method -> {"AlternatingSigns", Method -> "WynnEpsilon"}, WorkingPrecision -> 32]

(* 0.693147180559945309417232 *)
```

where the second result has several digits fewer than the first.

Is that a bug? Not necessarily, because both results have at least 16 correct digits which certainly attains the default `PrecisionGoal`, which is `WorkingPrecision/2`.

Still, I agree the consistency could be improved in this case and I have filed a report for the developers to take a look.

---

**Update**

This has been improved in the just released [Mathematica 11.0](http://www.wolfram.com/mathematica/new-in-11/).

Answer (score 7):

**Short answer:**

One workaround is to use `Method -> "LevinRule"` instead.

---

**Long answer:**

As mentioned by [Xavier](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/31159/xavier) in a comment above, changing `BesselJ[0, x]` to `BesselJ[0, Re[x]]` resolves the issue:

```
NIntegrate[{1, -1} BesselJ[0, Re@x], {x, 0, ∞}, WorkingPrecision -> 32, 
 Method -> "ExtrapolatingOscillatory"]
    Precision /@ %
```

> ```
> {0.99999999999999999999999999999979, -0.99999999999999999999999999999979}
> {32., 32.}
> ```

But why it works? Codes in the **UPDATE** of [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/96663/1871) solve the mystery. The truth is, `NIntegrate` has internally switched to `"LevinRule"`:

[image]

*Pictured by Simon Wood's [shadow](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/43187/1871).*

The output is indeed the same as that with option `Method -> "LevinRule`:

```
NIntegrate[{1, -1} BesselJ[0, x], {x, 0, ∞}, WorkingPrecision -> 32, 
 Method -> "LevinRule"]
Precision /@ %
```

> ```
> {0.99999999999999999999999999999979, -0.99999999999999999999999999999979}
> {32., 32.}
> ```

Notice in this case you'll be unable to adjust the `MaxRecursion` option because of a bug mentioned [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/24801/1871), but this seems not to be a big deal:

```
pmhankelLevin[p_, sign_: 1, prec_: 32] := 
 NIntegrate[sign ξ BesselJ[0, ξ] f[p, ξ], {ξ, 0, ∞}, 
  WorkingPrecision -> prec, Method -> "LevinRule"]

lst1 = pmhankel[#, -1] & /@ Range@32;
(* You'll see warning NIntegrate::ncvb and be unable to eliminate it 
   by adjusting MaxRecursion option because of the bug mentioned above 
   when generating lst2 and lst3 *)
lst2 = pmhankelLevin /@ Range@32;
lst3 = pmhankelLevin[#, -1] & /@ Range@32;
(* But the difference between lst2, lst3 and lst1 is negligible: *)
Max /@ {(lst1 + lst2)/lst1, (lst1 - lst3)/lst1}
```

> ```
> {2.27320119973*10^-6, 2.27320119973*10^-6}
> ```

Though a workaround is found, the reason why the precision is influenced by the sign when `"ExtrapolatingOscillatory"` method is used still remains unclear. I'm looking forward to answer(s) addressing the issue.