# Reuse local variable in declaration within With

Tags: evaluation, variable-definitions, localization

Considering the richness of Mathematica.SE, I am quite surprised I could not find my answer... I am very sorry if it is a duplicate.

Consider the following example:

```
With[{t1=0,t2=t1},t1+t2] (* -> t1 *)
```

I thought it would print `0` instead of `t1`.

Indeed, a `Trace` gives:

```
 Trace@With[{t1 = 0, t2 = t1}, t1 + t2]
 (* {With[{t1=0,t2=t1},t1+t2],0+t1,t1} *)
```

`t1` stays unevaluated.

Considering the complex usage of Hold and such attributes for a Mathematica beginner like me and the [documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/With.html) that states `With` has attribute `HoldAll`, I tried inserting `Evaluate` at various places, and also tried replacing `With` by `Module` (I admit the difference between `With` and `Module` is not obvious to me), but nothing printed me `0` instead of `t1`.

How can I inform Mathematica to evaluate `t2=t1` with `t1` and `t2` declared within `With`?

Edit: Thanks to the first comments and answer, some usefull and closely related question and answers can be found [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/10432/how-to-avoid-nested-with/10451#10451).

Comment: There are really good explanations of lexical and dynamic scoping [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6236458/plot-using-with-versus-plot-using-block-mathematica/6236808#6236808) and [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/559/what-are-the-use-cases-for-different-scoping-constructs). In your example, you can nest two `With`s if you don't want to try `Block`: `With[{t1 = 0}, With[{t2 = t1}, (t1 + t2)]]`

Comment: This is well known. This is how Mathematica works. nothing new. Try `Module[{x=0,y=x},Print[y]]` and it will print `x` and not `0`. Mathematica does not update the parameters `on the fly`. Hence it does not use the updated value just assigned to. This is how it always been.

Comment: The rule of thumb I use, so that I do not make a mistake like this, (thinking I set some variable to some value, but it is not), is to never use `p1=p2` at all in the local variables list. If you must set `p2` to `p1`, do that after the parameter list, here-->  `Module[{p1=0,p2},  p2=p1....]` You just have to remember this.

Comment: @SimonWoods it is not exactly the same question as some people have to know the answer of this one: "Nest your `With`" before reading this *very interesting* q/a you're refering to. In fact, I was just reading this one during you commenting.

Comment: @Nasser Thank you I will be using your advice as soon as now. Don't you think it is worth putting it as an answer so that I can close the question?

Answer (score 2):

`LetL` do exactly what you want. You can see it implementation [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/10451/2266).

```
LetL[{t1 = 0, t2 = t1}, t1 + t2]
```

> 0

Comment: How would one use `LetL` for `With` and `Module`? `Module[{LetL[{a = 1, b = a + 1, c = a + b + 2}, {a, b, c}]}, Print[a]; ]` did not work, and `Module[LetL[{a = 1, b = a + 1, c = a + b + 2}, {a, b, c}], Print[a]; ]` did not work. Is there a different syntax to use? The question is asking on using this in the context of `With` and `Module`, so I assume one can do that, I just can't figure the syntax :)

Comment: @Nasser what are the `Attributes` of `Module`? There in lies your answer. :P