# SyntaxInformation cannot reproduce syntax coloring of Block

Tags: syntax-highlighting

Is there any way to have the same syntax coloring with `SyntaxInformation` that `Block` has?

```
SyntaxInformation[func] = {"ArgumentsPattern" -> {{__}, _},
                        "LocalVariables" -> {"Solve", {1, Infinity}}};
func[vars : {__}, body_] := {};
```

After evaluating the above definition, the following two lines have different coloring:

```
func[{parameter, variable, constant = 0}, parameter + variable + constant]

Block[{parameter, variable, constant = 0}, parameter + variable + constant]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

As you can notice, any local variable with an initial value is not highlighted as local. I use the default syntax coloring, no changes were applied. `SyntaxInformation` accepts the following values: `{"Table", "Solve", "Integrate", "Limit", "Plot", "Manipulate"}` none of which produces the same behaviour as `Block` does. Perhaps someone knows about an undocumented option value?

Comment: +1. I was wondering about the same thing, for my LetL. Did not find the answer yet.

Comment: Maybe have a look at *GetFEKernelInit.tr*, which has a section called *Syntax coloring and other syntax information*. It's not very detail, but might provide some clues.

Comment: @Silvia Thanks for the pointer. Unfortunately, the syntax-coloring code in th .tr file refers to another textresource file (`FunctionInformation2.m`) containing syntax and usage information for almost all symbols, but not for `Block`, `Module`, `With` or `DynamicModule`. All their `"LocalVariables"` information is missing. The only new type for `"LocalVariables"` that I could found is `"D"` which might be identical to `"Integrate"`.

Comment: @IstvánZachar In *FunctionInformation.m* there is a line `{"Module", {{__}, _}}`, but nothing more. Guess we'll have to wait for someone from WRI to answer this puzzle.. (Strange I didn't get the comment notice. Sorry for reply late.)

Comment: Somewhat related: [What is ColorEqualSigns and how does one use it?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/59755/what-is-colorequalsigns-and-how-does-one-use-it)

Comment: Why the OP's question claims: "As you can notice, any local variable with an initial value is not highlighted as local."? If we evaluate `func[...constant=0...]`, the value of `constant` is going to be defined as 0 in the notebook, so it is not local and should not be colored as local.

Comment: @Stitch So why does `Block` color `constant` as a local variable then? Semantically, `constant` is not a local variable of course, but syntactically it is. I omitted the definition of `func` for sake of simplicity, but it is meant to be a scoping function which holds and localizes variables listed in its first argument. Even if you implement it as `Block`, syntax coloring won't be right.

Comment: Just for curiousity: how do you implement the same underlying behaviour in `func` as `Block` has. (So that `func` won't assign the provided value to the symbol `constant`, leaving it undefined after usage.) EDIT: With an attribute like HoldFirst?

Comment: @Gyebro Yes, you have to use `HoldAll` or similar. See for example Leonid's `LetL` [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/10451/89) which is a scoping construct similar to `With`.

Comment: FYI, I've asked WRI Support about that but no answer so far.

Comment: I've tried scraping the `"SystemFiles"` directory for any symbol containing `Syntax` in their name, but got nothing that gives new `SyntaxInformation` forms. I'll try expanding the scrape and including strings that have `"Syntax"` too.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Unfortunately, the current answer is "you can't". These are hard coded into the FE.  Module/With, in particular, are not treated as local variables since they are really lexically scoped.  If you look carefully, you'll see they are a slightly different color, and if you look in the syntax coloring prefs you'll see they have a dedicated section.

One of our own iternal wishlist items is to unify the implementation of these different color schemes as well as allowing new rules to be written in Wolfram Language so users can define they own local variable rules.  As with everything, this is just one of many competing features.  If this sounds like something you would want, I suggest you contact support with your request.  The more evidence we have that users are interested in this, the more likely it is we will spend the resources needed to make it happen.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  Would you kindly answer [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/66399/syntax-information-argumentspattern-for-function-of-function) question with an official "no"?  Many thanks!

Comment: Is the same true for `Compile` and `Function`?

Comment: Yes, if there's no "LocalVariable" rule returned by SyntaxInformation, it must be hard coded in the FE.