# Syntax information "ArgumentsPattern" for function of function?

Tags: syntax-highlighting

Is is possible to write `SyntaxInformation` of `"ArgumentsPattern"` for functions of the form:

```
f[a,b][x,y,z]
```

That is, I get syntax coloring such that the first set of square braces takes exactly 2 arguments, and the second set takes 3?

I tried this:

```
SyntaxInformation[f[_, _]] = {"ArgumentsPattern" -> {_, _, _}}
```

But it doesn't take it

Comment: I don't think so.  It must always be defined as `SyntaxInformation[f] = sompatterns` and `somepatterns` need to follow a very restricted syntax (as documented).  I think that's because they're interpreted by the front end, not the kernel.  This is of course just an educated guess. +1 though, interesting question.

Comment: Aw, that's too bad.  Thanks for the info though..

Comment: @Szabolcs Would you kindly turn your comment into an answer?  I'll accept and this question will go off the unanswered list.

Comment: Sorry, I really don't want to. [ I asked a similar question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/97411/12) where I was sure the answer would be "it's not possible" and it was possible in the end.  There's no harm in leaving it unanswered.  A developer from WRI might confirm that it is not possible or someone might actually find a solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is not currently possible.  The `SyntaxInformation` is set up to color "down values" (definitions of the form `f[x_,y_] := ...`), not "sub values" (definitons of the form `f[x_][y_] := ...`).

It's not a bad suggestion with the increase in operator forms.