# SyntaxInformation: take allowed options from multiple symbols – possible?

Tags: options, syntax-highlighting

Suppose I have a function like

```
Options[f] = {foo -> 1};
f[opt : OptionsPattern[{f,g}]] := h@g[Sequence @@ FilterRules[{opt}, Options[g]]]
```

I purposefully do not want to append `Options[g]` to `Options[f]` because I want the defaults to be inherited from `g` instead of setting them separately for `f`.

In this situation, is there a way to use `SyntaxInformation` with option highlighting for `f`?  It seems a naïve attempt results in red colouring for anything that is not in `Options[f]` (as the documentation states).  But I wanted to ask anyway, just in case I missed something and there's a way to get this working after all.

Example:

```
Options[g] = {bar -> 2}; (* in practice g could be a builtin *)
SyntaxInformation[f] = {"ArgumentsPattern" -> {OptionsPattern[{f, g}]}};
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

So it appears that arguments of `OptionsPattern` are not supported within [`SyntaxInformation`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/SyntaxInformation.html) (they are ignored).

Comment: Or perhaps people consider it bad practice to want to inherit the default option values from `g`? If so, why?

Comment: I use a different approach to inheriting default options [here](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/1529/4330). I think this is not directly useful to you, but it may still interest you and your feedback would be appreciated.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`SyntaxInformation` accepts undocumented `"OptionNames"` property. Using it we can explicitly define list of option names that will not be colored red.

```
ClearAll[f]
Options[f] = {foo -> 1};
SyntaxInformation[f] = {
    "ArgumentsPattern" -> {OptionsPattern[]},
    "OptionNames" -> {"bar"}
};
```

[image: f with bar]

With simple helper function extracting relevant option names:

```
optionNames = ToString /@ Apply[Join, Options /@ {##}][[All, 1]] &;

ClearAll[f, g]
Options[f] = {foo -> 1};
Options[g] = {bar -> 2};
SyntaxInformation[f] = {
   "ArgumentsPattern" -> {OptionsPattern[]}, 
   "OptionNames" -> optionNames[f, g]
};
```

[image: f with foo and bar]

Tested in *Mathematica* versions: 8.0, 9.0, 10.0, 10.1, 10.2 and 10.3.

Comment: +1, great find! Did you find this by doing ``PrintDefinitions@System`Utilities`GetSystemSyntaxInformation``?

Comment: @JacobAkkerboom No, I was looking at `SyntaxInformation@StyleBox` and there it was. I never seen ``System`Utilities`GetSystemSyntaxInformation``, thanks for showing it.