# A smarter nested With?

Tags: scoping, meta-programming

I often find myself writing code that looks a bit like this:

```
f[x_Integer] := 
  With[
   {
     range = Range[2] + x
   },
   With[
     {
       a = range[[1]],
       b = range[[2]],
       c = g[range]
     },
     h[a,b,c]
   ]
 ];
```

It would be nice if I could avoid [`With`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/With.html)s and just write

```
f[x_Integer] := 
  Let[
   range = Range[2] + x,
   {a,b} = range,
   c = g[range]
   ,
   h[a,b,c]
 ];
```

which would then automatically expand to the above at definition time.

What I'm asking is a bit similar to [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/10432/5485). There are additional requirements however. The new scoping construct (`Let` in the above) should:

- Group sequential disjoint assignments into single `With`s.
- Thread over `List` assignments.

Of course, it should not evaluate the left-hand-sides and the right-hand-sides of the assignments while expanding to `With`s.

Any proposals for such a scoping construct? (I'll post my version soon).

Comment: Your example doesn't need any scoping: `f[x_Integer] := h[Sequence@@#,g@#]&@(Range[2]+x)`

Comment: Why do you want to rewrite using `With` rather than preserving a higher abstraction such as `LetL`?

Comment: Also: what is the reason to prefer `With` over `Module`?  Assignments such as `{a,b} = range` are simpler with the latter.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard This should be a generalization of `LetL`, which doesn't do the two points I mentioned (Leonid's answer below does). `Module` doesn't allow you to do threaded assignments in the first argument, forcing you to write `Module[{a,b},{a,b}=Range[2];...]`, which is duplication I don't like. Also, it'd like to inject into held expressions -- another reason not to go with `Module`.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I guess, the idea is that we want to avoid user-defined functions in expanded code in definitions, both for efficiency reasons and because we may want to attach conditions. As to `With` vs `Module`, `With` is cleaner (manifestly no side effects), when one knows that variables won't change in the body.

Comment: If you are ok with undocumented features, you can supply multiple arguments to `With` in Mathematica 10.3 and above: e.g.  `With[{c = d}, {b = c}, {a = b}, a]`  (You'll have to also tolerate the red syntax coloring in the front end, or turn it off manually)  [and I just realized that it doesn't satisfy your second requirement of threading over `List` assignments]

Answer (score 14, accepted):

With this helper function:

```
SetAttributes[partThread, HoldAll];
partThread[l___, rhs_] :=
  Join @@ Replace[
    MapIndexed[Append[#, First@#2] &, Thread[Hold[{l}]]],
    Hold[s_, i_] :> Hold[s = rhs[[i]]],
    {1}];
```

The following modification of LetL seems to work according to your specs:

```
ClearAll[Let, let];
SetAttributes[{Let, let}, HoldAll];

Let /: Verbatim[SetDelayed][lhs_, rhs : HoldPattern[Let[__, _]]] := 
   Block[{With}, Attributes[With] = {HoldAll};
      lhs := Evaluate[rhs /. HoldPattern[With[{}, b_]] :> b]
   ];

Let[args___, body_] := let[{args}, body, {}, {}];

let[{}, body_, {}, _] := With[{}, body];

let[{Set[{s___}, rhs_], rest___}, body_, dec_, syms_] :=
   Module[{temp},
     partThread[s, temp] /. Hold[d___] :>
        let[{temp = rhs, d, rest}, body, dec, syms]
   ];

let[
   {Set[sym_, rhs_], rest___}, 
   body_, 
   {decs___}, 
   {syms___}
] /; FreeQ[Unevaluated[rhs], Alternatives[syms]] :=
     let[{rest}, body, {decs, sym = rhs}, {syms, HoldPattern[sym]}];

let[{args___}, body_, {decs__}, _] :=
   Block[{With},
     Attributes[With] = {HoldAll};
     With[{decs},Evaluate[let[{args}, body, {}, {}]]]
   ];
```

This works quite similarly to LetL. What it does in addition to `LetL` is that it collects previous declarations into auxiliary lists stored as extra arguments of `let`, so that it can group together disjoint declarations. It also threads over arguments, using the `partThread` helper function. In all other respects it is the same code as `LetL`.

Here is your example:

```
f[x_Integer] := 
   Let[range = Range[2] + x, {a, b} = range, c = g[range], h[a, b, c]];
```

we can check what was generated:

```
?f

Global`f
```

> ```
>   f[x_Integer]:=
>     With[{range=Range[2]+x},
>        With[{a=range[[1]],b=range[[2]],c=g[range]},h[a,b,c]]]
> ```

Comment: @MichaelE2 That was an evaluation leak, thanks for reporting. I seem to have fixed it, although perhaps not very elegantly.

Comment: You're welcome.  It seems fixed now.

Comment: @MichaelE2 Thanks for double-checking. I've not done this sort of things for some while, got a bit rusty.

Comment: That's a bit more elegant than what I had :). One question though: why doesn't `Alternatives` leak evaluation here?

Comment: @TeakeNutma because I wrapped symbols in `HoldPattern`, and use `Unevaluated` for the rhs. `HoldPattern` is exactly the right tool for the job here, since it is invisible to the pattern-matcher (and so `FreeQ` works fine).

Comment: Ah, *now* I see the HoldPattern on the RHS of that definition. Very nice. I do have one request though (sorry!): in cases like `Let[{a, b} = Range[2], {a, b}]` `Range[2]` gets evaluated twice. Any chance to let this expand into `With[{temp$=Range[2]},With[{a=temp$[[1]],b=temp$[[2]]},{a,b}]]`?

Comment: @TeakeNutma Yes, sure, that wasn't hard at all, see my edit. Thanks for the accept. This was a nice exercise, and this stuff can be actually useful too.

Comment: I'm having a bit of trouble bullet-proofing this. Upon changing the LHS of the second definition to `Let[args : HoldPattern[Set[_?symbolOrListQ, _] ...], body_]` (where `symbolOrListQ` is an appropriately defined recursive function) and adding another definition `Let[__] /; Message[Let::lvset] = Null;`, the `SetDelayed` expansion throws a very strange set of errors. Any idea what's going on? (Btw, you can change the attributes of `With` in the last definition to `HoldFirst` and remove the `Evaluate` there).

Comment: @TeakeNutma I can't reproduce this. With this definition:`ClearAll[symbolOrListQ];SetAttributes[symbolOrListQ,HoldAll];symbolOrListQ[_Symbol|_List]:=True;symbolOrListQ[_]=False;`, everything works fine (I tried the same example `f:=Let[...]`. I'd need to know exactly all the changes you've made to say more. Re: `HoldFirst` - not so simple. This may lead to evaluation leaks. In particular, here: `let[{}, body_, {}, _] := With[{}, body];`. Generally, I think this is a bad idea, makes the code potentially fragile. In my method, I explicitly override `HoldAll` lexically, in specific places.

Comment: [Here's the full code](https://gist.github.com/teake/d914c07f18e89094efa1). The problem arises when you give invalid local variable assignments in a `SetDelayed`. And thanks for pointing out my oversight regarding the `HoldFirst` -- these subtleties are easily overlooked.

Comment: @TeakeNutma This is rather crazy, the stuff going on there. The reason is that `With` is in fact broken inside `SetDelayed` (and inside `Let`/ `let`), so adding any more code you want to execute (rather than plain expansion) is dangerous, since that code can rely on `With` being unbroken. So, my original code was a walk on a thin ice, but still Ok, while the code with added message issuing was unlucky. Presumably, messages use `With` internally. Anyway, I fixed that, [here](https://gist.github.com/lshifr/ea6f39a3cfaf901b79e8), but for the expense of elegance, to some extent.

Comment: @TeakeNutma I'd add that at this point, this stuff becomes a bit scary. My feeling has been that this is pretty close to the limits of what I can control  :)

Comment: @TeakeNutma Another comment on all this code is that one can make it way more robust, but slightly less cool, by introducing a helper head `with`, making it `HoldAll`, and then replacing with `With` at the end. I just didn't go this way, but then one can safely use all language constructs inside, and perhaps it is better in terms of being more robust. Just less cool :)

Comment: `Let[a = x^2 + 1, b := Table[a, {x, t}], Block[{t = 5}, b]]` This does not work properly.

Comment: @expression The `SetDelayed` syntax for `With` is not documented, and I have not supported it in the code above either. It should be totally straightforward to add such support if needed.