# How to destructure local variables?

Tags: core-language

Why can't I use this

```
Where[{iw, ih} = ImageDimensions[i], ...]
```

instead of this

```
Where[dim = ImageDimensions[i], iw = dim[[1]], ih = dim[[2]], ...]
```

Comment: Excuse me, why the down-vote? This is a good question that might expose a limitation of the core language, perhaps you don't care for language design?

Comment: It has very little value in my opinion. But I reversed my down-vote.

Comment: possible duplicate of [A smarter nested With?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/64940/a-smarter-nested-with)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Presumably you are referring to `Where` from the `"GeneralUtilities`"` package.

You can see the definition for yourself:

```
Attributes[Where] = {HoldAll}

Where[expr_] := expr

Where[x_List, expr_] := With[x, expr]

Where[x_, expr_] := With[{x}, expr]

Where[x_, rest__, expr_] := Where[x, Where[rest, expr]]

Where[s : Verbatim[Set][x_List, y_], rest___, expr_] := 
  With[{x2 = Quiet[Replace[Hold[x], z_Symbol :> z_, {2}]]},
    Replace[y, {HoldPattern @@ x2 :> Where[rest, expr], _ -> $Failed}]]
```

If it is not written as you would like use this for inspiration and write your own. :-)

Comment: Ah, that casts some real light on the question. I still think the question is badly posed.