# Generating assignments and transforming code inside held forms when generating code

Tags: code-generation

I have been playing with slightly above trivial code manipulations in Mathematica. I thought Mathematica would be great for this kind of work because of rule replacement and expression manipulation, but I have been running in a lot of issues (I am an old lisp programmer and I love manipulating ASTs).

The code generation I am doing is taking DSP expressions like

```
{ f[x] -> a0 * x + b1 * y z^-1,
  y -> af0 * f[x] + bf1 * f[x] z^-1 + bf2 * f[x] z^-2 }
```

and transform them to code working on discrete samples by keeping sample delayed values (the values multiplied by `z^-n` in a ring buffer. The generated code (this is just pseudo code and by no means correct) is of the form:

```
Module[{ fxRingBuffer = {0, 0}, fxRingBufferIdx = 1,
         yRingBuffer = {0}, yRingBufferIdx = 1 },
   Function[x, 
      Module[{ fx = a0 * x + b1 * yRingBuffer[...], ...},
         fxRingBuffer[[fxRingBufferIdx]] = fx;
         fxRingBufferIdx = Mod[fxRingBufferIdx + 1, Length[fxRingBufferIdx]; 
         ...
         y]]]
```

Here is an actual example (see the link to the full code at the bottom):

```
expRecurseMakeFunction[{y → Expand@Simplify[x a0 + y z-1 b]}]

Hold[Module[{yrb$8738 = {0}, yidx$8739 = 1}, Function[x, Module[{ycur$8740},
    Sequence[{ycur$8740 = a0 x + b1 yrb$8738〚1 + Mod[-2 + yidx$8739, 1]〛}];
    Sequence[yrb$8738〚yidx$8739〛 = ycur$8740, yidx$8739 = 1 + Mod[yidx$8739, 1]];
ycur$8740]]]]
```

The approach I am taking is to use a template like this:

```
Hold[Module[ringBufferInitialization, 
    Function[x, 
       Module[{sampleUpdates},
          ringBufferUpdates;
          y]]]
```

and then doing code replacement. The problems I have been having is how to have the code I generate not be evaluated. I have reduced the issues to two toy examples. The first one is generating a list of `Set[var, val]` assignments to be plugged into `ringBufferInitialization` and `sampleUpdates` above. The approach I have taken is to generate `MySet` forms that are replaced by `Set` once they are safe inside the toplevel `Hold`:

```
generateAssignments[symbols_, values_] :=
  Hold[Module[assignments,
     someBody[]]] //. {
    assignments -> MapThread[MySet, {symbols, values}],
    MySet -> Set
    };
```

For example:

```
ClearAll[a, b, c, d];
generateAssignments[{a, b, c, d}, {1, 2, 3, 4}]

Hold[Module[{a = 1, b = 2, c = 3, d = 4}, someBody[]]]
```

Is there a better way to do this?

The other issue is replacing code inside forms with a `Hold*` attribute. For example, if any of my functions have the form `If[]`, replacing variable access with the form to access the ring buffers won't evaluate properly and cause problems. Here my solution is really half-baked, as I just replace my `If[]` blocks with `Piecewise[]`, which worked for my usecase. Again a toy example:

```
useLookupTable[body_, symbolMap_] :=
 body /. lookupForm[a_, idx_] :> symbolMap[a][[idx]]

useLookupTable[Hold[If[a > 1, lookupForm[b, 23], lookupForm[c, 24]]],
 <|a -> aLookup, b -> bLookup|>]

Hold[If[a > 1, <|a -> aLookup, b -> bLookup|>[b][[
   23]], <|a -> aLookup, b -> bLookup|>[c][[24]]]]
```

I was looking forward to manipulating my AST, but fighting the evaluation order was pretty frustrating, and I feel like I am missing some general mechanism (like the lisp quasiquote + splicing reader macros) to handle this case.

Here is a link to the (very hacky...) full code: [wavefolder DSP analysis](http://bl0rg.net/~manuel/wavefolder.nb.pdf)

**Edit:**

Here is an approach using `Inactive` which seems nice:

```
generateAssignments[symbols_, values_] :=
  Hold[Module[assignments,
      Print[a, b, c, d]]] //. {
     assignments -> MapThread[Inactive[Set], {symbols, values}]
     } // Activate;
```

Comment: Sorry about the two questions, I feel they are actually the same. The problem with the example I posted is that if I generate the `Set[a, 1]` on its own, I will end up with `a` being assigned, instead of it being replaced verbatim into my `Hold[]` template.

Comment: The `Inactive` indeed seems like a good way to handle this (see my edit). This leaves me with the second part (replacing code in `Hold` forms), which I can extract to another question.

Comment: It seems to me that this question is a rather straightforward duplicate of either [(3864)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/3864/121),
[(28610)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/28610/121), or 
[(31708)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/31708/121) for the first part and [(29317)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/29317/121) for the second, with maybe a reference to [(20328)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/20328/121) (basic) and [(2352)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/2352/121) (advanced).  Nevertheless I am glad the respondents saw it otherwise.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I think, your question is as much about techniques of evaluation control, as it is about code generation. I will show several different methods to achieve the first result you asked for, which would illustrate different approaches and techniques of evaluation control.

#### Working with unevaluated parts

You can, if you want to, work with parts of your expression, carefully avoiding evaluation leaks. This method is perhaps one of the most difficult and least economical, since it requires a good knowledge of evaluation control, and even then can be tedious and error-prone, if one doesn't stay really focused.

I will first show the solution step by step, and then assemble it into a function. We will start with the lists of variables and values, but first let us give some of the variables some global values, to test that our solution will not capture global bindings:

```
ClearAll[a, b, c, d];
a = 10;
b = 20;
{{a, b, c, d}, {1, 2, 3, 4}}

(* {{10, 20, c, d}, {1, 2, 3, 4}} *)
```

The idiom with `MapThread` that you suggested is a good one, and we will use it. But not with `Set` directly. We could use a temporary wrapper, and replace it with `Set` afterwards, but I will pick a different road. Here is what we would like to do:

```
MapThread[Hold[#1 = #2] &, {{a, b, c, d}, {1, 2, 3, 4}}]

(* {Hold[10 = 1], Hold[20 = 2], Hold[c = 3], Hold[d = 4]} *)
```

But this doesn't work. The first step in the right direction will be to insert `Unevaluated`:

```
MapThread[Hold[#1 = #2] &, Unevaluated@{{a, b, c, d}, {1, 2, 3, 4}}]

(* {Hold[10 = 1], Hold[20 = 2], Hold[c = 3], Hold[d = 4]} *)
```

This, however, is not good enough. The premature evaluation happens also in `Function` during the parameter-passing stage, and thus we need this:

```
step1 = MapThread[
  Function[Null, Hold[#1 = #2], HoldAll], 
  Unevaluated @ {{a, b, c, d}, {1, 2, 3, 4}}
]

(* {Hold[a = 1], Hold[b = 2], Hold[c = 3], Hold[d = 4]} *)
```

We are good now, but what we need is we need is single `Hold` around an assignment list, while we have a `List` of assignments each wrapped in individual `Hold`. The useful trick here is to use `Thread[#, Hold]&`, so that:

```
step2 = Thread[#, Hold] &@step1

(* Hold[{a = 1, b = 2, c = 3, d = 4}] *)
```

This is closer to what we need, but now we want to wrap `Module` around the variable / assignment list, and get it into `Hold`. One of the simplest ways to do this is by using rules, which would be a version of a so-called [injector pattern](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/1937/81):

```
step3 = Replace[step2, Hold[a_List] :> Hold[Module[a, someBody[]]]]

(* Hold[Module[{a = 1, b = 2, c = 3, d = 4}, someBody[]]] *)
```

which is the final result.

As a function, the resulting code would look like this:

```
ClearAll[genMT];
SetAttributes[genMT, HoldAll];
genMT[vars : {___Symbol}, vals_List] :=
  Composition[
    Replace[Hold[a_List] :> Hold[Module[a, someBody[]]]],
    Thread[#, Hold] &
  ] @ MapThread[
    Function[Null, Hold[#1 = #2], HoldAll],
    Unevaluated @ {vars, vals}
  ]
```

Where I used an operator form for `Replace`. So, for example, we have

```
genMT[{a, b, c, d}, {1, 2, 3, 4}]

(* Hold[Module[{a = 1, b = 2, c = 3, d = 4}, someBody[]]] *)
```

Note that this method is hard. We had to use several advanced techniques (evaluation control, a trick with `Thread`, injector pattern) in combination. I have shown this method to illustrate the "brute-force" approach, which is certainly possible, but is not the most economical or elegant one. One reason why this approach is hard is that we don't use rules and pattern-matching to the full extent.

#### Using holding symbolic containers for expression transformations

There is an alternative way to build an expression we need. I frequently find it more convenient than other methods, since it often gives you more control, and makes it easier to control evaluation.

The method is to replace iteration (where it is necessary) with recursion, and use symbolic containers with `Hold*` attributes to transform unevaluated expressions into suitable form. For the case at hand, it may look like this:

```
ClearAll[a, b, c, d, gen];
SetAttributes[gen, HoldAll];
gen[vars : {___Symbol}, vals_List] := gen[{}, vars, vals];
gen[{a___}, {v_, rvars___}, {val_, rvals___}] :=
  gen[{a, Set[v, val]}, {rvars}, {rvals}];
gen[a_List, {}, {}] := Hold[Module[a, someBody[]]];
```

We can test:

```
a = 1;
b = 2;
gen[{a, b, c, d}, {1, 2, 3, 4}]

(* Hold[Module[{a = 1, b = 2, c = 3, d = 4}, someBody[]]] *)
```

The way this works is that `gen` function gradually picks elements from lists of variable names and values and accumulates the assignments built out of them. When the lists are exhausted, we obtain a list of assignments in an unevaluated form, and can then generate the code we need, straightforwardly.

#### Using Block trick

The method I will describe here is completely different. It is based on the ability of `Block` to make (almost) any symbol "forget" its definitions temporarily. This may be used to non-trivially change the evaluation order. For the case at hand, it will be one of the most economical methods.

Here is the code:

```
ClearAll[genB];
SetAttributes[genB, HoldAll];
genB[{vars___Symbol}, vals_List] :=
  Block[{vars, Set, Module, Hold},
    SetAttributes[Module, HoldRest];
    Hold[Module[MapThread[Set, {{vars}, vals}], someBody[]]]
  ]
```

The way this works is that it temporarily switches off the standard behavior of `Set`, `Module`, and `Hold`, making them just symbolic wrappers during the evaluation of the body of the `Block`. This is what we need here for code generation. I had to attach a temporary `HoldRest` to `Module` inside `Block`, so that the body of the `Module` (`someBody[]`) is kept unevaluated.

We can test:

```
genB[{a, b, c, d}, {1, 2, 3, 4}]

(* Hold[Module[{a = 1, b = 2, c = 3, d = 4}, someBody[]]] *)
```

#### More advanced techniques

One can base more formal, universal and advanced techniques on methods I have described above, by generalizing and automating them to fit one's needs.

For example, some time ago I've developed code generator based on the generalized `Block` trick used above. The seriously simplified version of this technique I posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8741671/unevaluated-form-of-ai/8746584#8746584), and with the help of the `FrozenCodeEval` function defined there, the solution to your problem becomes trivial:

```
FrozenCodeEval[
  Hold[Module[MapThread[Set, {{a, b, c, d}, {1, 2, 3, 4}}], someBody[]]],
  {MapThread}
]

(* Hold[Module[{a = 1, b = 2, c = 3, d = 4}, someBody[]]] *)
```

basically, here you just tell `FrozenCodeEval`, which heads should evaluate (in this case, only `MapThread`), and all the rest are kept "frozen". This technique I have also illustrated (among some others) in [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/22259/81).

Another possible (but IMO somewhat less powerful) technique is to use rules. I have illustrated this technique in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6214946/how-to-dynamically-generate-mathematica-code/6215394#6215394).

Yet another technique can be based on generalizing the holding symbolic container approach I described above. One good example of this approach is the `LetL` macro (nested `With` replacement), which is described in [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/10451/81), and particularly its [more complex extension](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/64944/81). This method is the one I've preferred recently.

One can also base code generation on introducing several (many) inert heads (like `mySet`), and replacing them with some "actual" heads (like `Set`) at the end, after the code has been generated. This was one of your original suggestions, and is certainly also a possibility.

Finally, one may implement a macro system, which would provide macros in a way similar to `Lisp`. However, that would require introducing read-time, which currently sort-of exists (parsing code to expressions), but can't really be used much. This is possible to do if one implements an alternative code loader, that would parse code to symbolic expression and give the user access to that parsed code before actually evaluating it.

#### Why I think that `Inactive` is in general not an answer

This is certainly an opinionated topic, but I personally did not see (almost) any case where `Inactive` would solve a problem of evaluation control (outside math-related functionality), in a way that would be simpler than other means of evaluation control.

From the viewpoint of evaluation control, the problem of `Inactive` is that while it inactivates a given head, it does not hold the arguments of that head, so they can freely evaluate. And the effort needed to prevent them from doing so will most of the time invalidate all the benefits of using `Inactivate`, as compared to `Hold`, `Unevaluated` etc.

For example, in our case (taking your code):

```
Hold[Module[assignments, Print[a, b, c, d]]] //. {
  assignments -> MapThread[Inactive[Set], {{a, b, c, d}, {1, 2, 3, 4}}
]} // Activate
```

(* Hold[Module[{10 = 1, 20 = 2, c = 3, d = 4}, Print[a, b, c, d]]] *)

shows that the global bindings to `a` and `b` were picked up in this method. And avoiding that will make the code no less complex than the first alternative I have shown above.

#### Summary

There exist several (many) techniques, allowing one to dynamically generate Mathematica code. The ones I have illustrated are based on

- Direct manipulations with unevaluated parts of expressions
- Using symbolic holding containers for expression transformations
- Using `Block` trick

One can come up with more advanced / general / universal frameworks for code generation. The ones I mentioned are based on

- `Block` trick (code "freezing")
- Symbolic holding containers
- Repeated rule application to held expressions
- Inert intermediate (temporary) heads
- (Read-time) macros

Which one to use depends on the case. For simple cases, some of the simpler techniques may be just enough. If you need to routinely generate code, you may be better off with some heavier but more general and systematic approach.

Comment: @ManuelOdendahl Well, thanks, accepting within a few seconds of me posting an answer is impressive, but perhaps you could wait for a bit to at least read it - who knows, may be I got tired and posted a load of junk ...

Comment: uh i am a bit new to asking questions here, i must have clicked on it without knowing what it would do. thanks again, i read through the answer and it is indeed spot on.

Comment: @ManuelOdendahl Don't take is seriously, I was just kidding :). Actually, a good practice when asking / accepting a best answer is to give answerers some time (like half a day, a day or two) to answer before marking some answer as accepted, even if you have some really good answers already - because that would encourage others to contribute. But this is entirely up to the asker, and you can of course accept the answer you like any time you want.

Comment: If I had seen this question back in January I would probably just have closed it with multiple references in the comments (see e.g. my comment above) but I am glad instead that you wrote this.  You once again think to cover angles that don't even occur to me.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Well, thanks ). I thought it would give me a nice opportunity to systematically list these techniques, if not explain them in detail.

Comment: Do you have a more recent and complete version of FrozenCodeEval to share?  I think I should start using either that or jkuczm's code rather than bespoke evaluation control in each case as I am largely doing now.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I do have that (more complete, but not more recent), but it will take me some time to take the dust off that code, check it and publish. I will put it high on my todo list, but this will have to wait for several days. These days are extremely busy for me.

Comment: Please do not put it high on your list only for my sake!  I am very lazy these days and in reply you should be too. :^)  If at some time in the future you see fit to release it as (part of?) a stand-alone package just let me know.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Sure. You will be the first to know.

Answer (score 13):

Since OP mentions Lisp quasiquote mechanism, maybe we can implement something similar in *Mathematica*.

Disclaimer: I've never written a line of code in any of Lisp dialects.

In *Mathematica* rules for evaluation of an expression are "attached" to symbols in this expression through various [`...Values`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/96/14303) and [`Attributes`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Attributes.html) (evaluation of many built-in symbols is implemented in lower level than `...Values` but still it's "attached" to the symbol). To prevent evaluation of expression we don't need to hold whole expression, it's enough to "isolate" all symbols inside expression. This "isolation" can be achieved by wrapping symbol with some other symbol for which we know that it will remain unevaluated.

If we take

```
ClearAll[a, b, c, f, g]
expr = f[a, g[b]][c]
```

expression and wrap `f` with some head, let's say `quoted`:

```
quoted[f][a, g[b]][c]
```

we will prevent usage of `f`'s [`DownValues`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DownValues.html), `SubValues` and `Attributes`, which like e.g. [`Orderless`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Orderless.html) also can rewrite expression. If we add [`HoldFirst`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/HoldFirst.html), [`HoldAll`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/HoldAll.html), or [`HoldAllComplete`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/HoldAllComplete.html) attribute to `quoted` we will prevent usage of `f`'s [`OwnValues`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/OwnValues.html), but to be sure that any of `f`'s [`UpValues`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/UpValues.html) that could match `quoted[f]` also won't be used we choose `HoldAllComplete`.

To prevent any evaluation in above expression we can wrap all symbols with `quoted`:

```
quotedExpr = quoted[f][quoted[a], quoted[g][quoted[b]]][quoted[c]]
```

This expression has the same structure as "non-quoted" expression in the sense that at each [`Part`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Part.html) of "quoted" expression is quoted version of the same `Part` from "non-quoted" expression, for example `Part` `1` or `0, 2`:

```
expr[[1]]
quotedExpr[[1]]
(* c *)
(* quoted[c] *)

expr[[0, 2]]
quotedExpr[[0, 2]]
(* g[b] *)
(* quoted[g][quoted[b]] *)
```

If we want some parts of our expression to be evaluated, we can easily mix "quoted" symbols with "non-quoted" ones, which is the main advantage of this approach over wrapping whole expression with single holding wrapper.

Of course manual wrapping of all symbols with `quoted` would be tedious, so we can define function `quote` that will do this automatically. Since often we want to quote whole expression except some parts, that we want to evaluate, we can define `quasiquote` function that quotes every symbol except those inside expression with head `unquote`.

Since version 10, *Mathematica* has similar mechanism built-in. We can [`Inactivate`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Inactivate.html) expressions, but, as Leonid mentioned in [his answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/103278/14303), it'll inactivate (wrap with [`Inactive`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Inactive.html) head) only symbols that are heads of expressions. We can overcome this limitation by defining own functions wrapping all symbols with `Inactive`. Advantage of this approach, over custom `quoted` symbol, is that *Matematica* provides [`IgnoringInactive`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/IgnoringInactive.html) function which simplifies matching/replacing parts of inactive expressions. But there are few disadvantages. `Inactive` has `HoldFirst` and not `HoldAllComplete` attribute so there is a possibility of evaluation leak through `UpValues`. It was designed only for heads of expressions and when used for non-heads its formatting is inconsistent. Since inactivation serves slightly different purposes, mixing it with quoting may be a bad idea. Nonetheless implementation based on `Inactive` is available in [second revision of this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/revisions/103286/2).

## Implementation

#### Core functions

Core of the system is based on following four functions and `quoted` head:

`quote` replaces all symbols (except excluded ones) by symbols wrapped with `quoted`. Expressions, matching pattern given as value of `"ExcludedForms"` option, are not quoted. It accepts optional second argument used as pattern for expressions that will be excluded in addition to ones matching pattern from option.

`quasiquote` works like `quote`, but, by default, doesn't quote expressions with head `unquote`.

`unquote` is head used to mark parts, of `quasiquote` expressions, that shouldn't be quoted.

`eval` wraps expression with head taken from `"Head"` option, with default being `Identity`, and strips `quoted` wrappers.

```
ClearAll[quote, quasiquote, unquote, eval, quoted]

SetAttributes[{quote, quasiquote, unquote, quoted}, HoldAllComplete]

Options[quote] = {
    "ExcludedForms" -> 
        List | Rule | RuleDelayed | Hold | HoldComplete | HoldForm | 
        Slot | SlotSequence | Alternatives | Default | Blank | 
        BlankSequence | BlankNullSequence | Except | Optional | Pattern |
        PatternTest | PatternSequence | Repeated | RepeatedNull | 
        Longest | Shortest | Verbatim | HoldPattern | OptionsPattern | 
        IgnoringInactive |
        _quoted | _CompiledFunction | _Experimental`NumericalFunction |
        _InterpolatingFunction | _BSplineFunction | _BezierFunction |
        _ParametricFunction | _NDSolve`StateData |
        _NDSolve`FiniteDifferenceDerivative | _BooleanFunction | _Root |
        _AlgebraicNumber | _DifferenceRoot | _DifferentialRoot | _FittedModel |
        _DataDistribution | _SurvivalModel | _NearestFunction |
        _LinearSolveFunction | _Image | _Image3D | _StateSpaceModel |
        _TransferFunctionModel | _Graphics | _Graphics3D | _GraphicsComplex |
        _Point | _Line | _Polygon | _Directive | _TemporalData | _CellObject |
        _ColorDataFunction | _ColorProfileData | _ByteArray | _CoxModel |
        _EventData | _HypothesisTestData | _LibraryFunction |
        _LiftingFilterData | _NotebookObject | _OptimumFlowData |
        _SeriesData | _StructuredArray | _WeightedData,
    "ExtraRules" -> {}
};
quote[expr_,
    extraExclusion : Except[_?OptionQ] | PatternSequence[],
    opts___?OptionQ
] :=
    Unevaluated[expr] /. Flatten@{
        OptionValue[quote, {opts}, "ExtraRules"],
        excluded :
            extraExclusion | OptionValue[quote, {opts}, "ExcludedForms"] :>
                excluded,
        sym : Except[HoldPattern@Symbol[___], _Symbol] :> quoted[sym]
    }

quasiquote[expr_,
    extraExclusion : Except[_?OptionQ] | PatternSequence[],
    opts___?OptionQ
] :=
    quote[expr, extraExclusion | _unquote, opts]

unquote[expr_] := expr

Options[eval] = {"Head" -> Identity, "Pattern" -> _};
eval[expr_, opts___?OptionQ] :=
    OptionValue[eval, {opts}, "Head"][expr] /. 
        HoldPattern[quoted][x : OptionValue[eval, {opts}, "Pattern"]] :> x
```

#### Utilities

Additional functions that simplify matching/replacing parts of quoted expressions and help with evaluation control.

`quoteNonPattern` is like `quasiquote` but, additionally, leaves parts of expressions, that have special meaning in pattern matching, non-quoted.

`quoteEvaluated` first evaluates given expression, then quotes result. It accepts optional second argument that controls how many "evaluation steps" are performed before quoting, this functionality is inspired by [Mr.Wizard's `step` function](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/1447/14303).

`quoted` has some formatting defined (quoted symbols have `LightGray` backgrounds), for *Mathematica* versions >= 10 we piggyback on formatting of `Inactive` to get nice formatting for quoted versions of functions like `Plus` or `Set`.

```
ClearAll[quoteNonPattern, quoteEvaluated]

SetAttributes[{quoteNonPattern, quoteEvaluated}, HoldAllComplete]

quoteNonPattern[expr_,
    extraExclusion : Except[_?OptionQ] | PatternSequence[],
    opts___?OptionQ
] :=
    Quiet[
        quasiquote[expr,
            extraExclusion | Alternatives | Except | HoldPattern | 
            IgnoringInactive | Literal | Longest | Optional | 
            OrderlessPatternSequence | PatternSequence | RepeatedNull | 
            Shortest | _Blank | _BlankNullSequence | _BlankSequence |
            _OptionsPattern
            ,
            "ExtraRules" -> {
                OptionValue[quote, {opts}, "ExtraRules"],
                (h : Condition | PatternTest | Repeated)[patt_, rest___] :> 
                    h[quoteNonPattern[patt, extraExclusion, opts], rest],
                Verbatim[Pattern][name_, patt_] :> 
                    Pattern[name, quoteNonPattern[patt, extraExclusion, opts]],
                Verbatim[Verbatim][verb_] :> 
                    Verbatim@quasiquote[verb, extraExclusion, opts]
            },
            opts
        ],
        RuleDelayed::rhs
    ]


quoteEvaluated[expr_,
    (steps_ /; steps === Infinity) | PatternSequence[],
    (extraExclusion_ /; !IntegerQ[extraExclusion] && !OptionQ[extraExclusion]) |
        PatternSequence[],
    opts___?OptionQ
] :=
    quote[#, extraExclusion, opts] &@expr
quoteEvaluated[expr_, 
    steps_ /; steps === 0,
    (extraExclusion_ /; !IntegerQ[extraExclusion] && !OptionQ[extraExclusion]) |
        PatternSequence[], 
    opts___?OptionQ
] :=
    quote[expr, extraExclusion, opts]
quoteEvaluated[expr_,
    steps_ /; IntegerQ[steps] && Positive[steps],
    (extraExclusion_ /; !IntegerQ[extraExclusion] && !OptionQ[extraExclusion]) |
        PatternSequence[], 
    opts___?OptionQ
] :=
    (* Based on: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/1447/14303 *)
    Module[{i = 0, tag},
        Catch[
            quote[#, extraExclusion, opts]& @ TraceScan[
                If[i++ >= steps, Throw[#, tag]]&,
                Unevaluated[expr],
                TraceDepth -> 1
            ],
            tag,
            (* TODO: When TraceScan encounters Evaluate[...] expression, 
               it passes to function, from its first argument,
               HoldForm[HoldForm[Evaluate][...]],
               so we should remove not only external HoldForm,
               but also the one directly wrapping Evaluate,
               but the same expression is passed when TraceScan encounters
               HoldForm[Evaluate][...],
               where we should remove only external HoldForm.
               How can we distinguish these two situations? *)
            First@quote[#1, extraExclusion, opts] &
        ]
    ]


$quotedStyle = {Background -> LightGray};

If[$VersionNumber >= 10,
    ClearAll[inactiveToQuoted];
    SetAttributes[inactiveToQuoted, HoldAllComplete];
    inactiveToQuoted[Inactive[h_][args___]] := quoted[h][args];
    inactiveToQuoted[expr_] := expr;

    quoted /: MakeBoxes[quoted[h_Symbol][args___], StandardForm] :=
        With[{$quotedStyle = $quotedStyle},
            TagBox[
                MakeBoxes[Inactive[h][args], StandardForm] /. {
                    (Tooltip -> tooltip_String /;
                        StringMatchQ[tooltip, "Inactive[*]"]) :>
                            (Tooltip -> "quoted" <> StringDrop[tooltip, 8]),
                    (BaseStyle -> "Inactive") -> (BaseStyle -> $quotedStyle),
                    StyleBox[boxes_, "Inactive"] :>
                        StyleBox[boxes, $quotedStyle]
                },
                inactiveToQuoted
            ]
        ]
 ]
 quoted /: MakeBoxes[quoted[x_Symbol], StandardForm] := 
     TagBox[
         MakeBoxes[x, StandardForm],
         quoted,
         BaseStyle -> $quotedStyle, SyntaxForm -> "Symbol",
         Tooltip -> ToString[quoted[x], InputForm]
     ]
```

## Usage examples

Example of quoted expression, we define function `h` and variable `x` to show that their evaluation is properly held:

```
ClearAll[f, g, h, b, x]
x = 5;
h[x_] := 2 x

quasiquote@{
    1 + 2 + x,
    unquote@{(* this part is unquoted, so it'll be evaluated *)
        3 + 4,
        quasiquote@{(* this part is quoted again so it won't be evaluated *)
            5 + 6,
            unquote[7 + 8] (* and this will evaluate *)
        },
        quote@{(* this won't evaluate *)
            9 + 10,
            (* following will also not evaluate,
               since it's inside quote not quasiquote *)
            unquote[11 + 12]
        }
    },
    # + 1 &[3],
    f[g[x]][h[b]]
}
% // eval
(* {
       1 + 2 + x,
       {
           7,
           {5 + 6, 15},
           {9 + 10, unquote[11 + 12]}
       },
       (#1+1&)[3],
       f[g[x]][h[b]]
   } *)
(* {8, {7, {11, 15}, {19, 23}}, 4, f[g[5]][2 b]} *)
```

Example of generation of code of `Module` from OP:

```
ClearAll[a, b, c, d]
a = 1;
b = 2;
quotedModuleCode =
    quasiquote@Module[
        unquote[MapThread][Set, {{a, b, c, d}, {1, 2, 3, 4}}],
        Print[a, b, c, d]
    ]
eval[%, "Head" -> HoldComplete]
(* Module[{a = 1, b = 2, c = 3, d = 4}, Print[a, b, c, d]] *)
(* HoldComplete[Module[{a = 1, b = 2, c = 3, d = 4}, Print[a, b, c, d]]] *)
```

Different variant of generation of the same `Module` code, this time symbols localized by `Module` and their values are taken from lists assigned to variables. To make things more difficult some of symbols intended for localization have defined values, so ordinary evaluation of variable with their list won't work. To overcome this problem, we quote said variable after only one step of evaluation.

```
ClearAll[a, b, c, d, symbols, values]
symbols = {a, b, c, d};
values = {1, 2, 3, 4};
a = 1;
b = 2;

symbols
quotedSymbols = quoteEvaluated[symbols, 1]

quote[Module][
    MapThread[quote@Set, {quotedSymbols, values}],
    quote[Print] @@ quotedSymbols
]
(* {1, 2, c, d} *)
(* {a, b, c, d} *)
(* Module[{a = 1, b = 2, c = 3, d = 4}, Print[a, b, c, d]] *)
```

Note that in this case simple `Extract`ion of `OwnValues`: `quotedSymbols = Extract[OwnValues[symbols], {1, 2}, quote]` would also work.

Lookup table example:

```
symbolMap = quote[<|a -> aLookup, b -> bLookup|>, Association]
quote@If[a > 1, lookupForm[b, 23], lookupForm[a, 24]] /.
    quoteNonPattern@lookupForm[x_, i_] :> quote[Part][symbolMap[x], i]
(* <|a -> aLookup, b -> bLookup|> *)
(* If[a > 1, bLookup[[23]], aLookup[[24]]] *)
```

"Quoted" code can be easily manipulated and composed:

```
quotedFDef = quasiquote[
    f[x_] :=
        unquote[quotedModuleCode /. {
            quoteNonPattern[a = _] :> quote[a = x],
            quoteNonPattern@Print[x_, y_, rest__] :> 
                quasiquote@h[
                    unquote[(2 + 5) x],
                    3 10 y,
                    unquote[Sequence @@ {rest}]
                ]
        }]
]
(* f[Pattern[x, _]] := Module[{a = x, b = 2, c = 3, d = 4}, h[7 a, 3*10*b, c, d]] *)
```

and, when necessary, evaluated:

```
ClearAll[f]
eval[quotedFDef]
?? f
(* Global`f
   f[x_]:=Module[{a=x,b=2,c=3,d=4},h[7 a,3 10 b,c,d]] *)

f[z]
(* h[7 z, 60, 3, 4] *)
```

Comment: +1, it is an interesting technique. But as far as I can tell,  you can use any head (perhaps having `Hold*` or `HoldAllComplete` attributes) in place of `Intactive` here - i.e., you don't really use any `Inatctive` - specific built-in operations (such as `Activate`, `Inactivate`). I achieve similar results with  the full version of my code-freezing technique, based on the `Block` trick - with a difference that in my case, "frozen" symbols are hidden by dummy symbols during evaluation, rather than have another head wrapped around them.

Comment: Your technique is pretty close to the idea I discussed in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5747742/uses-for-mapall/5749275#5749275), although there I didn't go into as much detail as you did here. B.t.w., the answer of WReach for the same question is also relevant in this context.

Comment: @Leonid Yes, I could use any head in place of `Inactive`. I used it for two reasons. 1. `IgnoringInactive` can be sometimes useful when matching/replacing parts of "quoted" code, but instead of `IgnoringInactive` one could properly quote relevant pattern (then maybe specialized `quotePattern`, would be useful, that would not quote `Pattern` first argument, etc.). 2. Built-in formatting of `Inactive` makes "quoted" code a bit more readable, though when abused for non-heads it looks inconsistent, but of course for custom head can have custom (more consistent) formatting. ...

Comment: @Leonid When we need "stronger quoting" of `HoldAllComplete`-type then `Inactive` is ruled out, and custom head will be a better choice. I've not seen [your linked answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5749275/5400699) before, yes it is basically the same idea, but IMO wrapping only symbols and not whole expressions makes quoted code more wieldy (subexpressions have the same `Position` as in non-qouted code).

Comment: Yes, agree on all points. Thanks for replying. Actually, while I experimented with this technique, I may have overlooked its usefulness. In particular, I like the composability of your approach. When at some point I needed similar functionality, I ended up using `Block`-based technique, because there I could extend symbol (in)activation to the entire execution stack, which was what I needed. However, the technique you propose is safer, since it is based purely on lexical scoping constructs.

Comment: This is something I was missing from the beginning, thanks! :)

Comment: I can see that a lot of work went into this.  I guess given its complexity and because I did not write it and it is not a built-in I am somewhat uncomfortable applying it (or Leonid's alternative) but I should probably get over that discomfort as it seems like quite a powerful abstraction.  How much have you actually used this in practice?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard "How much have you actually used this in practice?" Not much, really. I've used the "core" functions (but not precisely this version) in few small, mostly "toy", projects. So, while I think this approach is promising, I consider it experimental. I'm sure Leonid's "code freezing" is much more battle tested.

Answer (score 10):

I'm very sure you will find answers to all your questions in very detailed form on this site, since the issues you have were already discussed. Please start reading

- [Metaprogramming in *Mathematica*](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/2352/187)
- [Replace inside held expressions](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/29317/187)

In general, you should look for answers from [Leonid](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/81/leonid-shifrin), since he did a great deal of work documenting many meta-programming techniques that show you how you can use *Mathematica* to create *Mathematica* code.

As for your two questions, let me give you a short head start. I'm giving `x` and `y` values, so that you see that the code still works:

```
x = 1;
y = 2;
```

One way to create a held `Module` is

```
Function[{vars, body}, Hold[Module[vars, body]], {HoldAll}][{x = 5, y = 6}, x + y + 3]
```

the other one is defining a separate function for this, like your `generateAssignments`

```
SetAttributes[createModule, {HoldAll}];
createModule[vars_, body_] := Hold[Module[{vars}, body]]

createModule[{x = 5, y = 6}, x + y + 3]
(* Hold[Module[{{x = 5, y = 6}}, x + y + 3]] *)
```

Both works find and crucial is that both function *hold* their arguments which means that the variable definition and the body is not evaluated during the call.

As for your second problem, please search for the Trott-Strzebonski trick for in-place evaluation. That being said, I made a small change to your definition:

```
useLookupTable[body_, symbolMap_] := 
 body /. lookupForm[a_, idx_] :> 
   With[{eval = symbolMap[a][idx]}, eval /; True]

useLookupTable[
 Hold[If[a > 1, lookupForm[b, 23], lookupForm[a, 24]]], <|
  a -> aLookup, b -> bLookup|>]
(* Hold[If[a > 1, bLookup[23], aLookup[24]]] *)
```