# Does Mathematica has any operators to program like writing lisp macros?

Tags: symbolic, lazy-computations

Lisps use `read/eval`, `quote/syntax-quote`, `unquote/unquote-splicing` and so on to make writing macros possible.

Does Mathematica has any operators like these?

I know there is a topic on `HoldAll`, `Unevaluated`, `Hold`, `HoldFirst`, `HoldRest`, `NHoldAll`, `HoldAllComplete`, `SequenceHold`, `Inactivate`, `Extract`.

And Mathematica itself implemented lazy-eval, so that symbolic computation works.

Are there any operators who works as `unquote-splicing`? And are there any other operators do the same kind of things?

For example:

Racket has `unquote-splicing`:

```
(quasiquote (0 (unquote-splicing (list 1 2)) 4))

;; => '(0 1 2 4)
```

and `~@` is `unquote-splicing` in Clojure:

```
`(1 2 ~@(list 3 4))

;; => (1 2 3 4)
```

Thanks!

Comment: `Are there any operators who works as unquote-splicing?` but you have not explained what `unquote-splicing` is, or given a link to what it is. Since most folks here probably are not lisp programmers, it helps to explain what this `unquote-splicing` does.

Comment: You would have a better chance of getting an answer if you were to describe the kind of macro you want in Mathematica terms. You should give an example or two of input and output expressions for such  macros.

Comment: Ok, thanks for reminding me.

Comment: So, `Sequence`? `{1, 2, Sequence@@{3, 4}, 5}` => `{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}`

Comment: For anybody who might be interested in this question, the macro characters cmal is asking about are described in 22.1.3 of Steele's Common Lisp: the Language. It is a strictly lexical macro facility which operates only at top-level read time. Do not confuse it with the facility for defining functions with non-stanard evaluation discussed in Chapter 8, Macros. The Chapter 8 tools are, in my opinion, more in correspondence with Mathematica's tools for managing evaluation (`Hold`, `Sequence`, `Unevaluated`, `Inactivate`, `Defer`, etc.) than the Chapter 22 macro facility.

Comment: Is this what you are after? [103286](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/103286/5478)

Comment: @cmal Is `Sequence` all you need, or are you looking for "real" `unquote-splicing` i.e. something that will work in context of code quoting.

Comment: Thanks, I just want to do the job like @Rahul mentioned. So Sequence is exactly what I am after.