# Block assignments not quite sequential?

Tags: evaluation

With scalars, `Block` acts like Scheme's `let*`, that is, the assignments (appear to) happen sequentially:

```
Block[{x = 10, f = #^2 &, y = f@x}, y]
```

> ```
> 100
> ```

But with lists, it produces a surprise:

```
Block[{xs = {10, 20}, f = #^2 &, ys = f /@ xs}, ys]
```

> ```
> {10, 20}
> ```

What's the explanation, please & thanks?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The r.h.s of the assignments *are* evaluated sequentially.  However, the symbols don't actually assume these OwnValues until the the evaluation of the body of `Block` begins.

Example:

```
In[8]:= Block[{a = (Print[{a, b, c}]; 1), b = (Print[{a, b, c}]; 2), 
  c = (Print[{a, b, c}]; 3)}, {a, b, c}]

During evaluation of In[8]:= {a,b,c}

During evaluation of In[8]:= {a,b,c}

During evaluation of In[8]:= {a,b,c}

Out[8]= {1, 2, 3}
```

Notice that `a`, `b` and `c` do not have their new values until we reach the body of the `Block` (its second argument).

---

Why do you see a difference between your two examples?  It's not because `xs` is a list.  It's because `f /@ xs` evaluates to `xs` if `xs` is a symbol.  `f` is lost, and won't be a part of `ys`.    In contrast with this, `f@x` evaluates to `f[x]` when `x` is a symbol.  `f` is preserved in `y`.  Notice the evaluation sequence and keep in mind that everything shown here refers to the time when the body of the Block is evaluated (the assignments don't show up in this trace):

[image: Mathematica graphics]

---

This behaviour is not unique to `Block`.  `With` and `Module` have it too, which leads to questions like this:

- [How to avoid nested With[]?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/10432/how-to-avoid-nested-with/54874#54874)