# Is there any way to implement a "sequential" With[] in Mathematica?

Tags: scoping, assignment

I want the equivalent of Scheme's `let*`, or basically, a *sequential* `With` that works like this:

```
With[{a = 0,
      a = a + 1,
      a = a + 1},
      a]
```

Is there any way to implement this? Everything I tried with `Hold`/`Unevaluated`/etc. led nowhere.

Comment: Interesting v10: https://www.wolfram.com/mathematica/new-in-10/inactive-objects/transform-code.html

Comment: Related: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/10432/how-to-avoid-nested-with/10451#10451

Comment: Add bracing for each level. In Mathematica 10.something we started to allow this. `In[655]:= With[{a = 0}, {a = a + 1}, {a = a + 1}, a]

Out[655]= 2`. There is some amount of reddening in the user interface because it has not yet caught up to this change (fixing that is not entirely trivial).

Comment: @DanielLichtblau: Thanks a lot for mentioning that, But ouch, that red is nasty! Any idea when it might get fixed? I actually use the syntax highlighting to help me figure out what variables are declared properly...

Comment: @unlikely: Thanks a ton for the links, those are super helpful!

Comment: I wish I knew, but I don't. And I agree the highlighting is useful, especially when it works as expected.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau This is interesting. What is the relationship betwen this construct, IterateWith and LetL of the link I provided? I.e. it is equivalent to something else? (I recently encountered a problem with IterateWith I don't remember...)

Comment: @unlikely: When I just tried the code on Wolfram's site that you linked to, it broke on some of my code. But I found an elegant way to fix it and make it work with other things to -- I'll post an answer on the duplicate!

Comment: @unlikely Offhand I'd say it is most similar to `BetterWith` from that MSE link.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau: Thanks for the response! PS, I think [I found a nasty bug you may want to look at](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/109389/22830).

Comment: Under Preferences > Appearance > Syntax Coloring > Errors and Warnings, I unchecked "Excess arguments" because I can't live with all that red. This is a more surgical alternative to turning off all syntax coloring.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is outside the scope of `With`. The documentation says:

> With[{*x*=*x₀*, *y*=*y₀*, ...}, *expr*]
>
> specifies that all occurrences of the symbols *x*, *y*, ... in *expr* should be replaced by *x₀*, *y₀*, ...

So even if there was a "sequential" `With`, it wouldn't be able to understand `a = a+1` as updating the value of `a`. It would always just be a replace rule.

I think you'd be best off with a `Module`:

```
Module[{a},
  a = 0;
  a = a+1;
  a = a+1;
  a]
```

You can write your own command which rewrites the form of the command for you, for example:

```
letstar[init_List, expr_] :=
  With[{vars = symbols[init]}, 
    Module[vars, CompoundExpression @@ Join[init, {expr}]]]
symbols[init_List] := Union@Hold[init][[1, All, 1]]
SetAttributes[symbols, HoldFirst]
SetAttributes[letstar, HoldFirst]
```

This assumes that the first argument of `letstar` is a list of assignments (this is not checked) and holds its form so that they are not performed. Instead, they are passed to `symbols` which only extracts the left-hand sides and lists unique variables appearing in them. This is passed to a `Module` as the local variables, the `init` block is converted into a compound expression and finally `expr` is evaluated. So if you call

```
letstar[{a = 0, a = a + 1, a = a + 1}, a]
```

this gets internally transformed to

```
Module[{a}, a = 0; a = a+1; a = a+1; a]
```

and returns

> 2