# Why does With return a temporary symbol?

Tags: core-language, scoping

Why does

```
With[{x0 = 1, y0 = 2}, 
  f[x_] = a + b x /. First[
   Solve[{y0 == a + b x0, b == 0.1}, {a, b}]]]
```

evaluate to

```
1.9 + 0.1 x$
```

instead of

```
1.9 + 0.1 x
```

?

Comment: See the [`Details` on `With`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/With.html#6700) and [this comment by jkuczm](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/109389/is-mathematicas-lexical-scoping-broken#comment296282_109389). It's the expected behavior.

Comment: note that `f` gets defined as intended. Only the return value of `with` is odd and you can hide it with a semicolon.

Comment: I think that in the [Details](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/With.html) section of the documentation, the relevant entry is about *nested* `With` statements which is obviously *not* the case here. Similarly, the linked comment verifies that it's not clear when *renaming* occurs in nested statements. I think that one seemingly relevant example in section [Properties & Relations](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/With.html) (the last one) is actually not relevant here; same applies for the examples in the *Possible Issues* section

Comment: @george2079 yes that's true; I actually encountered this behaviour when answering another question a few minutes ago; I am curious as to why it happens; the code is perfectly operational otherwise

Comment: notice in this seemingly equivalent form `With[{x0 = 1, y0 = 2},
 sol = First[Solve[{y0 == a + b x0, b == 0.1}, {a, b}]]; 
 f[x_] = (a + b x /. sol)]`  `With` does not feel the need to rename `x` . Who knows why?  Ultimately its just a curiosity since the renaming doesnt affect anything.

Comment: this is really confusing to me!

Comment: it is a potential source for errors; consider evaluating the initial example and using `/.x->1` instead of `f[1]`

Comment: You are over thinking. There is no good reason to do a substitution on the dummy variable inside a function.  If you can think up a real example where this is a real problem, work it up and add it to the question.

Comment: @user42582 `With` doesn't care whether the scoping construct is `With` or a function definition. It's all the same thing (lexical rescoping).

Comment: Something to do with the function causes `With` to make a superfluous lexical rescope.  Simpler example `With[{y = 0}, f[x_] = (x + y) ]-> x$`.  If `y` does not appear in the function then `x` is not renamed.