# Nested rules and automatic renaming of variables

Tags: scoping, variable

I understand why `$` happens here:

```
ClearAll[foo]
foo[a_] := (x_ :> a x)

foo[1]
```

> ```
> x$_ :> 1 x$
> ```

For future readers, see: [Enforcing correct variable bindings and avoiding renamings for conflicting variables in nested scoping constructs](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/20766/5478)

But **I don't understand** this one:

```
ClearAll[foo]
foo[a_] := (x_ :> a x) -> a

foo[1]
```

> ```
> (x$_ :> 1 x) -> 1
> ```

Only one `x` is renamed. Should I expect this or is this a bug?

Somehow I feel this one is related:

[Bug with iterated With: Referring to function arguments invalidates previous definitions](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/126425/5478)

p.s. here is a oneliner:

```
Key["a"] /. Key[name_] :> ((whatever_ :> whatever) -> name)
```

> ```
> (whatever$_ :> whatever) -> "a"
> ```

The real use case is something along

```
    Key["a"] /. Key[name_] :> (( 1 /. whatever_ :> whatever) -> name)
```

Where I'd expect `1 -> "a"` instead of  `whatever -> "a"`

Comment: This is much more related to [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/46611/81) and [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/91917/81) questions, where I tried to explain the mechanism behind this (I think this behavior can be viewed as a bug, or borderline bug). Perhaps this can be categorized as a dupe of one of those.

Comment: @LeonidShifrin I agree. Sadly `StrictLexicalScoping` is not an option if I write code for others. I don't want to change system settings without confirmation that it is safe.

Comment: Makes sense, alas. AFAIK, this has not been set to `True` by default, because WA was not building properly with this. Apparently, current (arguably buggy) behavior has been used and relied upon.