# Odd behavior of StringReplace and other replacements—but only in certain contexts

Tags: replacement, string-manipulation, rule

When defining a function that uses `StringReplace[...]` on the lhs of a rule, `StringReplace` seems to balk at named patterns and return a `StringExpression`—but only if the function argument is also on the rhs of that rule.

As an example, consider

```
f[s_String] := {StringReplace[s, (x:"Pattern"):>ToLowerCase[x]] -> ToUpperCase[s]}
```

(The choices of `ToUpperCase` and `ToLowerCase` are completely arbitrary, and are chosen just for the sake of example.)

You would expect `f["a Pattern"]` to produce `{"a pattern" -> "A PATTERN"}`. Instead, it somewhat mystifyingly can't evaluate `x` to a string, and instead produces `{"a " ~~ ToLowerCase[x] -> "A PATTERN"}`!

This seems like a bug because it's so counterintuitive, but I'm guessing it might somehow be a consequence of the following documentation for `Rule`:

> Symbols that occur as pattern names in *lhs* are treated as local to the rule. This is true when the symbols appear on the right‐hand side of /; conditions in *lhs*, and when the symbols appear anywhere in *rhs*, even inside other scoping constructs.

In any case, I'm wondering how exactly it is a consequence (as I can't quite make out what's happening) and how to circumvent this behavior.

What seems especially odd is that this *only happens* when the argument `s` is present on the rhs of the rule. For example, the function

```
g0[s_String] := {StringReplace[s, (x:"Pattern") :> ToLowerCase[x] ] -> "b"}
```

when called as `g0["a Pattern"]` outputs `{"a pattern" -> "b"}`, as you'd expect.

Changing the structure in other ways, such as defining

```
g1[s_String] := {StringReplace[s, (x:"Pattern") :> ToLowerCase[x] ], ToUpperCase[s]}
```

(a list instead of a rule) and

```
g2[s_String] := {StringReplace[s, (x:"Pattern") :> ("b" <> s) ] -> ToUpperCase[s]}
```

(not using the named pattern), produces intuitive behavior as well.

One can see the exact same issue with ordinary `ReplaceAll`:

```
flist[a_List] := { (a /. (x : 1) :> h[x]) -> (j /@ a) }
```

`flist[{1,2,3}]` gives `{ {h[x],2,3} -> {j[1],j[2],j[3]} }`, whereas excluding `a` from the rhs returns us to the intuitive behavior.

(Likewise, the same behavior can be exhibited for `Replace`.)

Comment: Annoying indeed, check `Hold[f["a Pattern"]] /. Echo@DownValues@f` and see initial part of this answer: [126426](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/126426/5478)