# Dependent variables in With operator

Tags: scoping

I want write something like this

> With[{x=1, y=x+1}, y]

and get 2 as an answer. What is the correct way to do this?

Comment: Either `With[{x=1},With[{y=x+1}, y]]` or you can use [`LetL`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/10451/38178) by Leonid Shifrin.

Comment: Undcumented:  With[{x=1}, {y=x+1}, y]

Comment: I'm voting to close this as a duplicate. The question is good, but all you want to know is given by Michael's answer in the link that adre gave above.