# Variables referring to other variables within Module

Tags: scoping

The following doesn't work:

```
Lol[x_, y_] = Module[ {w=x+1, z = w + 1}, z]
```

because `z` refers to `w`. Is there a way to make  it so that variable definitions within `Module` can refer to other variable definitions?

This is similar to `let` constructs in other languages.

Comment: Try this: `Lol[x_, y_] := Module[{w, z}, w = x + 1; z = w + 1]`

Comment: Strongly related if not a dupe: [How to avoid nested With](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/10432/how-to-avoid-nested-with)

Answer (score 5):

I think you meant to use `Lol[x_, y_]`. At any rate, you can use [`With`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/With) to do this, although the syntax coloring is bad:

```
Lol[x_, y_] := With[
    {w = x + 1},
    {z = w + 1},
    z
]
```

Then:

```
Lol[2, 3]
```

> 4

The syntax coloring should be fixed with the next version of Mathematica.

Comment: If With is the answer then it is a duplicate, if OP showed only a minimal example and Module is a key here, then it is not the answer. I know you know but readers may not know why Module was replaced with With without a word of explanation.

Comment: @Kuba The original post refers to the "let constructs" found elsewhere. That pretty much implies a `With`-like approach should be used, i.e. `Module` should not be a key requirement.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau thanks the comment. Seems like my initial comment is still valid though.