# Scoping construct for dependent constants

Tags: scoping

I sometimes want to write a function which needs to apply a bunch of transformations that are not functions of a single parameter only:

```
f[x_] := h[g3[g2[g1[x, 37], Some -> Stuff], "foo"], "bar"];
```

I find this hard to read code. And I would like to give names to the intermediate results.

If these were single parameter functions one could just write `f = h @* g3 @* g2 @* g1` but that does not work in this case. One could try to curry away the additional parameters, but sometimes the some other intermediate result needs to be used again.

Ideally I would like to have the following which just sets the `a`, `b` and `c` as values but allows me to have subsequent values depending on preceeding ones, so exacly what `With` will *not* let me do.

```
f[x_] := specialScope[
   {a = g1[x, 37],
    b = g2[a, Some -> Stuff],
    c = g3[c, "foo"]},
   h[c, "bar"]];
```

My current solution is to use `Module`, but I think that it creates more overhead than needed as the variables do not need to be mutable within the scope.

```
f[x_] := Module[
   {a, b, c},
   a = g1[x, 37];
   b = g2[a, Some -> Stuff];
   c = g3[c, "foo"];
   h[c, "bar"]];
```

Is there something like that? I believe that Haskell's `where` supports this use case.

Comment: Take a look at this question and answers therein: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/10432/how-to-avoid-nested-with - I frequently use the `LetL` function by @LeonidShifrin from there. Other alternatives are the ``GeneralUtilities`Where`` function and the undocumented form of `With` (see answer by @MichaelE2 there)

Answer (score 1):

An alternative approach.  You could rewrite your function

```
f[x_] := h[g3[g2[g1[x, 37], Some -> Stuff], "foo"], "bar"];
```

as

```
f[x_] := h["bar"][g3["foo"][g2[Some -> Stuff][g1[37][x]]]]
```

or more legibly

```
F = h["bar"]@*g3["foo"]@*g2[Some -> Stuff]@*g1[37]
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way of doing this would be using `Fold`:

```
Fold[First[#2][#1, Last[#2]] &, x, {{g1, 37}, {g2, Some -> Stuff}, {g3, "foo"}, {h, "bar"}}]
```

So the function and the other arguments are paired visually…

Or one can create an operator form using `Composition`:

```
(h[#,"bar"]&)@*(g3[#,"foo"]&)@*(g2[#,Some->Stuff]&)@*(g1[#,37]&)
```