# LetL Breaks in ParallelEvaluate

Tags: parallelization, scoping, hold

This was a wild head-scratcher for me to hunt down, but I now am sure [`LetL`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/10451/7936) is the culprit.  Here's a small example:

```
ParallelEvaluate[LetL[{id = $KernelID, sq = id*id}, sq]]
```

which gives

> With: Variable 1 in local variable specification {1} requires a value.
>
> With: Variable 2 in local variable specification {2} requires a value.
>
> With: Variable 3 in local variable specification {3} requires a value.
>
> General: Further output of With::lvws will be suppressed during this calculation
>
> `Out[1] = {With[{1}, With[{1}, 1]], With[{2}, With[{4}, 4]], 
>   With[{3}, With[{9}, 9]], With[{4}, With[{16}, 16]]}`

A similar failure happens with

```
ParallelTable[LetL[{x = i j}, x^2], {i, 1, 3}, {j, 1, 3}]
ParallelMap[LetL[{f = #^2}, Sqrt[f]] &, Range[1, 10]]
```

**Question**:  Can we formulate LetL in a way that it performs correctly inside a `ParallelEvaluate`, `ParallelTable`, and other `Parallel` functions?

Partial answer:  Put `LetL` in its own package and evaluate `` ParallelNeeds["LetL`"] ``.  Then the above examples work correctly.  I use `LetL` enough that I have it in my auto-loaded packages, and I don't always want to launch multiple kernels on startup.

**Alternative question to solve my use case**: How can I get `LetL` to be `ParallelNeeds`ed when additional kernels are launched?

Comment: Nowadays, you can do this: `With[{a = 1}, {b = a}, b]`. Although the syntax highlighting is still incorrect, that might work for you. At least `ParallelEvaluate[With[{id = $KernelID}, {sq = id*id}, sq]]` does what I expect.

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher I verified that this works, but it's also completely undocumented (I'm on 12.1).  It _also_ would require me hunting down every example of `LetL` in my code :P

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem, tried on 12.0 and 12.1 - in both cases things work for me just fine without errors (Mac OS X 10.13)

Comment: Curious.  I actually use the code [here](https://github.com/evanberkowitz/mma-let) and link `mathematica/Let.wl` into `$UserBaseDirectory/Applications`.  I have ``Needs["Let`"];`` in my `$UserBaseDirectory/Kernel/init.m`.  That's all that goes into my example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### The problem

Apparently, the problem is not with `Let` itself, but with the fact that the symbol's definitions are not autoloaded, as you noted youself . So what happens then is that the `HoldAll` attribute of `Let` is being ignored by the sub-kernels, and when you get the result back for evaluation on the master kernel, it is too late.

### Possible solution

What I will suggest below may be a bit heavy-handed, but it should work. You can convert the code into a paclet. The repository with working code is [here](https://github.com/lshifr/LetWL), where you can look for details of how to set things up so the symbol gets autoloaded.

You can download and extract the contents into applications folder, but I have also added a bootstrap installer which would do it for you, for convenience. The following code needs to be executed just once (note the call to `Quit` at the end):

```
Import[
   "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/lshifr/LetWL/master/BootstrapInstall.m"
]

RebuildPacletData[]

Quit
```

After which it works just fine:

```
ParallelEvaluate[LetWL`Let[{id = $KernelID, sq = id*id}, sq]]

(* {1, 4, 9, 16} *)
```

Note that I have changed the context of `Let` to be `` LetWL` ``. Otherwise, the code of implementation of `Let` is pretty much the same as your original one.

Comment: Is the key essentially `"AutoloadSymbols" -> {"LetWL`Let"},` in `LetWLLoader.m`?

Comment: @evanb Yes, it is. I don't remember now what role and importance of `Symbols` property in `PacletInfo.m`, and whether or not you can omit that.