# Map-ed programmatic Style-s (based on user-input) are not evaluating. Scoping constructs are suspected

Tags: evaluation, output-formatting, options, scoping, style

The top function manages several sub-functions which set visual properties over a list of `Options`.

Inside `stylerules` the function `deconstruct` `Extract`-s parts of a `Rule` and calls `string` or `symbol` for applying appropriate `Style`-s then reconstructs them.

A whole `set` of `Rule`-s is processed by `Map`-ping `deconstruct` onto `set`. `Style` properties are generated or selected based on user-input for `stylerules[set_List, keystyle_, valstyle_, strstyle_]` (option rules, keys style, values style, strings style ). For any style argument, user may input `Automatic` vs `True` vs  any custom `Style` properties in a `List` vs `None` or `False` (last two default to generic `Style`-s)

I'm having difficulties with the output. `Style`-s are not evaluating, which also prevents the deconstructed `Rules` from reconstructing.

Don't worry, the code below looks a lot worse than it is. I promise that it is very easy to follow. I believe the problem areas to focus on are the inner functions `string` and `symbol` which may be scoped wrongly. I tried other scopes which did not help, including dropping initialized variables and constants into the main body. Please help. Thank you.

**To reiterate:**

1. *Why are Style-s not evaluating and how to remedy this.*
2. *I just noticed that some strange out-of-place `Null`-s are also appearing in the resulting rules. I don't know why.*

```
(* PrettyOptions 0.7 Prototype 1 Runs - 2 *)

ClearSystemCache[];
ClearAll[set, stylerules];

(* the Echo's are temporary *)
stylerules[set_List, keystyle_, valstyle_, strstyle_] := With[{
    rules = {x_ /; 
        MatchQ[x, Automatic | True | False | None | Null]} -> 
      Nothing,
    keys = 
     DeleteDuplicates[
      Flatten[Join[{Bold, 
          FontFamily -> "Courier New"}, {keystyle}]] //. rules],
    vals = 
     DeleteDuplicates[
      Flatten[Join[{Plain, FontFamily -> "Arial"}, {valstyle}]] //. 
       rules],
    strs = 
     DeleteDuplicates[
      Flatten[Join[{Bold, FontFamily -> "Arial"}, {strstyle}]] //. 
       rules]
    },
   Echo[keys, "keys  \[Rule]"];
   Echo[vals, "vals  \[Rule]"];
   Echo[strs, "strs  \[Rule]"];
   deconstruct[rule_, keysty_, valsty_, strsty_] := With[{
      nbcol = Options[EvaluationNotebook[], FontColor],
      comcol = RGBColor[.75, 1, .75],
      altcol = Lighter[LightBlue],
      a = Extract[rule, {1}],
      b = Extract[rule, {2}],
      fn = Head[rule]
      },
     x = 
      If[StringQ[a], string[a, strs, strsty], symbol[a, keys, keysty]];
     y = 
      If[StringQ[b], string[b, strs, strsty], symbol[b, vals, valsty]];
     Return[fn[x, y]];
     ];
   symbol[sym_, ops_, style_] := 
    If[(ListQ[style] || ColorQ[style]), Style[sym, ops],
     Which[
      MatchQ[style, Automatic], Evaluate[Style[sym, comcol, ops]],
      TrueQ[style], Style[sym, altcol, ops],
      True, Style[sym, ops]
      ]
     ];
   string[str_, ops_, style_] := 
    If[(ListQ[style] || ColorQ[style]), Style[str, ops],
     Which[
       MatchQ[style, Automatic], 
       Evaluate[Style[InputForm[str], Gray, ops]],
       TrueQ[style], Style[str, comcol, ops],
       True, Style[str, ops]
       ];
     ];
   Echo[Map[deconstruct[#, keystyle, valstyle, strstyle] &, set]]
   ];
stylerules[set_] := set;
```

```
(*  arbritary data *)
set = Options[TestCases] = {TestCase1 :> 111111111, 
    TestCase2 :> "string222", "TestCase3" -> Symbol333, 
    TestCase4 :> Symbol444, "TestCase5" -> "string555"};
```

```
(* a few typical use cases, none worked *)
stylerules[set, Automatic, Automatic, Automatic];
stylerules[set, True, True, True];
stylerules[set, None, None, None];
stylerules[set, Automatic, True, Automatic];
```

```
(* this test case works *)
stylerules[
  set, {Blue, FontFamily -> "Times New Roman"}, {Magenta, 
   FontFamily -> "Times New Roman"}, {Orange, Plain, Italic}];
```

Comment: The main issue is that `With[{a=1,b=2a},{a,b}]` doesn't do what you think it does, see e.g. [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/10432/how-to-avoid-nested-with) for some context

Comment: @LukasLang  i fixed the typesetting in the code view.  Initialization in the scoping does appear like it would be the cause but im still a little confused. would you mind having a 2nd look and be more detailed? thank you.

Comment: What I am saying is that e.g. for your `keys = ...` line in your `stylerules` definition will not work as is, since `rules` is not replaced with the value from the line above. You'll have to use nested `With`s or similar, as discussed in the linked question. (So `With[{rules = ...}, With[{keys = ...}, ... ]]`

Comment: @LukasLang that was more clear. thank you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to avoid nested With\[\]?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/10432/how-to-avoid-nested-with)

Comment: @MarcoB only halfway but still having difficulty getting it to work. thanks anyway bro you helped me a lot before.