# How to write a robust memberQ that test membership in set theory sense?

Tags: pattern-matching, expression-test

```
Select[{{"foo", "bar"} -> "a", {"foo", "baz"} -> 
   "a", {"foo", _} -> "a"}, MemberQ[{{"foo", "bar"}}, #[[1]]] &]

(* {{"foo", "bar"} -> "a", {"foo", _} -> "a"} *)
```

I'd like the answer to be `{{"foo", "bar"} -> "a"}`.  The built-in `MemberQ` seems to use `MatchQ` for testing equality.  I'd like a `memberQ` that uses `SameQ` or `TrueQ[Equal[#1, #2]]&`, and works for possibly funky arguments such as patterns.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If I understand the question you are essentially displeased (for your application) that:

```
MemberQ[{x[1, 2], x[3, 4]}, x[1, _]]
```

> ```
> True
> ```

What you need is [`Verbatim`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Verbatim.html):

```
MemberQ[{x[1, 2], x[3, 4]}, Verbatim[ x[1, _] ]]
```

> ```
> False
> ```

```
Select[
  {{"foo", "bar"} -> "a", {"foo", "baz"} -> "a", {"foo", _} -> "a"},
  MemberQ[{{"foo", "bar"}}, Verbatim @ #[[1]]] &
]
```

> ```
> {{"foo", "bar"} -> "a"}
> ```

In case the behavior of `Equal` is necessary or desirable you can use that instead like this:

```
Select[
  {{"foo", 0.5} -> "a", {"foo", "baz"} -> "a", {"foo", _} -> "a"},
  MemberQ[{{"foo", 1/2}}, x_ /; x == #[[1]] ] &
]
```

> ```
> {{"foo", 0.5} -> "a"}
> ```

Note `0.5` and `1/2`.

Comment: Nice and fast +1

Comment: Is `Verbatim` the best?  What about `HoldPattern`, `Literal` etc.?

Comment: @MonkeyKing `HoldPattern` is [related but different](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/2867/121), and "*Since Version 3.0 (released in 1996), Literal has been superseded by HoldPattern.*"

Comment: I read the thread;  What's the difference between (the purpose of) `Cases[list, Verbatim[Rule]["foo", _]]` and `Cases[list, HoldPattern["foo" -> _]]`? For what `list` the two can be different?

Comment: @red3y3 as written I think those will be equivalent because nothing in `"foo" -> _` can evaluate.  However, consider this example: `list = {"foo" -> 1, "foo" -> _, "bar" -> 2};
x = "foo";` then: 
`Cases[list, Verbatim[Rule][x, _]]` versus `Cases[list, HoldPattern[x -> _]]` versus `Cases[list, Verbatim[x -> _]]` -- observe that `HoldPattern` prevents `x` from evaluating to `"foo"` and therefore nothing matches.  `Verbatim[Rule][x, _]` prevents the rule from being seen as a replacement by `Cases` but does *not* match `_` literally. `Verbatim[x -> _]` matches `"foo" -> _` literally.