# Add Pattern to List Removing Duplicates

Tags: pattern-matching, replacement

Lets say I have a list of patterns

```
p={
  HoldPattern[f[x___]] :> {x},
  HoldPattern[f[a_,b_]] :> {a,b},
  HoldPattern[f[a_,a_]] :> {a,a},
  HoldPattern[f[x_]] :>x
}
```

what is the most elegant way to add another pattern to the list while removing all duplicates?  For example let's say I what to add `f[c_,d_]:>code` then `f[a_,b_]` should be mapped as a duplicate but not `f[a_,a_]`.

Comment: Have you seen [How to match, unify and merge patterns](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/7904/5478)?

Comment: @Kuba No. This might be a duplicate.  Let me read.

Comment: I take it you want to match only the LHS of the rules; is that correct?  I will extend my answer with an example once confirmed.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Yes that is correct, but I do not want to keep adding duplicates (although precedence does work).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Automatic behaviors

It's worth noting that replacement rules have precedence by order, therefore you may not *need* to remove the duplicates.  For example:

```
Prepend[p, HoldPattern[f[c_, d_]] :> foo[c, d]];

f[1, 2] /. %
```

> ```
> foo[1, 2]
> ```

For the specific rules you show and for matching of the left-hand-side only you can use the automatic duplicate removal of definitions made with `Set` or `SetDelayed`:

```
Cases[p, (_[lhs_] :> rhs_) :> (lhs := rhs)];

f[c_, d_] := foo[c, d]

DownValues[f]
```

> ```
> {HoldPattern[f[a_, a_]] :> {a, a}, HoldPattern[f[c_, d_]] :> foo[c, d], 
>  HoldPattern[f[x_]] :> x, HoldPattern[f[x___]] :> {x}}
> ```

If the sorting that occurs here is undesired that can be temporarily disabled with `SetSystemOptions["DefinitionsReordering" -> "None"]` as I did for [How to select minimal subsets?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/8154/how-to-select-minimal-subsets/8160#8160)

#### Manual filtering

A manual approach for matching the LHS of arbitrary rules is to replace all Pattern names with indexes before comparing:

```
uniform[(lhs_ -> _) | (lhs_ :> _)] :=
 lhs /. MapIndexed[
   Verbatim[Pattern][#, x_] :> Pattern[#2, x] &,
   Cases[lhs, Verbatim[Pattern][name_, _] :> HoldPattern[name], -1] // DeleteDuplicates
  ]

p2 = Prepend[p, HoldPattern[f[c_, d_]] :> foo[c, d]];

First /@ GatherBy[p2, uniform]
```

> ```
> {HoldPattern[f[c_, d_]] :> foo[c, d], HoldPattern[f[x___]] :> {x}, 
>  HoldPattern[f[a_, a_]] :> {a, a}, HoldPattern[f[x_]] :> x}
> ```

#### Other approaches

If the methods above are not sufficient you may be facing a complicated problem; see:
[How to generally match, unify and merge patterns?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/2918/121)

From Oleksandr's answer there we learn of `` Internal`ComparePatterns `` which may be used for the automatic definition filtering illustrated in section one.  If one is comfortable with using undocumented internal functions one might use:

```
ptest[(L1_ -> _) | (L1_ :> _), (L2_ -> _) | (L2_ :> _)] :=
  Internal`ComparePatterns[L1, L2] === "Identical"

p2 = Prepend[p, HoldPattern[f[c_, d_]] :> foo[c, d]];

DeleteDuplicates[p2, ptest]
```

> ```
> {HoldPattern[f[c_, d_]] :> foo[c, d], HoldPattern[f[x___]] :> {x}, 
>  HoldPattern[f[a_, a_]] :> {a, a}, HoldPattern[f[x_]] :> x}
> ```

For matching both the LHS and RHS of rules you can try the method I provided for:
[Pattern matching a pattern with patterns](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/17892/pattern-matching-a-pattern-with-patterns/17903#17903).

Comment: Something of the form `StringMatchQ[Internal\`ComparePatterns[f[a_, b_], f[a_,a_]], "Equivalent" | "Identical"]` would work(from what I understand now), but I'm not certain if I can just use `Union` and `SameTest` for filtering out the options because I don't really know if there is a guarantee in which order `Union` works.

Comment: @Liam yes, I intended to add that. I'm back to working on this answer now.