# Inheritance in Mathematica using pattern matching on UpValues

Tags: pattern-matching, upvalues, object-oriented

Edit:

---

I think in my original post, I missed emphasizing the main point. This is mainly a pattern matching question. If you're interested in the 'why' of this question, please read the original post below. The short question:

Suppose I have a newly defined, unevaluated `Head`, called `NewHead`. I define a function associated with `NewHead` as (I add in the `x` & `y` to emphasize that the argument list can be arbitrary so long as it contains `n_NewHead`)

```
In[1]= NewHead /: func[x_, n_NewHead, y_] := n
```

This has

```
In[2]= UpValues[NewHead]
Out[2]= {HoldPattern[func[x_, n_NewHead, y_]] :> n}
```

I would like to use pattern matching so I can transform this `UpValue` list like

```
In[3]= UpValues[NewHead] /. (* Some pattern matching here resulting in: *)
Out[3]= {HoldPattern[func[x_, d_DerivedHead, y_]] :> func[x, d[[1]], y]}
```

The point is to make a 'class' `DerivedHead` that inherits all the functions of the 'class' `NewHead`. A `NewHead` object would be stored in `Part` 1 of a `DerivedHead` object. For an example, read the original post below.

The thing I can't figure out is how to pattern match on `n_NewHead` (in **`Out[2]`**) . The name of the pattern `_NewHead` can, in principle, be anything, and the argument list to `func` is similarly arbitrary.

Any advice is appreciated!
- Seth

Original post below:

---

I have read some posts here on object oriented programming as well as many pattern matching posts, but nothing (I have found) seems to address this case, so I thought I'd ask a question.

I am trying to implement some features of object oriented programming in Mathematica, most notably inheritance. Imagine I have a polygon class with Head Poly created like

```
ToPoly[l : {{_, _} ..}] :=
Module[{},
  If[Length@l < 3, Print["Poly object must have at least 3 points"]; Abort[]];
  Poly @@ l
]
```

It has functions associated with it like (note TagSetDelayed)

```
distance[{x1_, y1_}, {x2_, y2_}] := Sqrt[(x2 - x1)^2 + (y2 - y1)^2]
Poly /: Perimeter[p_Poly] :=
Module[{pts, ptsShift},
  pts = List @@ p;
  ptsShift = Join[{Last@pts}, Most@pts];
  Total@MapThread[distance, {pts, ptsShift}]
]
Poly /: Vertices[p_Poly] := Length@p
```

Now, I want to create a quadrilateral sub-class with Head Quad. Suppose a Quad can have a color associated with it. So we have

```
ToQuad[l : {{_, _} ..}, color_String] :=
Module[{},
  If[Length@l =!= 4, Print["Quad object must have exactly 4 points"]; Abort[]];
  Quad[ToPoly[l], color]
]

Quad /: QuadColor[q_Quad]:=q[[2]]
```

At this point, I would like to be able to inherit Perimeter and Vertices from the Poly class. Since they have been defined with TagSetDelayed, I can see those definitions using

```
UpValues[Poly]

(* {HoldPattern[Perimeter[p_Poly]] :> 
    Module[{pts, ptsShift}, pts = List @@ p; 
    ptsShift = Join[{Last[pts]}, Most[pts]]; 
    Total[MapThread[distance, {pts, ptsShift}]]], 
    HoldPattern[Vertices[p_Poly]] :> Length[p]} *)
```

Then, I want to define a function that assigns those UpValues to Quad like:

```
SuperClass[x_]:=x[[1]]
DefineDerivedClass[class_,superClass_]:=
Module[{},

  (* Assign UpValues associated with superClass to class *)

]
```

So, after this is called like

```
DefineDerivedClass[Quad,Poly]
```

I would have

```
UpValues[Quad]

(* {HoldPattern[Perimeter[q_Quad]] :>  Perimeter[SuperClass[q]],
  HoldPattern[Vertices[q_Quad]] :> Vertices[SuperClass[q]], 
  HoldPattern[QuadColor[q_Quad]] :> q[[2]]} *)
```

The problem is that I cannot figure out the pattern matching to turn the UpValues of Poly into the correct form for Quad for a generic pattern sequence. I can use Part to get inside the HoldPattern, but I cannot match on the p_Poly part. So far, the only way I can figure out to do this is by converting the UpValue expressions into strings, but that is very inelegant. Any ideas?

Thanks,

Seth

Comment: Like this? `DefineDerivedClass[class_, superClass_] := 
 Module[{uvs},(*Assign UpValues associated with superClass to class*)

    uvs = UpValues[superClass];
  uvs = uvs /. superClass :> class;
  UpValues[class] = Join[UpValues[class], uvs]
  ]`

Comment: @DanielLichtblau: Thanks for your response, but that's not exactly what I'm looking for. I've posted an edit that will hopefully clarify things a bit.

Comment: Related: http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/MathSource/671/ I don't know if this would solve your problem, you would have to test.

Comment: @FaysalAberkane: Yeah, I was looking at that. It definitely has some elements of what I'm trying to do, but not everything. 

Perhaps more directly applicable is Leonid's impressive question/answer here: [link](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/16869/once-more-on-object-orientation-in-mathematica-does-it-have-to-be-so-hard)

My only problem with his OOP implementation is that the functionality he has provided yields a syntax that is much closer to C++ or Java than Mathematica.

Comment: Personally I use the ideas exposed in my answer here http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/999/66 with MyClass[object], methods are in the UpValues of MyClass and properties in the DownValues of object. I use the package I quoted above for inheritance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I believe the crux of your problem is, as you say, how to match `n_NewHead`.  Let's look at the [`FullForm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/FullForm.html):

```
FullForm[n_NewHead]
```

> ```
> Pattern[n, Blank[NewHead]]
> ```

As you can see this is composed of [`Blank`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Blank.html) and [`Pattern`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Pattern.html), both of which are special heads with regard to pattern matching.  You therefore need to wrap them in [`Verbatim`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Verbatim.html) to make a literal match:

```
MatchQ[
 n_NewHead,
 Verbatim[Pattern][_, Verbatim[Blank][NewHead]]
]
```

> ```
> True
> ```

You can use the same methods to extract the parts:

```
n_NewHead /. Verbatim[Pattern][name_, Verbatim[Blank][head_]] :> {name, head}
```

> ```
> {n, NewHead}
> ```

As a more complete example perhaps you want something like this:

```
SetAttributes[replace, HoldAll]

replace[old_, new_, body_] :=
 Replace[
  UpValues[old],
  (lhs_ :> rhs_) :> (Replace[lhs, 
      Verbatim[Pattern][_, Verbatim[Blank][old]] :> new, {2}] :> body),
  {1}
 ]
```

Now:

```
NewHead /: func[x_, n_NewHead, y_] := n

replace[NewHead, d_DerivedHead, func[x, d[[1]], y]]
```

> ```
> {HoldPattern[func[x_, d_DerivedHead, y_]] :> func[x, d[[1]], y]}
> ```

Also see: [Pattern matching a pattern with patterns](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/17892/121)

Comment: Thanks for your response! Using Verbatim in that way was exactly what I needed.

Comment: Vera nice (and upvote).